# Make the Mexican Wave

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

In as few bytes as possible, write a program or function that outputs the following:

```
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdeFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijKlmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijkLmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklMnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmNopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnoPqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopQrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqRstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrStuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrsTuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstUvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuVwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvWxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwXyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxYz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxYz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwXyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvWxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuVwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstUvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrsTuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrStuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqRstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopQrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnoPqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmNopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklMnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijkLmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijKlmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdeFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

A trailing newline is permitted. You can find a reference ungolfed Python implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/katyaka/a2a74206d90451952146).

Comment: Is it safe to assume input is never upper case?

Comment: @Winny There is no input. The output is fixed. In fact, that's the general idea of [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] questions.

Comment: This has been in the HNQ list consistently since you posted it. Nice work. :)

Comment: You can find a reference ungolfed Python implementation here. -> link's broken

Comment: Franck Dernoncourt's point still stands. The link is broken.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
V+Gt_GXGNrN1
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V%2BGt_GXGNrN1&debug=0)

In Pyth, `G` is the lowercase alphabet. `+Gt_G` is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`, the character that needs to be uppercased in each row.

`V` sets up a for loop over this string, with `N` as the loop variable.

In the body, `XGNrN1` is a string translation function. `X` translates `G`, the alphabet, replacing `N` with `rN1`, the uppercase version of `N`. `r ... 1` is the uppercase function. This gives the desired output.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it funny that the lowercase alphabet is represented by an uppercase letter?

Comment: If only the uppercase alphabet is represented by a lowercase letter...

Answer (score 34):

## C,73

Sometimes the simplest approach is best: print every character one by one. this beats a lot of languages it really shouldn't.

```
i;f(){for(i=1377;i--;)putchar(i%27?123-i%27-32*!(i/702?i%28-4:i%26):10);}
```

explanation

```
i;f(){
   for(i=1377;i--;)
   putchar(i%27?                 //if I not divisible by 27
     123-i%27-                   //  print lowercase letter from ASCII 122 downards
       32*!(i/702?i%28-4:i%26)   //  subtract 32 to make it uppercase where necessary: above i=702, use i%28-4, below it use i%26
     :10);                       //if I divisible by 27 print a newline (10)
}
```

Answer (score 26):

## Python 2, 69 bytes

```py
i=25
exec"L=range(97,123);L[~abs(i)]^=32;i-=1;print bytearray(L);"*51
```

Nice and simple, I think.

Comment: That's really clever. Loop unrolling!

Answer (score 21):

## Brainfuck (8bit), 231 bytes

```
++++++++++>++[>>+++++[-<+++++>]<[>>>>>[-]>[-]--[-----<+>]<----->[-]>----[----<+>]<++<<<+++++[-<<+++++>>]<<+>[>>>.+>+<<<<-<->]>>>+>.+<<<<<-[>>>>.+>+<<<<<-]<<<<[<+>>>>>>>>-<<<<<<<-]<[>+<-]>>>>>>>>+[<+<+>>-]<[>+<-]<<<<<.>>-]+<-<<++>>]
```

Ok, so it's never going to be the shortest, but it's the taking part that counts... right?!

Try it [here](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/) (ensure to tick 'Dynamic memory')

Comment: If the goal was to be the longest possible code that is still completely indecipherable to the average human programmer…

Comment: @Caleb I think the BF code is some of the easiest code to understand in existence. It's the *program/functionality* that's hard to understand. Everyone should know that `>` shifts one cell to the right, for example.

Comment: Always got to love the BF answers ;)

Comment: You didn't write this code *directly* now did you?

Comment: I'm ashamed to say I did!

Answer (score 13):

## MS-DOS Binary, 61

This code does not have to be compiled, it will run in MS-DOS if you write it into a file called wave.com . The code in hex:

```
ba3d0189d7b91a00b061aa404975fbb00aaab00daab024aa31f6e8130046
83fe1a75f7be1800e807004e75fae80100c389d3802820b409cd21800020
c3
```

Or, if you prefer something more readable, here is how to produce it using debug.exe (the empty line after the code is important):

```
debug.exe wave.com
a
mov dx,13d
mov di,dx
mov cx,1a
mov al,61
stosb
inc ax
dec cx
jnz 10a
mov al,a
stosb
mov al,d
stosb
mov al,24
stosb
xor si,si
call 130
inc si
cmp si,1a
jnz 11a
mov si,18
call 130
dec si
jnz 126
call 130
ret
mov bx,dx
sub byte ptr [si+bx],20
mov ah,9
int 21
add byte ptr [si+bx],20
ret

rcx
3e
w
q
```

Answer (score 11):

## Ruby: <s>71</s> <s>68</s> <s>65</s> 63 characters

```ruby
puts f=(e=*?a..?z).map{|c|(e*"").tr c,c.upcase},f[0,25].reverse
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby -e 'puts f=(e=*?a..?z).map{|c|(e*"").tr c,c.upcase},f[0,25].reverse' | head
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdeFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: 63: `puts f=(e=*?a..?z).map{|c|(e*"").tr c,c.upcase},f[0,25].reverse`

Comment: Doh. I tried a couple of dumb ideas to optimize e's reuse, but of course not the right way. Thank you, @Ventero.

Answer (score 10):

### Matlab, <s>60</s> <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```
I=32*eye(26);[ones(51,1)*(97:122) '']-[I;I(25:-1:1,:)])
```

With thanks to [Dennis Jaheruddin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11159/dennis-jaheruddin) for saving me 4 bytes.

Comment: Here you can also use the typical trick to replace `char(x)` by `[x '']` to save a byte.

Comment: Also `end-1` is a rather verbose way to write 25!

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Oops. Thanks for both! Actually the `[x '']` trick is not usual at all for me. But now I remember seeing it in one of your anwers :-)

Answer (score 8):

## Scala <s>110</s> 109 characters

```
val a=('a'to'z').map(c⇒('a'to'z').map(v⇒if(v==c)c.toUpper else v).mkString)
a++a.init.reverse foreach println
```

Comment: OMG in Scala ⇒ symbol is used? I mean not => but ⇒???

Comment: Both are valid :)

Comment: could shave off 1 byte if I change `foreach println` to `mkString("\n")`, and output a string as return value instead of printing it to the screen

Answer (score 8):

## SWI-Prolog, 136 bytes

```
a:-(R=0;R=1),between(1,26,I),(I=1,R=0;I\=1,nl),between(1,26,J),(R=0,L=I;R=1,L is 27-I),(J=L,K is J+64,put(K);J\=L,K is J+96,put(K)),\+!.
```

Abusing backtracking to loop...

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell <s>100</s> <s>89</s> 88 bytes

```
putStr$map toEnum.(\(h,c:t)->h++c-32:t++[10]).(`splitAt`[97..122]).(25-).abs=<<[-25..25]
```

The lambda helper function `\(h,c:t)` takes a pair of lists of ascii values and concatenates both, but with the first value of the second list capitalized. The main function splits the lowercase alphabet (given in ascii, `97..122`) at every position `0,..,24,25,24,..,0` and calls the lambda in every step. Before printing each value is turned into the corresponding character.

Comment: Here's my approach: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53895/3852

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 70 bytes

```hs
mapM putStrLn[[toEnum$x+sum[32|x+abs y/=90]|x<-[65..90]]|y<-[-25..25]]
```

I revisited this problem 6 years later and saved a bunch of bytes. Character growth!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzexwFehoLQkuKTIJy86uiTfNa80V6VCu7g0N9rYqKZCOzGpWKFS39bSILamwkY32sxUTw/Ijq2pBHJ0jYA8I9PYWKAxmXkKtgpp//8lp@Ukphf/100uKAAA)

## Haskell, 81 bytes

Counting bytes the way @nimi did; `f` is an IO action that prints the desired output.

```hs
x!y|x==min(50-y)y=65|0<1=97
f=mapM putStrLn[[toEnum$x+x!y|x<-[0..25]]|y<-[0..50]]
```

Comment: Very elegant. Didn't know that guards can be used inline.

Answer (score 7):

## SQL (postgreSQL), <s>107</s> 101

Generate are series from -25 to 25 and use the absolute value to replace characters with their uppercase version.  Thanks to manatwork for the tip about the @ operator.

```sql
select replace('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',chr(122- @i),chr(90- @i))from generate_series(-25,25)a(i)
```

Comment: You know that PostgreSQL has a [`@`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) operator?

Comment: @manatwork nope I didn't know that, but now I do thanks

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth - <strike>18</strike> 17 bytes

First pass, probably can be made much shorter. Uses `X` to substitute and `r1` to capitalize.

```
V+KU26t_KXGNr@GN1
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V%2BKU26t_KXGNr%40GN1&debug=1).

Answer (score 6):

## J, <s>31</s> 23 bytes

```
u:|:(97+i.26)-32*=|i:25
```

8 bytes saved thanks to @Mauris.

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Comment: I could get 23: `u:|:(97+i.26)-32*=|i:25` (monad `=` is really useful here!)

Comment: @Mauris Thanks, I haven't thought of using monad `=` here. It's very nice!

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB - 58 bytes

```
char(bsxfun(@minus,97:122,32*[eye(25,26);rot90(eye(26))]))
```

Similar to [Luis Mendo's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53832/42418), but using the broadcasting abilities of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

Taking advantage that in ASCII, the difference between a capital and lower case character is exactly 32 values away from each other, we first generate lower case letters from ASCII codes 97 to 122 which are the ASCII codes from lowercase a to lowercase z respectfully, then create a 51 row matrix that contains the 26 ASCII codes from 97 to 122.  Therefore, each row of this matrix contains a numerical sequence of values from 97 to 122.  Next, we create another matrix where each i<sup>th</sup> row of this matrix contains a 32 in the i<sup>th</sup> column.  The first 26 rows of this matrix has this pattern, which is essentially the identity matrix multiplied by 32.  The function [`eye`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) creates an identity matrix for you.  The last 25 rows of this matrix is the scaled identity matrix rotated 90 degrees.

By taking this custom weighted identity matrix and subtracting this with the first matrix, then converting the resulting ASCII codes into characters, the desired "Mexican Hat" sequence is produced.

## Example Run

```
>> char(bsxfun(@minus,97:122,32*[eye(25,26);rot90(eye(26))]))

ans =

Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdeFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijKlmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijkLmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklMnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmNopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnoPqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopQrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqRstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrStuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrsTuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstUvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuVwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvWxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwXyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxYz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxYz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwXyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvWxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuVwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstUvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrsTuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrStuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqRstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopQrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnoPqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmNopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklMnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijkLmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijKlmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdeFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

You can also run this example using IDEone's online Octave environment. Octave is essentially MATLAB but free: http://ideone.com/PknMe0

Comment: `rot90` -- well thought!

Comment: char(ones(26,1)*[97:122] -eye(26)*32)

Comment: @user3528438 how do you handle the second half? The code only computes the first half of the wave. You need to compute the rest.

Comment: @user3528438 - Also note that what you wrote is basically the first half of Luis Mendo's answer.  I decided to write something a bit different to achieve the same thing :)

Comment: @rayryeng yeah, it suprises me that the second half is harder to handle, and also how to avoid the center duplicate.

Comment: @user3528438 - Yup... the second half is what killed my byte count lol.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <del>87</del> <del>71</del> 69 bytes

Not the shortest one, but it works as intended.
Thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for a few tips to reduce it's size by a lot.
And thanks to [@Blackhole](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11713/blackhole), the size was reduced by 2 bytes.

```
for(;$L=range(a,z),$L[25-abs($i++-25)]^=' ',$i<52;)echo join($L).'
';
```

Not exactly pretty, but works.

Comment: “glue   Defaults to an empty string.” – PHP documentation about `join()`'s first parameter.

Comment: That string subscript is not really optimal: `$i<25?$i:25-($i-25)` → `25-abs($i-25)`

Comment: Given that you are already ignoring warnings (for the undefined constants a and z), you could ignore another one for the uninitialized $i. While touching $i, move its incrementation into the string subscript. `for(;$i<51;){$L=range(a,z);$L[25-abs($i++-25)]^=" ";echo join($L),"↵";}` (Just wrap the line where I used “↵” in the code.)

Comment: @manatwork Thanks a lot! I totally forgot that the `\n` was there. The initialization of `$i` was left as an accident. And thank you a lot for the `25-abs($i-25)`. I wouldn't get there by myself.

Comment: Your `for` loop can be optimised: `for(;$L=range(a,z),$L[25-abs($i++-25)]^=' ',$i<52;)echo join($L).'↵';` (-2 bytes).

Comment: @Blackhole Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It really is a great idea! And it seems to work so far. Once again, thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 51 bytes

50 bytes code + 1 byte command line parameter

```
@a=a..z,@a[-1-abs]=uc@a[-1-abs],print@a for-25..25
```

Can be used as follows:

```
perl -le '@a=a..z,@a[-1-abs]=uc@a[-1-abs],print@a for-25..25'
```

Or online [here](http://ideone.com/ZCJjel) (note I had to add `,"\n"` to this as I couldn't add the -l arg).

---

**Much longer method**
Before the shortened version above, I tried a different method which ended up being pretty chunky. I've left it below anyway for reference.

86 bytes code + 1 byte command line arg

```
$_=join"",0,a..z,1;print s/1//r while s/(([A-Z])|0)(\D)|(.)((?2))(1)/\L\2\U\3\4\6\L\5/
```

First Perl I've ever golfed properly so I imagine there's a lot that can be done with it - please do suggest improvements!

Can be used as followed:

```
perl -le '$_=join"",0,a..z,1;print s/1//r while s/(([A-Z])|0)(\D)|(.)((?2))(1)/\L\2\U\3\4\6\L\5/'
```

Or online [here](http://ideone.com/mEA5Xm) (note I had to add ."\n" to this as I couldn't add the -l arg).

#### Explanation

General approach is to use regex substitution to do all the hard work. We start off with:

```
0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1
```

This matches `(([A-Z])|0)(\D)` and gets replaced with `\U\3` (\U changes to uppercase) to give:

```
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1
```

From this point onwards, we continue to match the same regex and replace with `\L\2\U\3`:

```
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1
...
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyZ1
```

Now the second alternation of the regex matches, `(.)((?2))(1)` (which is the same as `(.)([A-Z])(1)`). We replace with `\U\4\6\L\5` to give:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxY1z
```

This continues to match and replace until we reach:

```
A1bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

and there are no more regex matches.

At each point in the loop we strip off the '1' and print.

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell 3.0, 82 bytes

```
$(0..25)+$(24..0)|%{$i=$_;[string](@(97..122)|%{[char]@($_,($_-32))[$_-eq$i+97]})}
```

Answer (score 5):

## TIS Node Type T21 Architecture - <s>216</s> 215 bytes

[image]

[Watch it in action here!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jipsgwtRW4) There's a `DOWN` in that video that I later golfed to `ANY`, but it's functionally identical.

This language has no concept of strings or characters, so I should point out that I'm using ASCII values, i.e. output begins `97, 66, 67`...`88, 89, 90, 10, 65, 98`...

Here's the code in the format of TIS-100's save data, for the purposes of scoring:

```
@5
ADD 25
L:MOV 27 ANY
SUB 1
JGZ L
MOV 25 ANY
JRO -1
@6
JRO 2
S:MOV 10 ANY
ADD 65
MOV ACC ANY
SUB 90
JEZ S
ADD 26
@9
MOV 32 ANY
ADD UP
L:MOV 0 ANY
SUB 1
JGZ L
@10
MOV UP ACC
ADD ANY
SUB 42
D:JEZ D
ADD 42
MOV ACC ANY
```

**Explanation**

[image]

Comment: is this the first question in TIS-100 or what?

Comment: I have implemented a TIS emulator for TIO, so you can now [try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BDsIgEEX3c4q5AAnQgmlXVDCmpEojwcTewMSd3h9h1KaJLAjzefPf6/7M2SgYnEOpYOpP4Ypyh8P5BjHtUYA/LjgBxYpifwnIBBhNLwmRdgSnz9qjFeGDtWtNx8EfFowfjwbTEdLIdSnNXzn/cxvBiU5z7ST6h7QSXF@bHcVl3JhzzuyRG2zBlrO5QtFGO47I3g "TIS – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 23 bytes

```
51{25-z~'{,97>'[2$+tN}/
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=51%7B25-z~'%7B%2C97%3E'%5B2%24%2BtN%7D%2F).

#### How it works

```
51{                  }/ e# For I from 0 to 50:
   25-                  e#   Compute J := I - 25.
                        e#   This maps [0 ... 50] to [-25 ... 25].
      z                 e#   Compute K := abs(J).
                        e#   This maps [-25 ... 25] to [25 ... 0 ... 25].
       ~                e#   Compute L := ~K = -(K + 1).
                        e#   This maps [25 ... 0 ... 25] to [-26 ... -1 ... -26].
        '{,             e#   Push ['\0' ... 'z'].
           97>          e#   Discard the first 97. Pushes ['a' ... 'z'].
              '[2$+     e#   Add L to '['. Pushes 'A' for -26, 'Z' for -1.
                   t    e#   Set ['a' ... 'z'][L] to '[' + L.
                    N   e#   Push a linefeed.
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, 121 bytes

```js
_=>Array(51).fill('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').map((e,i)=>e.replace(/./g,(f,j)=>j==i|i+j==50?f.toUpperCase():f)).join`
`
```

This is really long because it makes more sense to hardcode the alphabet than to use the absurdly long `String.fromCharCode` to generate the characters. Test it out below with the Stack snippet, which uses better-supported ES5 and below.

```js
f=function(){
  return Array(51).fill('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').map(function(e,i){
    return e.replace(/./g,function(f,j){
      return j==i|i+j==50?f.toUpperCase():f
    })
  }).join('\n')
}

// Polyfill for ES6-only fill()
Array.prototype.fill = Array.prototype.fill || function(val){
  for(i=0;i<this.length;i++){
    this[i] = val
  }
  return this
}

document.getElementById('p').innerText=f()
```

```html
<pre id="p"></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>78</s> 70

```r
M=replicate(26,c(letters,"\n"));diag(M)=LETTERS;cat(M,M[,25:1],sep="")
```

Improved by @MickyT

Comment: Almost identical to one I came up with but put to one side.  I used `M=replicate(26,c(letters,"\n"))` rather than a matrix.  It will save you a few bytes

Comment: Save 1 byte by using `write`: https://tio.run/##K/r/39e2KLUgJzM5sSRVw8hMJye1pCS1qFiTKyUzMV3DV9PWxzUkxDUomKu8KBOoIlnDV8c3WsfI1MowVlPHUAeoQ0dJSfP/fwA

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <strike>140</strike> <strike>139</strike> <strike>135</strike> 132

```
void f(){int d=1,i=0;var s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n";for(;i>=0;i+=d=i==25?-1:d)Console.Write(s.Replace(s[i],(char)(s[i]-32)));}
```

Expanded

```
void f()
{
    int d = 1, i =0;
    var s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n";
    for (; i >= 0; i += d = i == 25 ? -1 : d)
        Console.Write(s.Replace(s[i], (char)(s[i] - 32)));
}
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to [@Gunther34567](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/37953/gunther34567) using a ternary instead of `if`

Saved 4 bytes then nesting that ternary inside the loop and moving the alphabet to the outside of the loop

Saved 3 bytes combining integer declarations thanks to [@eatonphil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42769/eatonphil)

Comment: you could save 1 byte by changing `if(i==25)d=-1;` to `d=i==25?-1:d;`

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by changing `var d=1` to `int d=1,i`.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash: <s>76</s> 66 characters

```bash
printf -va %s {a..z}
for c in {a..z} {y..a};{ echo ${a/$c/${c^}};}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ printf -va %s {a..z};for c in {a..z} {y..a};{ echo ${a/$c/${c^}};} | head
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdeFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: An anonymous user suggested that the first line is not necessary at all which would reduce the byte count to 45.

Comment: Interesting. Then from where would the alphabet appear?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. The edit simply removed the `printf` call. [I rejected the edit](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1619/8478), so you can test it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I saw. (The site notified me about the edit and its fate.) As without the 1st line which places the alphabet in variable a, the 2nd line can only print empty strings from variable a, I see no other resolution than rejecting it. :(

Answer (score 4):

## Linux Assembly, 289

Unfortunately not competitive with high level languages and probably far from optimal, but pretty straightforward. Run it using `nasm -f elf64 -o a.o wave.S; ld -s -o a a.o; ./a` (the resulting binary is just 568 bytes big):

```
section .data
s:db 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',10
section .text
global _start
_start:
mov esi,0
a:call c
inc esi
cmp esi,26
jne a
mov esi,24
b:call c
dec esi
jnz b
call c
mov eax,1
call d
c:mov ecx,s
sub byte [ecx+esi],32
mov eax,4
mov edx,27
d:mov ebx,1
int 80h
add byte [ecx+esi],32
ret
```

Comment: Seems a waste of space to compile this to ELF (lots of bloating zeros there). It can be much reduced if done as a DOS's COM program. I guess it could then run in dosbox in Linux :)

Comment: I know and I did just that. Look at my other post http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53984/42642 :)

Comment: Yeah, seen it, upvoted it. Didn't notice it was you too though.

Answer (score 4):

## x86 assembly for DOS, 41 Bytes compiled

Binary:

```
00000000  b9 e6 ff b3 61 b8 61 02  50 38 d8 75 02 24 df 88
00000010  c2 cd 21 58 40 3c 7b 75  ef b2 0a cd 21 41 79 02
00000020  43 43 4b 80 f9 19 75 dd  c3
```

Source code, save as "wave.asm", compile with "nasm -f bin -o wave.com wave.asm" and run with "dosbox wave.com"

```
org 100h 
section .text
start:
mov cx,-26
mov bl,'a'
next_line:
mov ax, 0261h
next_char:
push ax
cmp al,bl
jnz lower_case
and al,255-32
lower_case:
mov dl,al
int 21h
pop ax
inc ax
cmp al,'z'+1
jnz next_char
mov dl,0ah
int 21h
inc cx
jns move_left
inc bx
inc bx
move_left:
dec bx
cmp cl,25
jnz next_line
ret
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl - <s>95</s> 64 bytes

Takes advantage of the fact `\u` makes the next character printed an uppercase in Perl.

```
for$c(0..50){$n=1;print map{++$n==27-abs$c-25?"\u$_":$_}a..z,$/}
```

Thanks to manatwork for saving 31 bytes and fixing it (my previous code did not work.)

Comment: That `\u` seems to work in a separate sample, but not in your code. :( All characters stayed lowercase. Could you show us how your code should be executed? (I put it in a file then called `perl` passing it the file name, no switches.) By the way, I use `perl` 5.20.2.

Comment: By the way, it seems to work when `\u` is followed by the letter to transform in the same string literal: `for$c(0..50){$n=1;print map{++$n==27-abs$c-25?"\u$_":$_}a..z,$/}`

Comment: @manatwork Strange, it worked when I did it. (I use 5.18.) Your code works, and it cuts down the size significantly, so I'll use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES6), 113 bytes

```
c=-1;while(c++<50){console.log('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.replace(/./g,(x,i)=>i==c|i+c==50?x.toUpperCase():x))}
```

## 110 bytes

```
for(c=-1;c++<50;)console.log('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.replace(/./g,(x,i)=>i==c|i+c==50?x.toUpperCase():x))
```

## 102 bytes

Old school is unbeatable unless we'll have range operator/function/generator/whatever in js

```
for(c=-1;c++<50;){for(s='',i=-1;i++<25;)s+=String.fromCharCode(i+(i==c|i+c==50?65:97));console.log(s)}
```

## 100 bytes

Unluckily Math.abs is too long

```
for(c=51;c--;){for(s='',i=26;i--;)s+=String.fromCharCode(c+i==25|c-i==25?90-i:122-i);console.log(s)}
```

## <s>96</s> 94 bytes

Though I've beeing downvoted without explanation I continue my struggle

```
for(c=-26;c++<25;){for(s='',i=26;i--;)s+=String.fromCharCode(c*c-i*i?122-i:90-i);console.log(s)}
```

We can shave off a couple of bytes by rearranging loop instructions:

```
for(c=-26;c++<25;console.log(s))for(s='',i=26;i--;s+=String.fromCharCode(c*c-i*i?122-i:90-i));
```

Comment: Please explain downvotes. The output is wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you technically have multiple answers in a single post?  Hell if I know, good shaving, though!

Comment: Also, I think you can shave off that last semi-colon

Comment: Nope, I was incorrect

Answer (score 3):

## awk, 91 bytes

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<51;i++)for(j=0;j<27;j++)printf("%c",j>25?10:i==j||j==50-i?j+65:j+97)}'
```

Comment: Shave 3 bytes off by removing the `i=0`.

Answer (score 3):

## Sed: <s>135</s> <s>119</s> <s>116</s> 111 characters

(109 character code + 1 character command line option + 1 character input.)

```
s/.*/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
h;H;G;H;G;H;g;G
s/.{,28}/\u&/gp
s/$/\t/
:;s/(\w+\n?)\t(.*)/\t\2\1/;t
s/.*Z//
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ sed -rf mexican.sed <<< '' | head
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdeFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ØaFŒu⁹¦¥ⱮJŒḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//w5hhRsWSdeKBucKmwqXisa5KxZLhuIT/wqJZ/w)

```
ØaFŒu⁹¦¥ⱮJŒḄ
Øa             Lower case alphabet
       ¥       Combine the last two links into a dyad:
  F              Flatten   (1st link)
      ¦          At index... (2nd link)
     ⁹             right argument to the dyad defined by ¥...
   Œu              Make upper case.
        Ɱ      Do the dyad defined by ¥ at each element of the right argument:
         J     [1...26] (len of the alphabet)
               This gives ["Abc..", "aBc...",... ,"...xyZ"]
          ŒḄ   Bounce. i.e. take the list above, remove the last element, reverse 
               and append to the original argument. 
               This leaves a list of lines which can be printed properly with Y.
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @lirtosiast just added an explanation. Let me know if anything is unclear

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-nr`, <s>77</s> <s>72</s> 70 bytes

The first part up to `min` is taken from [manatwork's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53909/64121)

```
range(51)|[.,50-.]|min|[. as$i|range(26)|.+(.-$i|.?/.*97//65)]|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VcPUULMmWk/H1EBXL7YmNzMPyFFILFbJrIFIG5lp1uhpa@jpAkX07PX1tCzN9fXNTDVjazJzC3LyU1L///@XX1CSmZ9X/F83rwgA)

**Some comments:**

`range(51)|[.,50-.]|min` generates a sequence of the indices of uppercase letters

`|[ ... ]` maps the inner part for each index and collects the results in one array for each index:
`. as$x` store current uppercase index in `$x`
`range(26)` range from 0 to 25
`.+(.-$i|try./.*97//65)` get the codepoint for that alphabet index, uppercase if it matches `$x`, lowercase if not. `try./.*97` returns `empty` for 0/0, which gets replaced with 65 by `//65` (I think that's how that works)

`|implode` converts each array of codepoints into a string

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, I can't award a +50 bounty for this as I've already answered this.

Answer (score 3):

## jq `-nr`, 58 bytes

```
range(51)-25|fabs as$a|[range(26)+97]|.[25-$a]-=32|implode
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VcPUUFPXyLRGT0uvpriwqEQhsVglsSYaImdkpqltaR5boxdtZKqrkhira2tsVJOZW5CTn5L6//@//IKSzPy84v@6eUUA) with `.*.|sqrt` instead of `fabs`, or try it on https://jqplay.org/ with input `""` and *Raw output*.

Comment: Here's a jqplay link: https://jqplay.org/s/vyrOcN12Jp

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 121 bytes

```python
f=[];x=0
for i in[map(chr,range(97,123))]*26:l=i[:];l[x]=l[x].upper();f+=[''.join(l)];x+=1
print'\n'.join(f[:-1]+f[::-1])
```

This was weird one because of the need to make a [**copy**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/3576493) of `i`.

For reference, here's the output *without* making a copy of `i`:

```python
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKlmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOpqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRStuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRStuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOpqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKlmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 2):

## q (37 characters)

A first cut

```
@[.Q.a;;upper]'[(raze(|:\)til 26)_26]
```

Comment: `@[.Q.a;;upper]@'x,1_reverse x:til 26` for **36 bytes**. Or `@[.Q.a;;.q.upper]@'x,1_|x:!26` for **29 bytes** in K4.

Answer (score 2):

## K5, 47 bytes

```
(`0:)'{`c$(97+!x),(x+65),97+1_x_l}'l,1_|(l:!26)
```

More golfing to come shortly.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch - 284 bytes

```
@!! 2>nul||cmd/q/v/c%0&&exit/b
set a=&for /l %%a in (65,1,90)do (set/aa+=1,b=0&cmd/cexit %%a&set c=!=exitCodeAscii!&for /L %%b in (97,1,122)do set/ab+=1&cmd/cexit %%b&if !a!==!b! (set %%a=!%%a!!c!)else set %%a=!%%a!!=exitCodeAscii!
echo !%%a!)
for /l %%a in (89,-1,65)do echo !%%a!
```

Ungolfed:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set a=0
for /l %%a in (65,1,90) do (
    set /a a+=1,b=0
    cmd /c exit %%a
    set c=!=exitCodeAscii!
    for /L %%b in (97,1,122) do (
        set /a b+=1
        cmd /c exit %%b
        if !a!==!b! (
            set %%a=!%%a!!c!
        ) else set %%a=!%%a!!=exitCodeAscii!
    )
    echo !%%a!
)
for /l %%a in (89,-1,65) do echo !%%a!
```

To get the alphabets, this uses the `!=exitCodeAscii!` variable generated from new CMD instances (knowing that 65 to 90 is A to Z, and 97 to 122 is a to z). Just hard-coding the alphabets could very well be shorter, but this is much cuter.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 103

```py
a,l='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',list(range(26))
for i in l+l[24::-1]:print(a[:i]+a[i].upper()+a[i+1:])
```

or, without hardcoding alphabet:

```py
l,a=list(range(26)),''.join(chr(i+97)for i in l)
for i in l+l[24::-1]:print(a[:i]+a[i].upper()+a[i+1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

## jq: 99 characters

(96 characters code + 3 characters command line option.)

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"as$a|range(51)|[.,50-.]|min|$a[:.]+($a[.:.+1]|ascii_upcase)+$a[.+1:]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -n -r '"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"as$a|range(51)|[.,50-.]|min|$a[:.]+($a[.:.+1]|ascii_upcase)+$a[.+1:]' | head
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aBcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcDefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdeFghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefGhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgHijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22as$a|range%2851%29|[.,50-.]|min|$a[:.]%2B%28$a[.:.%2B1]|ascii_upcase%29%2B$a[.%2B1:]&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

### Groovy, <s>99</s> <s>88</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```
((a='a'..'z')+('y'..'a')).each{println a.join().replace(it,it.toUpperCase())}
```

*Thanks to **manatwork** for helping me trim off <s>11</s> 21 bytes.*

Comment: With some usual golfing tricks applied: `51.times{println(('a'..'z').join().replace((char)it=25-Math.abs(25-it)+97,(char)it-32))}`

Comment: I'm new to golfing. I never thought about reassigning 'it' before. Thanks!

Comment: 78 characters: `((a='a'..'z')+('y'..'a')).each{println(a.join().replace(it,it.toUpperCase()))}` (Watch out when copying code from a comment. The site seems to insert some invisible multibyte characters in them. My previous code was 88 characters, not 90.)

Comment: Awesome. Way more elegant and easy to read as well. I had no idea you could add ranges. Learning something every day! I removed the parenthesis around println to lower one more byte.

Answer (score 2):

**C (208 characters)**

(my first try at Code Golf)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define P printf
#define A(i) {for(l='a',p=0;l<='z';++l,++p){if(p==i)P("%c",l-32);else P("%c",l);}P("\n");}
int main(){int i,p;char l;for(i=0;i<26;++i)A(i);for(i=24;i>=0;--i)A(i);return 0;}
```

Comment: Can you remove the space after A(i)? I program Java, but it seems like you could.

Comment: @MCMastery I don't think so since it's in a `#define`. It's defining `A(i)` to hold the value `{for...;}`, and the statement needs the space to differentiate symbol from value. (I think that's right but I could be wrong.)

Comment: @AlexA. Yes, that's right. The preprocessor needs the space to delimit the macro name from its definition.

Comment: [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VwVGhoLSkWENJSVMzLb9II8fW0lynwNbAWr1KXT/HWhMomZyRCBTX1tY1NtLSKNDWtrXN1NTkyrTOsc5NzMzTKNCsBmm0zrQxMrPO1LZ1tAZxM3V1rUHY0br2/38A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: building on @ceilingcat [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1MnR7M6Lb9IwzpHW9vGyMxas6C0JDkjsUgjR1sjRzfT3tLMysxEU9MaKFysoaSkaV2bm5iZp5EJ1AXUbKBpnQnUpaYG4kAktA2Bqmv//wcA)

Answer (score 2):

### **><>, 48 bytes**

Just playing around with the `.` operator more than anything else.

```
"a"&"a"::&:&=84**-o1+:"{"=6$.
=?;&30.~ao&1+:"{"
```

Answer (score 2):

**C - 110 bytes**

***Golfed***

```
void f(){int i,n=0,c=0;for(;n<51;n++){for(i=0;i<26;i++)putchar((i==c)?i+65:i+97);c+=(n>24?-1:1);putchar(10);}}
```

***Ungolfed***

```
void f()
{
    int i,n,c=0;
    for(n=0;n<51;n++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<26;i++)
            putchar((i==c)?i+'A':i+'a');
        c+=(n>24?-1:1);
        putchar(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unnecessary parens in `(i==c)?:` and `c+=()`; if you use global variables they are initialized to 0 automatically; `int` is implicit (also don't use `void`).

Comment: Also save 2 more bytes by moving `i++` and `n++` to other uses of the variable, gives me 91 bytes.

Comment: @o11c - thanks for these 2 tips I'd long since forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

## R 72

Since there are no R answers:

```
a=function(i){l=letters;l[i]=toupper(l[i]);l};for(i in c(1:26,25:1))cat(a(i),'\n',sep='')
```

Comment: There is already an R answer, but yours beats it if you make the function anonymous: `for(i in c(1:26,25:1))cat(\`[<-\`(letters,i,LETTERS[i]),'\n',sep="")`

Comment: Short and sweet, very cool!

Answer (score 2):

**Scala - 103**

```
(0.to(25)++24.to(0,-1))map{i⇒val a=(97+i)toChar;println('a'to('z')mkString("")replace(a,a.toUpper))}
```

Some fun postfix operator abuse.

Answer (score 2):

### R, <strike>60</strike> 59

```
cat(intToUtf8(c(x<-rbind(97:122-diag(26)*32,10),x[,25:1])))
```

Improvement based on the comment by @JayCe.

---

Former version:

```
x=rbind(97:122-diag(26)*32,10)
cat(intToUtf8(c(x,x[,25:1])))
```

This is based on ASCII codes that are transformed to characters.

Comment: Very nice solution +1

Comment: You can save one byte on your awesome solution. https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUIjWaPCRrcoKTMvRcPS3MrQyEg3JTMxXcPITFPL2EjH0EBTpyJax8jUyjBWU1Pz/38A

Comment: @JayCe Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｚ＼──ｌｚ＊；ｎ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNDJXUyNTAwJXUyNTAwJXVGRjRDJXVGRjVBJXVGRjBBJXVGRjFCJXVGRjRF,v=2)

This also works in [the latest version](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNDJXUyNTAwJXUyNTAwJXVGRjRDJXVGRjVBJXVGRjBBJXVGRjFCJXVGRjRF,v=3), but didn't before [this commit](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/commit/bb1485d0f4bed34c5535d31306e3e56d8319d713) <sub>(..yes it was used)</sub>, so the link is to an older version of Canvas.

Explanation:

```
Z\--lz*;n
Z          push the uppercase alphabet
 \         create a diagonal out of that
  --       palindromize vertically with 1 overlap
    l      get the height of that
     z*    and repeat the lowercase alphabet vertically that many times
       ;n  overlap the diagonals over the lowercase block of alphabet
```

unfortunately [`Ｚ＼─ｌｚ＊；ｎ`](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNDJXUyNTAwJXVGRjRDJXVGRjVBJXVGRjBBJXVGRjFCJXVGRjRF,v=2) doesn't work as Canvas is too smart and replaces the `V` in the upside down version with a `^`..

Comment: Came up with a(longer) different version: [`Ｚ＼ｚ┌ｌ；┐＊；ｎ`](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNDJXVGRjVBJXUyNTBDJXVGRjRDJXVGRjFCJXUyNTEwJXVGRjBBJXVGRjFCJXVGRjRF,v=8)

Comment: @Razetime that doesn't do the vertical palendromizing. And you could've done `‾¶` instead of `┌ｌ；┐`

Comment: [works, but not palidromized](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNDJXVGRjVBJXUyMDNFJUI2JXVGRjBBJXVGRjFCJXVGRjRFJXVGRjFBJXUyMUY1JXUyMjE0,v=8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki), <s>24</s> <s>12</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ｅββ↑↗α‖Ｏ↑
```

-12 bytes thanks to *@ASCII-only*.
-3 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUAjSUchSVPTmss3vyxVwyq0AMiESALZQZnpGSU6ColAsaDUtJzU5BL/stSiHKAusML////rluUAAA) or [try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nqXnNp3b9Kht4qO26ec2PmqY9n7PeiDv/38A).

**Explanation:**

Print the lowercase alphabet with newline delimiter 26 times:

```
Print(Map(b, b));
Ｅββ
```

Move up once:

```
Move(:Up);
↑
```

Print the uppercase alphabet in an up-right direction:

```
Print(:UpRight, a);
↗α
```

Reflect everything upwards horizontally with one line overlap:

```
ReflectOverlap(:Up);
‖Ｏ↑
```

Comment: [16 maybe?](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMkMze1WMPUUEfBMSVFI0lHQSkmT0lTU9Oay6s0tyAkX8NAR8EAyIOotnLJL88LykzPKNFRSASK@uaXpWpYhRb4pKaVoCoCiegoBKWWpRYVp2okAg38//@/blkOAA)

Comment: [13?](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMkMze1WMPUUEfBMSVFI0lHQSkmT0lTU9Oayze/LFXDKrQAyIQoBbKDMtMzSnQUEuHSLvnleT6paSXIikB8HYWg1LLUouJUjUSgWf///9ctywEA) [13 using for](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98tv0jD1FBTIaAoM69EwzElRSNJR0EpJk9JU9Oayze/LFXDKrQAyITIA9lBmekZJToKiXBpl/zyPJ/UtBJkRSC@jkJQallqUXGqRiLQrP///@uW5QAA), [also 13](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98/KSc/L13DyExHAYSTNK25Aooy80o0rFzyy/OCMtMzSnQUEoGiQalpOanJJf5lqUU5iQUQaU3r////65blAAA)

Comment: [12 :D](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMkMze1WMPITEfBMSVFI0lHQSkmT0lTU9Oayze/LFXDKrQAyIQoBbKDMtMzSnQUEoFiQalpOanJJf5lqUU5iQUQhf///9ctywEA)

Comment: @ASCII-only I was just done editing the page, lol.. Here we go again. Thanks though! I knew this could be golfed by a lot, but you've just halved it. :D

Comment: My original attempt was [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUAjUUchuATISwdxknQUQlKL8hKLKjV8M/NKizWydRRyNXUUcnQUMjWBwJorKDUtJzW5xL8stSgHqMHKJb88T9P6////umU5AA "Charcoal – Try It Online") but after seeing your answer I golfed it down to [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUAjSUchSVPTmss3vyxVwyq0AMiESALZQZnpGSU6ColAsaDUtJzU5BL/stSiHKAusML////rluUAAA "Charcoal – Try It Online").

Comment: @Neil Thanks! Didn't even knew about `Map` and that it could be used like this.

Comment: Well, `Map` returns an array, and the default output for an array is each element on its own line, which saves on explicit newlines!

Answer (score 2):

**VIM, <s>37</s> 35 bytes**

↵ is the enter key

```
:h<_↵jjYZZ51P25@='vUlj'↵26@='vUjh'↵
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 53 bytes

```powershell
0..25+24..0|%{($s=[char[]](97..122))[$_]-=32;-join$s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPz8hU28hET8@gRrVaQ6XYNjo5I7EoOjZWw9JcT8/QyEhTM1olPlbX1tjIWjcrPzNPpbj2/38A)

Each iteration makes a fresh array of a-z, capitalizes the correct one by shifting its ASCII value, then joins it into a proper line

Comment: try this `0..25+24..0|%{([char[]]$s=97..122)[$_]-=32;-join$s}` :)

Comment: @mazzy Your version doesn't capitalize the first `A` -- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPz8hU28hET8@gRrVaIzo5I7EoOjZWpdjW0lxPz9DISDNaJT5W19bYyFo3Kz8zT6W49v9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: very interesting! Thanks. sceenshot from VS Code and Pure Powershell: https://photos.app.goo.gl/RycqsKGLJinRpnW68

Comment: Why? Any ideas?

Comment: `ps5.1`, `pwsh 6.0.2`, `pwsh 6.1.0-preview4 for Linux`, `VS Code Integrated Console 6.0.2` doesn't capitalize the first `A`. Ok, assume it's special behavior of `VS Code Integrated Console 5.1`. Why they doesn't capitalize?

Comment: I've found a computer with Windows 7 PS2.0: It capitalize nothing. `Curiouser and curiouser! cried Alice` https://photos.app.goo.gl/L6L1627JAau9zNGe7

Comment: Well that's very bizarre to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 81 bytes

```cs
int i,j;for(;i<1376;j=++i%27)Write((char)(j>25?10:j+(i/27==j|i/27==50-j?65:97)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcWxCoAgEADQX2kJ7jDJDJM06zOaQ4ruhgJt7N9t6C0vZhkzlULXU1HD/rgTeJq63g6egxBUa4tromcHiOeWEHjWZumUYwHUahsCv/9GSV4G40aLiL6UDw)

My answer uses a similar strategy to [this C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53867/8340), but I came up with it independently.

For the heck of it, here is a solution that decrements the loop variable, (like the C solution), but it is not quite as short as the solution that increments.

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 86 bytes

```cs
for(int i=1377,j;i-->0;)Write((char)((j=i%27)<1?10:(i/27==j+24|i/27==26-j?91:123)-j));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcaxDgIhDADQX3ExaaONtBiJIPIZzoZobAcvAcb7d264N73aqXad87s00P84aGYfwtmSEj1dwlfT8QGov3dDAMt6lIAPLuwi6EVCznaS67pXbmTlzpHFIxlimnMD)

Answer (score 2):

## Vimscript - 41 bytes/keystrokes

```
ia<Esc>qqylp<C-a>q24@qY51pk^qw~jq25@whqs~hjhq25@s
```

Make sure that alphabet increment is enabled:

```
set nrformats+=alpha
```

### Explanation:

`ia<Esc>qqylp<C-a>q24@q` writes down [the alphabets from 'a' to 'z'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109625/writing-whole-alphabet-in-vim).

`Y50p` copies the line and paste it 50 times.

`k^` moves cursor to letter 'a' on the first line.

`qw~jq` starts recording, changes the 'a' to uppercase moves the cursor down and stops recording

`25@w` replays the record 25 times

`hqs~hjhq` starts recording, moves the cursor to 'y', changes 'y' to uppercase moves the cursor down left and stops recording

`25@s` replays the record 25 times

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! We typically [score vim by keystrokes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8995/66833) (counting e.g. `<Esc>` as 1 keystroke/byte) and by my count this is 41keystrokes. Also, check out our [Tips for golfing in Vim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71030/tips-for-golfing-in-vim) page for ways you can golf your code

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thank you for the feedback, I'll check out the tips too!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 11 bytes

```
kaømƛ:⇧ka∇V
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=ka%C3%B8m%C6%9B%3A%E2%87%A7ka%E2%88%87V&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
ka          # Lowercase alphabet
  øm        # Palindromised
    ƛ       # Map...
     :   ∇V # Replace that character
      ⇧     # With its uppercase
       ka   # In the lowercase alphabet
```

Answer (score 2):

## [jq `-nr`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>93</s> 89 bytes

```
[range(26)+97]|. as$a|range(51)|[.,50-.]|min|$a[:.]+($a[.:.+1]|[.[]-32])+$a[.+1:]|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCoQwDEDRq7hwYYkNVnHEXqVkUVCkoq1TZ5mzT1RcfXh//Yq47OMyV@1HwTgQY@HP0vOLvVHssO4bjcR7iFx6Z5GguosWwdC9HemuJQWPgbHEYT@2NM0i/3T8Qoqn6Jgv)

porting manatwork's idea.

-4 bytes from ovs.

## [jq `-nr`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 95 bytes

```
[range(26)+97]|implode|. as$i|./""|[.[]as$j|$i|sub($j;$j|ascii_upcase)]|.+reverse[1:]|join("
")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBDsIgEADAu69oSA@QRkx70KhPIcRguzFLFJBte9q3u3KciV8RV0N6gZ7OZrhePOOnvPMCbLtAPbI9KcXOOt8UuQVtT93He0OgGfGxlTkQGM92qLBDJXDjzXPMmLQ6KCPyy2XFnEiOqf4B)

removing the variables might increase the size. Having explicit references is useful sometimes.

`-n` is for no input.

`-r` is to output the string raw. Otherwise it is printed with `\n` instead of actual newlines.

Comment: If you move `implode` to the end, can you save a few bytes by using `.-32` instead of `ascii_upcase`? I couldn't get it to work but I have no experience with this language

Comment: i'm not perfect sure how manatwork's answer works myself. i will tell you if i manage to get it right

Comment: @ovs got it working!

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 26 bytes

```
26,:L_W<W%+{L'af+\_'A+tN}/
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=26%2C%3AL_W%3CW%25%2B%7BL'af%2B%5C_'A%2BtN%7D%2F)

Explanation:

```
26,     Create sequence [0 .. 25].
:L      Store it in variable for later reuse.
_       Copy.
W<      Slice off last element to get [0 .. 24]
W%      Reverse it to get [24 .. 0]
+       Concatenate to get [0 .. 25 .. 0]
{       Loop over position list.
  L'af+   Build [a .. z] by adding 'a to previously saved [0 .. 25]
  \_      Pop position to top, and copy it.
  'A+     Calculate upper case letter by adding 'A to position.
  t       Store upper case letter in sequence.
  N       Add a newline.
}/      End loop over position list.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 104 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[#~Join~Rest@Reverse@#]<>""&[{##,10}&@@@(97~Range~122~Table~{26}-32IdentityMatrix@26)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### F# - 141

This is my first try in F#. I would love some feedback :)

```
[97..122]@List.rev [97..121]|>Seq.iter(fun x->[97..122]|>Seq.map(fun y->(char(y-if x=y then 32 else 0)))|>System.String.Concat|>printfn "%s")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 125 (ugh)

```
(map println(map #(apply str(replace{(char(+ %(int\a)))(char(+ %(int\A)))}%2))(range 26)(repeat 26(map char(range 97 123)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## F#: 114 characters

Simple, and a little naïve -- can't really think of any other way to shorten the technique I used here. I'm sure there's a different approach that would be shorter.

```
Seq.map(fun i->(for c in 97..122 do printf"%c"(char(if c=i then c-32 else c)));printfn"")<|[97..122]@[122..-1..97]
```

Explanation: iterate the alphabet twice (forward then backwards) with `Seq.map ... [97..122]@[122..-1..97]`, the printing the alphabet each time but with the current character capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <strike>151</strike> <strike>146</strike> 142

Golfed:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){int a=1,b=0,j;while(b>-1){for(j=0;j<27;j++){std::cout<<(char)(j>25?'\n'j:j==b?'A'+j:'a'+j);}b+=a;b>24?a=-1:a;}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int main(){
    int a=1,b=0,j;
    while(b>-1) {
        for(j=0;j<27;j++){
            std::cout << (char)(j>25?'\n':j==b?'A'+j:'a'+j);
        }
        b+=a;
        b>24?a=-1:a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <strike>159</strike> 158 bytes

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){for(int b=0;b++<51;)for(int c=70;c++<96;)System.out.print((char)(c+(96-Math.abs(b-26)==c?-6:26))+(c>95?"\n":""));}}
```

### Online demo

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NYtBC4IwGED/injahygWuNBl0g/o5LE6fJuWM93ETSHE37526fQeD16PK8Z6alXffJwTAxoTXLdp4YMUgbFoPVYtm2BEqUhtZ6ne9yfC9tIzkcoGvEwZj6JzdmDwb6I8pUz4mFMG9dfYdkz0YpPJ35YQ0eEMREQkp/ENbZcgN4THRwplKaqYFt4gIuKSZ1X4UGERhgBs3537AQ)

### Explanation

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        // loop the alphabet two times (2 x 26)
        for (int b = 0; b++ < 51;) {
            // loop from lower character ASCII codes a (97) to z (122)
            // c will be from [71 to 96] (because of condition "c++" before the first iteration)
            for (int c = 70; c++ < 96;) {
                System.out.print(
                    // print character by ASCII code
                    (char)(c + (
                        // if character position matches the wave
                        96 - Math.abs(b - 26) == c
                        // substract 6, because 71 - 6 = 65 = 'A'
                        ? -6
                        // otherwise add 26, because 71 + 26 = 97 = 'a'
                        : 26)
                    ) +
                    // if current character is greater then the 'y' (ASCII 95), also print a new line
                    (c > 95 ? "\n" : "")
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps there's too much math in this. Someone who can shorten this?

Comment: I know it's been almost three years, but you can golf 8 bytes like this: `interface A{static void main(String[]a){for(int b=0,c;b++<51;)for(c=70;c++<96;)System.out.printf("%c%s",96-Math.abs(b-26)==c?c-6:c+26,c>95?"\n":"");}}`. Summary of changes: `class` to `interface` so you can remove `public`; `int b=0;` and `int c=70;` to `int b=0,c;` and `c=70;`; `System.out.print((char)(...)+(...));` to `System.out.printf("%c%s",...,...);`; `c+(...?-6:26)` to `...?c-6:c+26` to get rid of the parenthesis. [Try it online: **150 bytes**.](https://tinyurl.com/yasg7778) nice answer though, +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 121 bytes

```
Array(26){"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}.mapIndexed{i,s->s.replace(s[i],s[i]-32)}.let{it+it.reversed()}.forEach(::println)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xDoIwFAB/hTC1ERgwcSCGxMHB2dE4VPqAJ6XU14Jgw7dXdLnhcsl1g1OoQz3qqBeomaDGFtGJSCzHqyPUTckjH/6C5QfuY/GoJNRNi89O9XowL7JunN7z8onXrBfmoiXMID0mNi1tRmCUqIDZG96TH9J9ztdMgfPodui2YAKyINlm64HOompZUZht7ZTmYQ1f)

Generates array of alphabet string with alphabet size, and then replacing characters to uppercase characters, after concacts resulting list and its reversed version.

Comment: nice `::println`

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

-1 byte from using @ngn's approach

```
x,1_|x:`c$97++(!26)-32*=26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/79CxzC@psIqIVnF0lxbW0PRyExT19hIy9bI7P9/AA)

- `=26` build a 26-by-26 unit matrix (with 1's on the main diagonal)
- `+(!26)-32*` convert to matrix of offsets from "a" (e.g. -32 => "A", 1 => "b", etc.)
- `` `c$97+ `` convert offsets to actual characters
- `x,1_|x:` "mirror" the result vertically

Comment: -1 byte: ``x,1_|x:`c$97++(!26)-32*=26``

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 272 bytes

```py
a=range(97,123)
d=False
i=0
while True:
    if d and i>24:
        i-=1
        continue
    for (x,l) in enumerate(a):
        print(chr(l) if x!=i else chr(l-32),end='')
    i-=1 if d else -1
    if i<0:
        break
    if i>26:
        i=25
        d=True
    print()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/dDoIwDIXv9xT1yi2BBIY/0TgufQJfYLoijVjMhKhPjzgC2Ltzetp@fXyasuas66zxlq8od9so1ZkSzhxt9URBJhGvkiqEk29xL6AvKsCBZQeU69VgBTs26SQuNTfELQajqD3Id1QpIAbk9o7eNiitmocfnriRl9LLX6qA98IQYE8AwYszrSJkZ5ZLJcZjA0gIxelIRodk3nr2aG9TJ9ebP1qj15Nw5vedmEFU130B)
My first attempt at codegolf, so it definitely could be smaller.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You may want to check out the [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/), 48 bytes

```bash
b=({a..z})
for n ($b {y..a})<<<${(j::)b/$n/$n:u}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/yVajOlFPr6pWkystv0ghT0FDJUmhulJPL7FW08bGRqVaI8vKSjNJXyUPiKxKa///BwA)
Similar to the [bash solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53926/15940) but using zsh [substitutions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 33 bytes

```
:h<_
jjYZZ51Pqr~jq25@rqlh~hjq24@l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yrDJp4rKysyKsrUMKCwqC6r0MjUoagwJ6MuA8g0ccj5//@/bhkA)

#### Explanation

More or less combines the approaches of the two [existing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166532/16766) Vim [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217485/16766), saving a couple of bytes along the way.

```
:h<_
jjYZZ
```

[Yank the lowercase alphabet from the help file.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97868/16766)

```
51P
```

Paste it 51 times, leaving the buffer's original empty line at the end.

```
qr~jq
```

Record macro `r`: swap case of the current letter and move right (`~`), then move down one row (`j`).

```
25@r
```

Run macro `r` 25 more times.

```
qlh~hjq
```

Record macro `l`: move left (`h`), swap case of the current letter and move right (`~`), move left again (`h`), and move down one row (`j`).

```
24@l
```

Run macro `l` 24 more times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `jr`, 8 bytes

```
kA∞ƛ⇩kaV
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqciIsIiIsImtB4oiexpvih6lrYVYiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/products.htm), 23 bytes

```
↑{1⎕C@⍵⎕C⎕A}¨(⍳26),⌽⍳25
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8GCpaUlaboWN_Ue9U191DbhUdvEakMg09nhUe9WEA3EjrWHVmg86t1sZKap86hnL4hlCtEF1QwzBAA)

```
                    ⍳25  integers from 1 to 25
                   ⌽     reverse
                  ,      join with
             (⍳26)       integers from 1 to 26
 {         }¨            for each integer n
         ⎕A               uppercase alphabet
       ⎕C                 casefold
  1⎕C                     convert to uppercase
     @                    at
      ⍵                   index n
↑                        convert nested vector to simple matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java: 918 characters

```java
public class Sample{

    public static int i;

    public static int j;

    public static int z;

    public static String[] k={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};


public static void main(String args[]){
        for (i=0; i<k.length;i++){
            for(j=0 ;j<k.length;j++){
                if (i==j){
                System.out.print(k[j].toUpperCase());
                }
                else
                System.out.print(k[j].toLowerCase());
            }
            System.out.println();
            }
        for (i=1; i<k.length;i++){
            for(j=0 ;j<k.length;j++){
                if (i==(k.length-(j+1))){
                System.out.print(k[j].toUpperCase());
                }
                else
                System.out.print(k[j].toLowerCase());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is code golf, so the goal is to solve the problem with as few bytes of code as possible. For a start you could get rid of all the unnecessary whitespace amd braces.

Answer (score 0):

## ECMAScript 6 - <strike>114</strike> 110 characters

(<strike>112</strike> 108 + 2 linebreaks)

```
b=(c,d)=>c<26?String.fromCharCode(c==d?c+65:c+97)+b(c+1,d):""
a=i=>b(0,i)+(i?"\n"+a(i-1)+"\n"+b(0,i):"")
a(25)
```

Two recursive functions `a` and `b`:

- `b` creates an alphabet string with the letter at index `d` capitalized.  Doesn't take very much advantage of recursion, but fat arrows make this function just a tiny bit shorter than a loop.
- `a` creates line by line anagrams (sort of) of the strings generated by `b`

**EDIT:**  Woops!  The capitalization is backwards ('z' is capitalized on the first and last line, 'a' in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell 128 Bytes

```
import Data.Char
a c=take 701(cycle(toUpper:replicate c id))
f=zipWith($)(a 27++drop 27(a 25))$cycle(['a'..'z']++"\n")
g=f++"z"
```

Not as short as the others but a very different approach. Defines the constant `g` as the string. save to a file and open interactively using `ghci <filename>`. Then enter `g` to the repl.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 78 bytes

```
mapM_ putStrLn[['a'..toEnum(x-2)]++toEnum(x-33):[toEnum(x)..'z']|x<-[98..123]]
```

This code takes for all 'numbers, x from 'a'(+1) to 'z'(+1):

- the letters from a to the letter corresponding to x-2
- the letter x-33 (x-1 uppercased)
- the letters from the letter corresponding to x
  It concatenes them. We have the list of the strings. We print it.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 103 characters

```
a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for i in range(51):
 x=25-abs(25-i)
 print(a.replace(a[x],a[x].upper()))
```

Comment: Why calculating `len(abc)` 3 times? It will be always 26. See [Tips for golfing in Python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) for a couple of hints to reduce code size. (By the way, the code you posted has only 141 bytes according to [UTF-8 string length & byte counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter).)

Comment: You keep being one step behind yourself: you fixed the count as 141 _and_ reduced your code to 121 characters.☺ Given that you use long variable name and unnecessarily deep indentation, [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) may also give you a few golfing hints. And one hint for this particular case: count from 0. That way you can use `range(51)` and `x=25-abs(25-i)`, which are shorter.

Comment: manatwork, thanks for all the advice, i was taking the size displayed at the file system, instead of the character count.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v1.4.5 `-R`, 12 bytes

```
;C¬ê £CrX,_u
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0Os6iCjQ3JYLF91&input=LVI=)

Somehow tied with top Pyth submission.

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
;Cq ê mX{CrX,Z{Zu
;                  Use alternative set of initial variables
 C                 "abc...z"
  q ê              Split into chars and palindromify [a,b,...,z,...,b,a]
      mX{          Map...
         CrX,Z{Zu    Replace the char X in C into uppercase

-R                 Join with newline
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0Oso0NoWVh1w+o=&input=LVI=)

Comment: [Alternative 11 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0Oso0NyWFh1w+o=&input=LVI=), if you want to stick with `r`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 107 bytes

```python
a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for c in range(51):
i=25-abs(25-c)
print a[:i]+a[i].upper()+a[i+1:]
```

Comment: the diagonals go forwards & back in the output. You're only outputting half of the required output.

Comment: Oh, My bad. Ill edit it

Answer (score 0):

## MS-SQL, 135 bytes

```
WITH t AS(SELECT-25n UNION ALL SELECT n+1FROM t WHERE n<25)SELECT
STUFF('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',26-ABS(n),1,CHAR(90-ABS(n)))FROM t
```

Inspired largely by MickyT's [postgreSQL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53826/70172), but since we can't use `generate_series`, we use a CTE to create a number table, and use `STUFF` to replace each character.

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 93 bytes

An anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=-25To 25
For j=-25To 0
s$=Chr$(122+j)
If j=-abs(i)Then s$=Upper$(s$)Fi
?s$;
Next
?
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SCHTVtfINCRfwciUC8TNgnINuIpVbJ0zilQ0DI2MtLM0uTzTQHKJScUamZohGal5CkD50IKCVKCKYhVNt0wu@2IVay6/1IoSLnsw9f8/AA)

---

#### Alternate Solution, 93 bytes

```vb
For i=-25To 25
For j=-25To 0
s$=Chr$(122+j)
If j+abs(i)Then?s$;Else?Upper$(s$);Fi
Next
?
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SCHTVtfINCRfwciUC8TNgnINuIpVbJ0zilQ0DI2MtLM0uTzTFLK0E5OKNTI1QzJS8@yLVaxdc4pT7UMLClKBqopVNK3dMrn8UitKuOzB1P//AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 83 bytes

```
97sj1sxBDsy[32-]sU[liddlj=UP1+dsiBD>I]sI[97silIxAPljlx+dsjly!=J]dsJx_1sx96syBBsjlJx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/SvDjLsLjCyaW4MtrYSDe2ODQ6JzMlJSfLNjTAUDulONPJxc4zttgzGqgwM8ezwjEgJyunAiiRlVOpaOsVm1LsVREPNMDSrLjSyQko6lXx/z8A)

Bit chunkier than I would have liked. Ultimately we're going to use two macros, `I` and `J`, and they're going to use some counters, `i` and `j`. The counters are decimal values converted to ASCII for printing. Macro `I`  (`[liddlj=UP1+dsiBD>I]sI`)handles printing one line of the alphabet, letter at a time, checking each letter to see if it matches and running macro `U` (`[32-]sU`) to uppercase if need be. It runs until it hits 123, just past the letter 'z'. Macro `J` (`[97silIxAPljlx+dsjly!=J]dsJx`) resets `i` to the beginning of the alphabet, runs `I`, prints a linebreak (`AP`), adds the value of `x` to `j`, and keeps running as long as it doesn't match the value of `y`. The first time we run it, `x` is positive 1 and `y` is 123, so we increment until we're past the letter 'z'. After doing that, we put `j` back down to 121 (after `...xyZ` we're supposed to print `...xYz` and not a second `...xyZ`), and set `x` to negative 1 and `y` to 96, running `J` with a decrement and lower bound just below the letter 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 88 bytes

```python
a=list(range(26));[print(''.join([chr([97+x,65+x][x==i])for x in a]))for i in a+a[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2J7O4RKMoMS89VcPITFPTOrqgKDOvRENdXS8rPzNPIzo5o0gj2tJcu0LHzFS7Ija6wtY2M1YzLb9IoUIhM08hMVYTzMkEc7QTo62sdA1jY///BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 80 bytes

A script that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=-25To 25:For j=-25To 0:s=Chr(122+j):?IIf(j+Abs(i),s,UCase(s));:Next:?:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 96 bytes

```lua
for j=1,51 do for i=1,26 do io.write(string.char(i+((j+i==52or i==j)and 64or 96)))end print()end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoAgEEDRq8xyxBCUFFp4GEmrkdAwo@ObtvsP/vm41rZcIFo5aQk@wxB1KTNEWbyFasC7Fkq7WA9XkDhi5GStVv9sI3PJg5m7FsMYC11X/yuObO0D)

---

```lua
for j=1, 51 do -- a to z (26) + y to a (25), because the Z doesn't repeat
  for i=1, 26 do -- for each letter
     io.write(string.char(i+((j==52-i or j==i) and 64 or 96))) -- ↴
     io.write(string.char(i+(                               )) -- writes the character represented by the value i+(...) on the ASCII table 
                             (j==52-i or j==i)                 -- if the uppercase letter is equal to i or to 52-i
                                               and 64 or 96    -- then sum 64 else sum 96 (because 'A' is 65 and 'a' is 97)
  end
  print() -- jumps to the next line
end
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 101 bytes

Using Immediate Window and Output in Cell`A1:A51`

```
[A1:A51]="=SUBSTITUTE(""abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"",CHAR(122-ABS(ROW()-26)),CHAR(90-ABS(ROW()-26)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
AûvAyDu:,
```

The existing 05AB1E answer got deleted for some reason, so I decided to post a new one.

-3 bytes thanks to *@dzaima*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8fDuMsdKl1Irnf//AQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
A           # Push the lowercase alphabet: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 û          # Palindromize it: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
  v         # Loop over each of its characters `y`
   A        #  Push the lowercase alphabet
    y  :    #  Replace the current lowercase letter `y`,
     Du     #  with it's uppercase variant
        ,   #  Print the modified alphabet with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-R`, 11 bytes

```
;C¬£ChYXuÃê
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O0Oso0NoWVh1w+o=&input=LVI=)

Answer (score 0):

## ARM Thumb-2 (with libc), 54 bytes

`f7ff fffe` is a 4 byte linker placeholder for `puts`.

Machine code:

```
b5fe 466f 241a 3c01 f104 0161 5539 d1fa
76bc 0038 0025 2d1a d009 bf88 f1c5 0533
5d46 f006 025f 5542 f7ff fffe 557e 3401
2c34 d3ee bdfe
```

Commented assembly:

```c
        .thumb
        .arch armv6t2
        .globl main
        .thumb_func
main:
        // Create a 27 byte buffer on the stack by doing a massive push
        // 27 is for the buffer, 1 is padding, and the last is the link register
        // to return from main.
        push    {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
        // Create a frame pointer in r7, since sp lacks narrow register offset
        // addressing.
        mov     r7, sp
        // Fill the stack buffer with "abcdefgh....\0"
        movs    r4, #26
.Lfill_loop:
        subs    r4, #1
        add.w   r1, r4, #'a' // wide
        strb    r1, [r7, r4]
        bne     .Lfill_loop
.Lfill_loop_end:
        // r4 is zero now. Serves as both a null terminator and a loop counter.
        // Null terminate the string.
        strb    r4, [r7, #26]
        // The print loop
.Lprint_loop:
        // Load buffer into r0 for puts
        movs    r0, r7
        // Make a copy of r4 into r5
        movs    r5, r4
        // Compare to 26.
        cmp     r5, #26
        // If equal, skip to prevent printing Z twice
        beq     .Lskip_double_Z
        // If r5 is > 26 change it to 51 - r5 to reverse the order.
        it      hi
        rsbhi   r5, #51 // wide
        // Load the byte from the stack
        ldrb    r6, [r0, r5]
        // toupper(r6) -> r6 & 0x5f
        and.w   r2, r6, #0x5f // wide
        strb    r2, [r0, r5]
        // Call puts on our modified buffer
        bl      puts
        // Reset the char we modified.
        strb    r6, [r7, r5]
.Lskip_double_Z:
        // Loop 52 times.
        adds    r4, #1
        cmp     r4, #52
        blo     .Lprint_loop
.Lloop_end:
        // restore stack (clobbering all registers but bionic libc seems to be
        // fine with this) and return by popping the link register into pc.
        pop     {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
```