# Is it an Odd Word?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

### Challenge

Given a single word as input, determine if the word is odd or even.

### Odd and Even words

Assume the general rules:

```
odd + odd = even
even + odd = odd
odd + even = odd
even + even = even
```

In the alphabet, the odd letters are:

```
aeiou
```

And the even letters are:

```
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
```

The same applies to capital letters (`AEIOU` are odd and `BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ` are even).

You then 'add' each of the letters in the word together. For example, the word `cats` is equivalent to:

```
even + odd + even + even
```

Which simplifies to:

```
odd + even
```

Which simplifies further to:

```
odd
```

So the word `cats` is odd.

### Examples

```
Input:  trees
Output: even
```

---

```
Input:  brush
Output: odd
```

---

```
Input:  CAts
Output: odd
```

---

```
Input:  Savoie
Output: even
```

---

```
Input:  rhythm
Output: even
```

### Rules

All input will be a single word which will only contain alphabetical characters.

If the word is odd, output a truthy value. If the word is even, output a falsey value.

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Could you add an example of a word without any odd letters.

Comment: @Hedi I've added one, rhythm

Comment: Ex*cuse* you. Odd Word™ [has been trademarked already by JLee.](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19857/what-is-an-odd-word) This is an unauthorized use of the term. :P

Comment: This is begging for a pure regex submission

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to only contain alphabetical characters?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Whoops, I thought I clarified that :)

Comment: The answer is no. Only numbers are odd.

Comment: Got a hint for everybody... The ASCII values of the vowels in question are always odd. No doubt someone will exploit that for a few bytes ;).

Comment: Is it possible to arrive at the answer by simply knowing the number of odd and even characters (vowels and consonants)?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Nearly 6 years later, and this is [finally done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248944/17216).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
lžMÃgÉ
```

**Explanation**

```
l       # convert to lower case
 žMÃg   # count odd letters
     É  # true if odd else false
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=bMW-TcODZ8OJ&input=U2F2b2lF)

Answer (score 18):

## EXCEL, 79 bytes:

```
=MOD(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),{"a","e","i","o","u"},""))),2)
```

**input:**
This function can be placed anywhere **EXCEPT A1**
Put your word in question into A1.

Output: 0 if even, 1 if odd.

Answer (score 14):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>34</s> <s>41</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

Saved 1 bytes thanks to Arnauld:

```js
s=>~s.split(/[aeiou]/i).length&1
```

- Odd word : returns `1`
- Even words : returns `0`

---

Previous solutions:

33 bytes thanks to Arnauld:

```js
s=>s.split(/[aeiou]/i).length&1^1
```

- Odd word : returns `1`
- Even words : returns `0`

Another way without bitwise operators:

```js
s=>++s.split(/[aeiou]/i).length%2
```

41 bytes:

```js
(s,a=s.match(/[aeiou]/ig))=>a&&a.length%2
```

- Odd word : returns `1`
- Even words with odd letters : returns `0`
- Even words with no odd letters : returns `null`

42 bytes to return `0` instead of `null`:

```js
(s,a=s.match(/[aeiou]/ig))=>a?a.length%2:0
```

34 bytes, breaks on words with no odd letters:

```js
f=s=>s.match(/[aeiou]/ig).length%2
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Shaun H

```js
s=>s.match(/[aeiou]/ig).length%2
```

Comment: This method breaks when word has no vowels. That said: `f=` isn't needed, and calling exec on the regex object is shorter. `s=>/[aeiou]/ig.exec(s).length%2`

Comment: I don't have the same result with `exec` with the `g` flag.

Comment: dammit brain yeah ignore that, f= still isn't needed though

Comment: Could you do `s=>s.split(/[aeiou]/i).length&1^1`?

Comment: `s=>~s.split(/[aeiou]/i).length&1` is actually one byte shorter.

Comment: Eww, `++...length%2`? I'd have written that `...length%2<1`.

Comment: @Hedi how does the logic on this work? I'm trying to make sense of this...

Comment: @WallyWest the `split(...).length` is the number of gap between odd letters (may be even letters or empty string). If we just did `%2` the result would be falsy for odd words and truthy for even words.
The `~` inverts the bits of its operand (~x == -x-1) so if x was even ~x is odd.  The `&1` does the same as `%2` (except that negative value `%2` gives `-0` or `-1`).

Comment: The expected result is `If the word is odd, output a truthy value`. So returning zero for odd words won't do because 0 is a falsy value.

Comment: Didn't read the end of question, sorry :)

Answer (score 9):

## C, 42 bytes

```c
f(char*s){return*s&&2130466>>*s&1^f(s+1);}
```

This works with GCC 4.x on a x86-64 CPU. Results may vary with different setups.

Test it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/DePi).

At the cost of 5 more bytes, undefined behavior can be avoided, so the code should work as long as *int*s are at least 32 bits wide.

```c
f(char*s){return*s&&2130466>>(*s&31)&1^f(s+1);}
```

#### How it works

Modulo **32**, the character codes of all odd letters are **1**, **5**, **9**, **15**, and **21**. **2130466** is the 32-bit integer that has set bits at these positions and unset bits at all others.

When **f** is called on a string, it first checks if the first character of the string is a null byte (string terminator). If it is, `*s` yields **0** and **f** returns **0**. Otherwise, `*s` yield the character code of a letter  and the right argument of the logical AND (`&&`) is executed.

For `>>`, GCC generates a shift instruction. On a x86-64 CPU, the corresponding instruction for a 32-bit integer ignores all but the lower 5 bits of the right argument, which avoids reducing `*s` modulo **32**. The right shift and the following bitwise AND with **1** extracts the bit of **2130466** that corresponds to the letter, which will be **1** if and only if the letter is odd.

Afterwards, we increment the pointer **s** (effectively discarding the first letter), call **f** recursively on the beheaded string, and take the bitwise XOR of the result from above and the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Great bit wise work!

Comment: erees Return 0 in Ideone, is it right?

Comment: @RosLuP No, that's not correct. It works on my computer and on [repl.it](https://repl.it/DePi) though (possibly because the version of GCC is quite different).

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely the compiler. With clang 3.7, [it works on Ideone as well](http://ideone.com/iaIQzA).

Answer (score 8):

## sed <strike>44</strike> (42 + 1 for -n) 43

-1 thanks to Neil

```
s/[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou]//gi
/[aeiou]/Ico
```

Prints `o` for odd and nothing for even

Comment: `s/[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou]//gi` might save you a byte, if I've counted correctly.

Comment: @Neil Yep! I wish sed could do non-greedy search.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) <s>206</s> <s>196</s> <s>192</s> 178 + 3 = 181 bytes

[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdPHsoe31bKCgoKCgoKCkoKSgpKSl7fSl7fSl7fSl7fSl7fSgpXSl7KHt9Wyh7fSgpKV0peyh7fVsoe30pXSl7KHt9Wyh7fSgpKCkpXSl7KHt9Wyh7fSldKXsoe308PikoPD4pfX19fX17fXt9fT48PltbXV08PigpKCkpeygoe31bPD4oKCkpPD4oKSgpXSkpe3t9KHt9KCkpKCg8Pik8Pil9e319e308Pih7fTw-KQ&input=aGVsbG8gZWFydGgh&args=LWE)

```
([]<{({}[((((((()()())){}){}){}){}){}()]){({}[({}())]){({}[({})]){({}[({}()())]){({}[({})]){({}<>)(<>)}}}}}{}{}}><>[[]]<>()()){(({}[<>(())<>()()])){{}({}())((<>)<>)}{}}{}<>({}<>)
```

This requires the `-c` flag to run in ASCII mode adding an extra 3 bytes to the length of the program.

### Ungolfed

```
([]<
{({}[(((((()()()){}){}){}){}){}()])
 {
  ({}[()()()()])
  {
   ({}[()()()()])
   {
    ({}[(()()()){}])
    {
     ({}[(()()()){}])
     {
      ({}<>)
      (<>)
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 {}
}
><>[[]]<>)
(<(()()<>)>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}()[({})])){{}(<({}({}))>)}{}<>}{}<>({}<{}><>)
```

### Explanation

First store the stack height for future purposes

```
([]<...>
```

Then while the stack is not empty (assumes that none of the characters is zero)

```
{...}
```

Subtract ninety seven (and store 3 for later optimizations)

```
({}[((((((()()())){}){}){}){}){}()])
```

If it is not zero (i.e. not a)

```
{...}
```

Subtract 4 (and store 4 for later optimizations)

```
({}[({}())])
```

If it is not zero (i.e. not e)

```
{...}
```

Subtract 4 (and store 4 for later optimizations)

```
({}[({})])
```

If it is not zero (i.e. not i)

```
{...}
```

Subtract 6 (and store 6 for later optimizations)

```
({}[({}()())])
```

If it is not zero (i.e. not o)

```
{...}
```

Subtract 6 (store 6 because the program expects one later)

```
({}[({})])
```

If it is not zero (i.e. not u)

```
{...}
```

Move the remainder to the other stack and put a zero on the active stack to escape all of the ifs

```
({}<>)(<>)
```

Once all of the ifs have been escaped remove the zero and the six

```
{}{}
```

Once all the characters have been processed subtract the height of the offset from the originally stored height.

```
...<>[[]]<>)
```

Mod by two

```
{(({}[<>(())<>()()])){{}({}())((<>)<>)}{}}{}<>({}<>)
```

Comment: I think `-c` is only +1 byte since ever Perl answer also only adds 1 byte / flag.

Comment: @ThreeFx That's because `perl -pe'code'` is only one byte longer than `perl -e'code'`.

Answer (score 8):

### Python, 41 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(map(s.count,"aeiouAEIOU"))%2
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13 12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to @Luis Mendo (use `Ḃ` to replace `%2`)
-1 byte thanks to @Dennis (use a string compression)

```
Œlf“¡ẎṢɱ»LḂ
```

All test cases are at **[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJsZuKAnMKh4bqO4bmiybHCu0zhuIIKxbzDh-KCrEvigqxZ&input=&args=InRyZWVzIiwiYnJ1c2giLCJDQXRzIiwiU2F2b2llIiwicmh5dGhtIg)**

How?

```
Œlf“¡ẎṢɱ»LḂ - Main link takes an argument - s
Œl          - lowercase(s)
   “¡ẎṢɱ»   - string of lowercase vowels (compression using the words a and eoui)
  f         - filter - keep only the vowels
         L  - length - the number of vowels
          Ḃ - Bit (modulo 2)
```

---

**Non-competing, 5 bytes** (since I just added the function `Øc`)

```
fØcLḂ
```

Test cases also at **[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZsOYY0zhuIIKxbzDh-KCrEvigqxZ&input=&args=InRyZWVzIiwiYnJ1c2giLCJDQXRzIiwiU2F2b2llIiwicmh5dGhtIg)**

Same as above, but `Øc` yields the Latin alphabet's vowels, `'AEIOUaeiou'`

Comment: I think you can replace `%2` by `Ḃ `

Comment: *euoi* is [*a cry of impassioned rapture in ancient Bacchic revels*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euoi), so you can use the dictionary and get the vowels as `“¡ẎṢɱ»`.

Comment: @Dennis - LOL of course!

Comment: @Dennis How exactly does that work? Is it just base-compression to get the index of a word in a giant dictionary? Where does the 'a' come from?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem it's a base 250 compression using a [dictionary](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/dictionary.py) (which I believe was just taken from Dennis's computer) with separation between short (less than 6 char) and long words. Some [code to automate the process of making compressed strings](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70932/53748) was written by Lynn. The unused 6 bytes are Jelly's string identifying characters `“”«»‘’` (there is also `⁾` which is for a two-char string, but that is used within compressed strings).

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>524, 446</s>, 422 bytes

```
{(<((((()()()()){}){}){}<>)>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}[({})]())){{}(<({}({}))>)}{}<>}{}<>([(((({}<{}<>>))))]()){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}([{}]()()()()()){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}(((()()())){}{}[{}]){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}(((()()()()())){}{}[{}]){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}((((()()()){}())){}{}[{}]){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}}(<(()())>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}[({})]())){{}(<({}({}))>)}{}<>}{}<>({}<{}<>>)
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=eyg8KCgoKCgpKCkoKSgpKXt9KXt9KXt9PD4pPik8Pnsoe31bKCldKTw-KCh7fVsoe30pXSgpKSl7e30oPCh7fSh7fSkpPil9e308Pn17fTw-KFsoKCgoe308e308Pj4pKSkpXSgpKXsoPHt9Pik8Pih7fVsoKV0pPD59PD4oe30oKSk8Pnt9KFt7fV0oKSgpKCkoKSgpKXsoPHt9Pik8Pih7fVsoKV0pPD59PD4oe30oKSk8Pnt9KCgoKCkoKSgpKSl7fXt9W3t9XSl7KDx7fT4pPD4oe31bKCldKTw-fTw-KHt9KCkpPD57fSgoKCgpKCkoKSgpKCkpKXt9e31be31dKXsoPHt9Pik8Pih7fVsoKV0pPD59PD4oe30oKSk8Pnt9KCgoKCgpKCkoKSl7fSgpKSl7fXt9W3t9XSl7KDx7fT4pPD4oe31bKCldKTw-fTw-KHt9KCkpPD57fX0oPCgoKSgpKT4pPD57KHt9WygpXSk8Pigoe31bKHt9KV0oKSkpe3t9KDwoe30oe30pKT4pfXt9PD59e308Pih7fTx7fTw-Pik&input=SGFsbG8&args=LWE)

Ungolfed, more readable version:

```
{((((()()()()){}){}){})(<({}<>)>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}()[({})])){{}(<({}({}))>)}{}<>}{}<>({}<{}><>)((((({})))))
(())
({}[{}]){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}
(()()()()())
({}[{}]){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}
(()()()()()()()()())
({}[{}]){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())
({}[{}]){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())
({}[{}])
{(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())<>{}}<>(()())(<({}<>)>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}()[({})])){{}(<({}({}))>)}{}<>}{}<>({}<{}><>){{}([()])
(<><>)}({}{}())
```

Comment: The Ungolfed version doesn't seem to work (can't fit TIO link in comment ;_;)

Comment: "more readable" 'nough said

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
odd.length.filter(`elem`"aeiouAEIOU")
```

Thanks to Angs for one byte!

Comment: Truthy for odd, so you have to use `odd` instead of `even`. Saves one byte!

Comment: @Angs clever :)

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 42 bytes

```
lambda s:sum(c in"aeiouAEIOU"for c in s)%2
```

Not a whole lot to explain here. An unnamed function that returns 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 53 Bytes

This can probably be golfed further:

```
lambda n:[x in 'aeiou' for x in n.lower()].count(1)&1
```

Comment: Remove spaces between `in` and `'aeiou'` and `for`, and use `sum` to save 8 bytes: `lambda n:sum(x in'aeiou'for x in n.lower())&1` (although as you can see from DJMcMayhem's post using all ten vowels is also shorter)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I noticed the extra spaces a little bit after posting, but in all honesty, @DJMcMayhem and I had identical approaches with his being the best version I can imagine for a Python solution. I didn't know about the `sum()` command before this golf so once again I learned something! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 4):

**C 52 bytes**

```
h(o){o=strpbrk(o,"aeiouAEIOU");return o?1^h(o+1):0;}
```

the main and the result:

```
main()
{int   k;
 char *a[]={"trees","brush","CAts","Savoie","rhythm", 0};

 for(k=0;a[k];++k)
     printf("[%s]=%s\n", a[k], h(a[k])?"odd":"even");
}

/*
91
[trees]=even
[brush]=odd
[CAts]=odd
[Savoie]=even
[rhythm]=even

*/
```

Comment: i try to use int as pointers but it not compile where the use of inirection *... the solution printed first here was wrong...

Comment: `h(o){return~-o?1^h(1+strpbrk(o,"aeiouAEIOU")):1;}` saves 3 bytes.

Comment: s;h(o){s=~-o?1^h(1+strpbrk(o,"aeiouAEIOU")):1;}  the result is in the global variable s...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not allowed. Functions have to be reusable, and this will break if you use it more than once. Also, saving the output in a variable is not allowed, unless you take the location as user input.

Comment: I think in this case reuse is possible becausr the start value of s now is not important...ok ok now i think something can go wrong... Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, [storing the output in a variable](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6965/12012) is not considered a valid form of output. The code I proposed is exactly as long as yours and complies with our rules for I/O.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
%l@"aeiou"rQ02
```

[Try it Online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25l%40%22aeiou%22Q2&input=%22caaeeiiit%22&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
  @"aeiou"       Grab only the vowels
          rQ0      From lowercased input
 l                 Get the length of this
%            2     And mod 2 to check for oddness
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 30 bytes

```
->w{w.scan(/[aeiou]/i).size%2}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, <s>32, 31</s>, 29 keystrokes

```
:s/[^aeiou]//gi
C<C-r>=len(@")%2<cr>
```

Since the V interpreter is backwards compatible, you can [try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=OnMvW15hZWlvdV0vL2dpCkMSPWxlbihAIiklMgo&input=SGVsbG9v) right here.

*<s>One</s> Three bytes saved thanks to m-chrzan!*

Comment: Can you do `s/.../gi` instead of `s/\c.../g`?

Comment: @m-chrzan Woah, awesome tip. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `'<C-r>"'` -> `@"`.

Comment: @m-chrzan Wow, thanks. You should consider posting on the [vim tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71030/tips-for-golfing-in-vim) thread. I bet you'd have some useful ones.

Comment: I found out about `@"` 15 minutes ago. The best vim tip I have is to use `:help foo` and `/` the documentation :P.

Comment: Well, since we're talking about golf, `:h foo` is shorter. :P

Answer (score 3):

**Java, 73**

```
boolean f(String s){return s.replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]","").length()%2>0;}
```

saw a couple other java answers, otherwise wouldn't have shared. Thanks to Phaeze for saving a byte.

Comment: I think you can save a byte with `%2>0`

Answer (score 3):

## [dimwit](https://github.com/MCMastery/dimwit), 14 bytes (non-competing)

```
ar[aeiou]}et}T
```

I thought this would be a fun, simple challenge to start with for a new language.

#### Explanation

- `a` -  push a new array to the matrix
- `r[aeiou]}` - count occurrences of all values matching the regex "[aeiou]" in the first array (since the first array contains the input), ignoring case, and push that value to the end of the last array.
- `e` - if the last number in the last array is even (which we set to the number of occurrences), perform the next operations up until a closing bracket ("}")
- `t` - stop execution, clear the matrix, and set the first value to be false
- `}` - end of `e` code block
- `T` - stop execution, clear the matrix, and set the first value to be true

#### [Try it online!](http://dgrissom.com/dimwit/index.html?ar[aeiou]%7Det%7DT)

Use the Input field to enter the word.

I'll soon add documentation...

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 36 bytes

```bash
x=${1,,//[aeiou]/}
((1&${#1}&${#x}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v8JWpdpQR0dfPzoxNTO/NFa/lktDw1BNpVrZsBZEVtRqav7//98jNScnv9y/KCdFEQA)

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 30 bytes

```bash
((1&$#1&${#${1:l}//[aeiou]/}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9fQ8NQTUUZiKuVVaoNrXJq9fWjE1Mz80tj9Ws1Nf///@@RmpPjX@5flJMCAA)

Accepts input as its first argument. Exits with nonzero if even, exits zero if odd.

We *barely* beat out the bash+coreutils solution!

```bash
x=${1,,//[aeiou]/}  # lowercase first argument, then remove all [aeiou]
((1&${#1}&${#x}))
  1&     &          # bitwise-and 1 with
    ${#1} ${#x}     # length of first parameter and length of stripped parameter
((             ))   # if nonzero, exit 0 (truthy in shell)
```

The Zsh solution is very similar, but uses the ability to nest parameter expansions to save an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
=/^"aeiou"?_:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJx1j8FKAzEQhu/zFCF40MM2LYLQBBHx5KmHHku1cXe2CW0zbTKpu4g+u21KLYje5uf7Z/im1ffqRVr0lOXDqwZg/XE167+iboUQnVnQylwvWuvXpjO9iTfzz0NnJjkiJmlG82N4izk5aYYlPD1yOs9TuyeP51p0PbtNSaDAMW+TVqqmBpe0bgeJbb3CrnY2LHFQ00btMib2FJIa346Hd8qnynNlQ0VNU71TbACewzazFqL4wCRzibjHcGFF74cddi/oKPs3Oan/c/H0yS8I8A2FOmuS)

Returns `1` for "even" inputs and `0` for "odd" ones.

- `_:` lowercase the (implicit) input
- `^"aeiou"?` generate a bitmask indicating which characters in the (lowercased) input are *not* vowels
- `=/` do an equals-reduce; if there are an even number of `0`s (i.e. vowels), this returns `1`. if there are an odd number, it returns `0`

Comment: By the default site I/O rules, `1` for even and `0` for odd should be allowed.

Comment: Great, thanks! Updated the answer to trim those notes out.

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 19 bytes

```
Mi`[aeiou]
[13579]$
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApNaWBbYWVpb3VdClsxMzU3OV0k&input=dHJlZXMKYnJ1c2gKQ0F0cwpTYXZvaWU) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

The first line counts the vowels in the input. The second line checks that the result is odd.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```
($args[0]-replace'[^aeiouAEIOU]').Length%2
```

Takes input `$args[0]`, sends it through `-replace` to remove all non-vowel characters, takes the resulting `.length`, and `%2` to check whether it's odd/even.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 'trees','brush','CAts','Savoie','rhythm'|%{"$_ --> "+(.\is-it-an-odd-word.ps1 $_)}
trees --> 0
brush --> 1
CAts --> 1
Savoie --> 0
rhythm --> 0
```

Comment: You can just [use `[^aeiou]` for **37 bytes**](https://tio.run/##dY2xTsMwEIZ3P8UpOXA8GBXGVh0qxIbEwFgVybSX2pJrB9tpoFGePdiVECxMd6f7vv/v/EAharJ2xnY9zg2qcIzbxU4G6qzaE9@@KTK@33Fx90zumPTNwzyt8LJerFofSO11gxaMAzSu65MYGYBpG7yIcQgmkdQ@pinz99cHZFrSB1QVSB8Abekqd10JKO4EZCNdV4DfBJDOOxqscQQVNiXoFtvsZ4u/HA5LAP6j8qczuWW@RVUC2X85aNk011BooE916ixFxlKgPF7V2RtiQX8lfWKshtzxB3oPfdTscZPiNw), as `-replace` is by default case insensitive. You'd have to use `(?-i)[^aeiou]` to make it case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 34 bytes

```
@(s)mod(nnz(~(s'-'aeiouAEIOU')),2)


s'-'aeiouAEIOU'    % Creates a 2D-matrix where each of the odd letters are 
                   % subtracted from the string s
~(s'-'aeiouAEIOU') % Negates that array, so the all zero elements become 1
nnz( .... )        % Counts all the non-zero elements (the odd letters)
mod(nnz( ....),2   % Takes this sum modulus 2
```

This is 6 bytes shorter than the traditional approach using `ismember`, `@(s)mod(sum(ismember(s,'aeiouAEIOU')),2)`, and two bytes shorter than the regex approach: `@(s)mod(nnz(regexpi(s,'[aeiou]')),2)`.

[Test it here](https://ideone.com/DfHDIN).

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 88

```java
boolean f(char[]s){int x=0;for(char c:s)if("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c)>=0)++x;return x%2>0;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
  boolean f(char[] s) {
    int x = 0;
    for (char c : s) {
      if ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c) >= 0) {
        ++x;
      }
    }
    return x % 2 > 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 20 bytes

```
2|+/@e.&'aeiouAEOIU'
```

Straight-forward approach

### Explanation

```
2|+/@e.&'aeiouAEOIU'  Input: string S
     e.&'aeiouAEOIU'  Test each char in S for membership in 'aeiouAEOIU'
  +/@                 Sum those values
2|                    Take it modulo 2 and return
```

Comment: Haha, I just posted a J answer (now deleted) 1 byte longer than this. Nice job!

Comment: Where is the command for "take input"?

Comment: @RosLuP This is a verb (function) that takes a single argument as input. J uses tacit programming so commands are chained together and pass values implicitly

Answer (score 2):

## C# <s>64</s> <s>62</s> <s>56</s> 50 Bytes

```
s=>1>s.Split("aeiouAEIOU".ToCharArray()).Length%2;
```

- <s>We are already using linq, so Contains saves 2 bytes over IndexOf</s>
- <s>Using the method overload of Count saves 6 bytes</s>
- Thanks to @Milk for suggesting a neat method and saving 6 more bytes

An anonymous function that takes a string and counts the odd letters then returns true if there is an odd number of them or false if there is not.

This new solution splits the string on any of the characters in the given char array. The mechanics of this flip the meaning of the `%2` result; 0 is now odd and 1 even hence the `1>`.

[Try it online here!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xWOl7z)

Comment: It's only 50 bytes to use `string.Split()` to count the vowels and you don't need LINQ. `s=>1>s.Split("aeiouAEIOU".ToCharArray()).Length%2;`

Comment: @milk Thanks for that, very neat solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 7 bytes

```
1&Uè"%v
```

[**Test it online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=MSZV6CIldg==&input=InRyZWVzIg==) Outputs 1 for odd, 0 for even.

#### How it works

```
         // Implicit: U = input string
  Uè     // Count the number of matches of the following regex in the input:
    "%v  //   /[AEIOUaeiou]/g
1&       // Take only the first bit (convert 1, 3, 5, etc. to 1, and others to 0)
         // Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 41 bytes

```
<?=count(spliti("[aeiou]",$argv[1]))%2-1;
```

This outputs -1 for truthy and 0 for falsey.

Comment: **spliti** was deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 (30 June 2009), and removed in PHP 7.0.0 (03 Dec 2015), so this submission should have specified a version for the language, e.g. "**PHP 5.6.26**". This submission would not have even worked in "PHP 5.2.17", the last version that didn't print a deprecation warning, because the `<?=` shorthand for `<?php echo ` was only introduced in PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
OddQ@StringCount[#,Characters@"aeiouAEIOU"]&
```

Gives True for an odd string and False for an even one.

Comment: +1 to any man or woman learning mathematica

Answer (score 2):

## q, 29 bytes

```
{mod[sum x in "aeiouAEIOU";2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs `1` for odd and `0` for even.

```
è\v u
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=6Fx2IHU&footer=Z2BldoEgb2RkYLggaVZnV/ogbSsnOvsz&input=WwoiY2F0cyIKInRyZWVzIgoiYnJ1c2giCiJDQXRzIgoiU2F2b2llIgoicmh5dGhtIgpdCi1tUg) (Includes all test cases)

```
è\v u     :Implicit input of string
è         :Count the occurrences of
 \v       :  RegEx /[aeiou]/gi
    u     :Modulo 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
ḷ{∈Ṿ}ˢḍz₂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VSy1LzlPRqQMz8lBSl2tOLyv8/3LG9@lFHx8Od@4Dchzt6q4Bq//@PViopSk0tVtJRSioqLc4A0s6OJSBucGJZfmYqkFGUUVmSkasUCwA)

The predicate fails if the input is odd and succeeds if it is even.

```
ḷ{  }ˢ       For each lowercased letter of the input,
   Ṿ         map it to the string of lowercase vowels
  ∈          if it's an element of it
     ˢ       and delete it otherwise.
      ḍ      Split the list in half.
       z₂    Are the halves the same length?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>53</s> <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 42 bytes

```java
s->(s+"#").split("(?i)[AEIOU]").length%2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7LasMwEDzbXyFUChJtBO0x6QNTcuih9GB6CjlsHNWSK9lCuw6Y4G93N7TkNDuzuzPTwQlW3fFn8TENmUTH3Izkg6lyhgk3ZRoPwTeiCYAoPsD34lwW/yISEMNp8EcReaVqyr5vd3sBuUV9uSyuElmkBtCieBZnSdlalPfykEd0jG8VXWgNbGZ5yG4iF@W8YYu/Kgb5B6K6@mgTIakFVy8K7@SN1AZT8KSkevV6V23fP7/2LAbbt@RuH58elqIotPke8hYap@oJyUYzjLReJ@5IodecNpfz8gs)

Edit: Saved <s>a byte</s> 2 bytes thanks to @JonathanFrech
Edit: Saved another 9 bytes thanks to @Deadcode

Comment: `return 1>(...` to `return(...<1` possibly?

Comment: Also, could you not use `(?i)[aeiou]` instead of `[aeiouAEIOU]`?

Comment: You can [drop 9 bytes by using a shorthand syntax for returning a single expression](https://tio.run/##dZBBT8JAEIXv/RVjjckWpUGPlELQYGKicmg8EQ5Lu6WD22nTnYLE8NtxpHjReJrsvPe@fbsbvdX9TfZ@xLKuGoaNnMOW0YZ5SyljRWEvgj9iL/JSq52DF40Enx5A3a4spuBYs4xthRmUoqmEG6T1Ygm6WbvgZAV4PLNHnXpzX1XWaBpDDvHR9cfKXfuXfhC62iIrX00wWExnT/O3pSytoTUXV3ej22MktCTVRKYBpLpliIHM7menkr1jU4ZIgbyBGDAeRLAr0BpQJ39YaPdqPlgFUg0wV3gRD4JzrBK9ln5sSX0D4tvo1L4rDVYu6yAkhGckI67O8Cuv8lDXtd0rG8AE/HmWDQF8GII/2xqS8V/OinA4HI7cGOO8VdO6wnuYsvMSLT9svKbYc1F@AQ "Java (JDK) – Try It Online").

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
A∑∷
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJB4oiR4oi3IiwiIiwicmh5dGhtIl0=)

Answer (score 2):

## C# 36 Bytes

```
s=>s.Count("aeiouAEIOU".Contains)%2;
```

Returns 1 for odd, 0 for even.

[Try it online here!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fVAae8)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>8</s>, 7 bytes

```
13Y2mso
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTNZMm1zbw&input=J1Nhdm9pZSc)

Explanation:

```
13Y2    % Push the string 'aeiouAEIOU', a predefined literal. 
    m   % For each char of the input that is in that string, push a one. For every other element, push a zero.
     s  % Sum this array
      o % Mod 2
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 10 bytes

```
l1~Vm/s 2%
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=l1%7EVm%2Fs+2%25&input=trees&warnings=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Actually, 17 bytes

Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=w7nilZ0iYWVpb3UiYOKVm2NgTc6jMSY&input=ImFscGhhYmV0Ig)

```
ù╝"aeiou"`╛c`MΣ1&
```

**Ungolfing**

```
                    Implicit input s.
ù╝                  Add s.lower() to register 1.
  "aeiou"`  `M      Push the string "aeiou" and map the following function over it.
          ╛         Push register 1 to stack.
           c        Count the occurrences of "a", then "e", etc.
              Σ     Sum the counts of these occurrences.
               1&   x&1 == x%2.
                    Implicit return.
```

Comment: You don't have to output the actual words `even` and `odd`. Anything that is false and true in your language qualifies

Comment: Ah. Thanks @TonHospel. I had not reread the specification since I first saw in chat. Will edit my answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 18/19 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input on STDIN, prints `0` for even, `1` for odd

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=1&lc=~y;aeiou;
```

Must be put in a file, but the file must ***not*** have a final newline giving 18 bytes. This is admittedly abusing the perl counting rules a bit since this actually doesn't work when run in a `-e` commandline which implicitely adds a final `\n` which makes the program not work. So more honest but 19 bytes is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=1&lc=~y;aeiou;;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
0lel"aeiou"f{&,^}
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=MGxlbCJhZWlvdSJmeyYsXn0&input=dHJlZXM)

#### Explanation

```
0                 e# Push 0
 l                e# Read line from input
  el              e# Convert to lowercase
   "aeiou"        e# Push this string
          f{   }  e# Map code block to each char of the input and the string "aeiou"
            &     e# Set intersection of each input char with the "aeiou". The result
                  e# is either that char or the empty string
             ,    e# Length. Gives 0 or 1
              ^   e# Binary XOR. Uses the initial 0 the first time
                  e# Implicitly display
```

Comment: `lel_"aeiou"--,1&` saves a byte.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks! That's very clever. But it's a significantly different approach, you should post it yourself

Answer (score 1):

### R, 164 bytes

I'm sure this can be done better, but it's still good practice.

```
f<-function(w){
l<-"aeiouAEIOU"
c<-0
for(i in 1:10){
for(j in 1:nchar(w)){
if(substr(l,i,i)==substr(w,j,j)){c<-c+1}}}
if(c%%2==0){print("F")}else{print("T")}}
```

### input/output

```
> f("trees")
[1] "F"
> f("brush")
[1] "T"
> f("CAts")
[1] "T"
> f("Savoie")
[1] "F"
> f("rhythm")
[1] "F"
```

"F" for false and "T" for true.

Comment: Welcome to codegolf fellow R-user. May I recommend the following approach rather to reduce it to 117 bytes: `function(w){a=substr;l="aeiouAEIOU";c=0;for(i in 1:10){for(j in 1:nchar(w))if(a(l,i,i)==a(w,j,j))c=c+1};cat(c%%2!=0)}`. In other words, use `=` for assignment rather than `<-`, removed some unnessecary `{...}` as well, aliasing the `substr()` function to `a` since you use it twice. Finally instead of printing out a `T` or `F` string, just print the logical equivalents instead with the `cat()` function rather than `print`.

Comment: Also, I would recommend to check out my vectorized solution [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94011/56989). There I also use `readline()` rather than defining a full function which is shorter when only one input is required.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will look at all of your suggestions Billywob.

Answer (score 1):

### Bash + coreutils, 37 bytes

```sh
bc<<<!`sed s:[^aeiou]::ig\;q|wc -m`%2
```

The input word is taken from STDIN. Output is 1 if the word is odd, or 0 if it is even.

**Explanation:**

```sh
       sed s:[^aeiou]::ig\;q     # remove even letters from input and exit sed
       |wc -m                    # count remaining chars (odd letters + 1 for \n)
bc<<<!`                     `%2  # apply mod 2 and invert the boolean result
```

**Run example:**

```sh
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ ./odd_word.sh
trees
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 43 Bytes

```
<?=preg_match_all("#[aeiou]#i",$argv[1])%2;
```

Comment: Following the rules directly, just `preg_match_all("#[aeiou]#i",$argv[1])%2` qualifies.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 132 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ps=
set s=%s%%s:a=%%s:e=%%s:i=%%s:o=%%s:u=%
:l
if "%s%"=="" exit/b0
if "%s:~1%"=="" exit/b1
set s=%s:~2%
goto l
```

Takes input on STDIN, exits with `ERRORLEVEL` equal to `1` if the word is odd, `0` if it is even. Works by multiplying all the vowels by five and other letters by six, then calculating the parity of the resulting length.

Answer (score 1):

## Turtlèd, <s>91 65 64 52 47</s> 67 bytes

More bytes because now takes case insensitive input

Changed approach again

does * for even, else o for odd

(trailing space)

```
!-u[*+.(a,)(e,)(i,)(o,)(u,)(A,)(E,)(I,)(O,)(U,)(*d(*'ou)(o'*u))_]'
```

It goes through input, writing it down on one square, each time there is a vowel, it moves down, flips the state of a the output cell, continues until EOF of input, then removes the cell where it writes down all the characters.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, <s>47</s> <s>44</s> 43 Bytes

```
print(#arg[2]:gsub('[^aeiouAEIOU]','')%2>0)
```

Takes the input via the command line, replaces all non-vowels with nothing, (removes them), prints true if the length of that is odd, false otherwise.

### Old submission

```
_,n=arg[2]:gsub('[aeiouAEIOU]','')print(n%2~=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Go, 93 bytes

```
func(s string)int{n:=0;for _,c:=range s{for _,d:=range"aeiouAEIOU"{if c==d{n++}}};return n%2}
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5PS8MwGMbPzad4DQgJkzI9tkQYsoMXJ0zPkrVJF1zfjCSdupLPXpNtIru8h9/z5306O@1l8yk7Bb00SEy/ty4Ao5tBG0tran06ug@UEz1gc3IxDqOuxJQB8@CDM9hxg2HESsxrbR183DWVcBJTrx/PoL0AKpWxw2L5vHqno9HQCNGOOJvFGGunwuAQ8PYhToVvJKJyUAk4rSlf1Nf6zJj15Tq0BnkNx/STFPnHJVBmU95IiiL1s@PjPA/uQ/mahoZd0mKKifuk@9z@l3tT34HxS0ozz@FGwFWW0VXbVgCUR1A7r66k5UFhlaXU8I99KowkTsEp5cnGDX5LnhbBk7U8WKOI2/6Ebf8L "Go – Try It Online") Note: The return value is `0` for even and `1` for odd, which isn't directly usable as a boolean in Go, and must be compared against zero. It would take +2 bytes to return boolean.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 78 bytes

Solution is based on counting the number of vowels:

```
s=strsplit;w=s(readline(),"")[[1]];v=s("aeiouAEIOU","")[[1]];sum(w%in%v)%%2!=0
```

#### Explanation

Unfortunately most functions in R relating to strings work on vectors of characters rather than full strings, thus the solution converts input into a vector using `strsplit` and checks whether this contains any vowels => sum the number of vowels and check if odd/even.

Also I found that using `v=s("aeiouAEIOU","")[[1]]` was shorter than manually inputting a vector of vowels which would have worked if only lower or upper case letters were used.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 49 bytes

```
f=function(x)nchar(gsub("[^aeiou]","",x,i=T))%%2==0
```

Examples:

```
> f("cats")
[1] FALSE

> f("Savoie")
[1] TRUE
```

If it doesn't need a function and I can assume `x` is the input:

### 36 bytes:

```
!nchar(gsub("[^aeiou]","",x,i=T))%%2
```

If I can allow an output of 0 for even and 1 for odd:

### 35 bytes:

```
nchar(gsub("[^aeiou]","",x,i=T))%%2
```

## Explanation

I'm substituting all vowels with blank character, ignoring case (`i=T`). This works because the `i` is enough to unambigiously identify the `ignore.case` argument and `T` is short for `TRUE`. Then count the odd characters and see if there's a remainder. If a number isn't a good response, I use `!` (not) to coerce the 0/1 to TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: Your primary answer is reversed (the question states that odd=truthy), but even that way with coercion it could be `%%2<1`. And `i=T` can be changed to `1`. Without coercion this yields [**44 bytes**](https://tio.run/##Hco9a8MwEADQXb9CCILuQEPSMcJDCd0MGTp06Aco9ikWuKegk0Lq0t/upl0fr6yxW2PjoabMcEMeplDgLO0E5vUjUMrt3Thj3M3tEDebh1W6rddLF9NMYKSOiQ16FXOBXifW0i6XQiIvoXDis0ChMPaJSWBBxG@ldYogOIQK9o0teul2/q5/kCLNQhChR2eP47jX2jr7dCXea4vo/1OP/kcNc77HBf1aC5GoU2kyqcNjFfUcrjmRKtNXnT5/AQ), or [**42 bytes** using pryr](https://tinyurl.com/2p9d97y7), or [**37 bytes** using R v4.1.0](https://tinyurl.com/3h7339hb).

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL (SQL Server 2014), 217 bytes

### Golfed

```
declare @ table(a char)declare @i int=1while @i<=len(@a)begin insert into @ values(SUBSTRING(@a,@i,1))set @i=@i+1 end select count(*)%2from @ where a in('a','e','i','o','u')
```

### Usage

First declare the variable @a as a char of some sort and assign the input like so

```
declare @a varchar(max) = 'CAts'
```

Output will either be `1` for odd, or `0` for even

### Ungolfed

```
declare @input varchar(max) = 'rhythm'

declare @temp table ( letter char(1) ) -- table to hold each letter of the word

declare @i int = 1

while @i <= len(@input) -- split each letter, and each row in @temp will have one letter
begin
    insert into @temp values (SUBSTRING(@input, @i, 1))
    set @i = @i + 1
end

-- count the vowels and mod two to get if there's an even number of vowels or an odd number
select count(*) % 2
from @temp
where letter in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') -- use sql's case insensitive strings
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy (39 Bytes)

```
{s->s.collect{/aeiou/=~it?1:0}.sum()%2}
```

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5195711326978048

Answer (score 1):

### Julia, 53 Bytes

```
f(s)=sum(map(x->x in ["aeiouAEIOU"...]?1:2,[s...]))%2
```

replace odd characters with 1 and even characters with 2, then sum up. if the sum is even, then the word is even.

Answer (score 1):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), 27 bytes

```
Q_e\'a-'e-'i-'o-'u-e\;-e01?
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 91 bytes

```
foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c)$n+=substr_count("AEIOU",strtoupper($c));if($n%2==0)echo 1;
```

Outputs `1` for even word, empty for odd word.

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/896799677863c639879f04637eb9f56c633cc0d0)

Testing code:

```
$wa = array('trees','brush','CAts','Savoie','rhythm');
foreach ($wa as $w) {
    $n = 0;
    foreach(str_split($w) as $c) 
        $n+=substr_count("AEIOU",strtoupper($c));
    if ($n%2==0) echo 1;
}
```

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c525cdb97b50b02537dbad91226566313b8ff43f)

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 127 bytes

```
(if(= 0(modulo(for/sum((i(map(λ(i)(ormap(λ(x)(equal? i x))(string->list"aieouAEIOU")))(string->list s))))(if i 1 0))2))#f #t)
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f s)
  (let* ((vl (string->list "aieouAEIOU"))
         (od (λ(i) (ormap (λ (x) (equal? i x)) vl)))
         (ol (map od (string->list s)))
         (s (count (λ(i) i) ol ))
         (m (modulo s 2)))
    (if (= m 0) "even" "odd")
  ))
```

A longer (240 bytes) but more direct version:

```
(let*((vl(string->list"aieouAEIOU"))(od(λ(i)(ormap(λ(x)(equal? i x))vl))))(let lp((l(string->list s))
(st #t)(d 0))(cond((null? l)(if d"odd""even"))(st(lp(cdr l)#f(if(od(car l))#t #f)))
(else(lp(cdr l)#f(if(equal? d(od(car l)))#f #t))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s)
  (let* ((vl (string->list "aieouAEIOU"))
         (od (λ (i) (ormap (λ (x) (equal? i x)) vl) )))
    (let loop ((l (string->list s))
               (starting #t)
               (odd 0))
      (cond
        ((null? l) 
         (if odd "odd" "even"))
        (starting
         (loop (rest l) #f
               (if(od (first l))
                  #t #f )))
        (else 
         (loop (rest l) #f 
               (if (equal? odd
                           (od (first l)))
                   #f #t)))))))
```

Testing:

```
(f "trees")
(f "brush")
(f "CAts")
(f "Savoie")
(f "rhythm")
```

Output:

```
"even"
"odd"
"odd"
"even"
"even"
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY47DsIwEET7nGLlNLsFItADihAFFQXiAIbYyQo7Bn9QOBt34EohQGjo3sxoNOPl6axinxvZ1uA/IsNKaW4VoIZAPbLGBRRoXZWMQ@38NCSLyGjlBZ8PZELnR@4I1TVJswKGjghD9NzWk6XhEIVk5VK52e4Ogv6yYehtsR56MyiI5kS5hjxST9nwQ0SvVBBfPvoUmpHXZfzZe3lzrEbhm3tsrKD@BQ "Racket – Try It Online")

Comment: Very nice page for online evaluation of Racket code. Its a pity that Racket has not picked up in popularity.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 30 bytes

```
->w{w.count('aeiouAEIOU')%2>0}
```

Returns true for an odd word and false for an even word. The existing Ruby solution returns 0 for even words, which is a truthy value in Ruby.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNj4IwFEX3/RWPEmVcQNClTTXGuJiVC@MKWaA8hialkH7IEONvx6KZZFY3791zj3bXYaz4GG/6R5/cWqfsV1SgaN3u8H08R4vZapM@R8FTBn0tJILkP2gNARAViGD6d84aBqhKBoIv2VTILF7mnNOLoswvZJYmSbzK39RnGsgEm84OW5jPPZ7mAY/CyMu0UBaqTOawBXosyzUAhTXQwx2Vjz/Fh5PEX2MIUwn4WzSdREOI1ejjVNxbgUTXg60bQkLwtn/QVTtTk/3Omhc "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```
&rem(length(Regex.scan(~r/[aeiou]/i,&1)),2)>0
```

Anonymous function defined using the capture operator. If the number of vowels is odd, the specified word is odd, so the function returns true.

Full program with test cases:

```
s=&rem(length(Regex.scan(~r/[aeiou]/i,&1)),2)>0
# test cases
IO.puts s.("trees") # false
IO.puts s.("brush") # true
IO.puts s.("CAts")  # true
IO.puts s.("Savoie")    # false
IO.puts s.("rhythm")    # false
```

**Try it online on [ElixirPlayground](http://elixirplayground.com/) !**

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(map(s.count,"aAeEiIoOuU"))%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc6xCoMwEAbgPU8RAoUEQgdHwUFKh04dSqe2Q6wnBkwiuYvQp09VBAdvOe7j7vjHH/XBF7mr3nkwrmkNxxKTk86MEs/fkDxpYWq42lu4p6dQ6lRkAiTkFX8xPpcUFAFQaC5gAi@U3riJCfuFQ9vueqkJD/gwU7BwfBH7OaDbnX0Y60LkSwLNI2AaiFu/zliuR2O0nraFTi5d5T8)

Returns 0 for even, and 1 for odd.

**Explanation:**
Counts how many total odd letters are in the word, and returns whether that number is even (0) or odd (1).

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 32 bytes

0 is false, 1 is true.

```
{it.count{it in "aAeEiIoOuU"}%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BCsIwFET3PcUQEJKFLlwWW@nCRUFwIR4gmFiC9Ud@fxUpPXtMdVYD83jMPUofKL1sj@hcCX0WDtQZrGu0JKjSFGRzjSNJLggEZRt/CG08jRc1r7Zzuo2Ehw2kLXdDiYbZfnZ/TW0wFchZ/O/IDhXYW3cM5LXBvoRSv/2ZadH5gV4oY4o5CXs/fAE)

Answer (score 1):

## Z80Golf, 34 bytes

```
0000                restart:      
0000   cd 03 80               call   $8003   
0003   30 05                  jr   nc,letter   
0005                done:        
0005   78                     ld   a,b   
0006   e6 01                  and   1   
0008   ff                     rst   $38   
0009   76                     halt      
000a                letter:      
000a   e6 1f                  and   $1f   
000c   3d                     dec   a   
000d   28 10                  jr   z,vowel   
000f   d6 04                  sub   4   
0011   28 0c                  jr   z,vowel   
0013   d6 04                  sub   4   
0015   28 08                  jr   z,vowel   
0017   d6 06                  sub   6   
0019   28 04                  jr   z,vowel   
001b   d6 06                  sub   6   
001d   20 e1                  jr   nz,restart   
001f                vowel:       
001f   04                     inc   b   
0020   18 de                  jr   restart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZTBcoIwEIbvPMUenFE7IIkgImW8tcf20CeIEGoZBBuodWj77DQb4jgVmLKHLEk@/l02WXas3DdRyg6zOXxByk4MrJQJsItjZeO6fafcAhfDGY/2BUzo/B5@jIhVEIbTh@fHKXwDQjB9f7LdZEu9JCxfLFw@n2OwBFhH2EK9YOWhIdLgxgQvKyaqoJ0ZGoliIA74t3TEsky6iU/kbkujdwiQFXQsFXLIIzPjVcWF5jtcXOQ8uEwuxNqHPstiOTBzp0lPeu4BoV2S5YhSDaJakvRKirLCL3J8jW4wuteL7llWXdNkneTUZwZ/CZkeTYbSm6gtRCOsYtwbNea4yTSIzNIHSgbKXZun4pNnmkb5WBbI7dLlB1bRbUFKW1mVx7@y1Bkru9Ky/ijZtZb1hmQ9DW60rDtKdjdWVtWWAKdDV7k2dbfoFzoHq8IG17usiL40pb3lWGx9lZd4ntSXhz0Q@xq4kV1vGOonUfvktcgSuxTR5bnt9Lb7G/YL)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
-XV Na%:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@F/9XzciTMEvUdXK6H@tgq9CNJeCUklRamqxEpCRVFRanAFiODuWgAWCE8vyM1NBrKKMypKMXCWu2P//dfMA)

```
 XV        Regex matching [aeiou]
-          Case-insensitive
    N      Count matches in
     a     Command-line argument
      %:2  Mod 2 (the : helps with parsing)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 38 bytes

```clj
#(rem(count(re-seq #"(?i)[aeiou]"%))2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/X1mjKDVXIzm/NK8EyNItTi1UUFbSsM/UjE5MzcwvjVVS1dQ00vz/HwA)

This anonymous function outputs 1 for odd and 0 for even.

### Explanation

```clj
#"(?i)[aeiou]" ; This is a regular expression that matches a capital or lowercase vowel.
re-seq ; Returns a lazy sequence that contains all of the regex's matches from the input string.
count ; Returns the length of that sequence.
rem ; Returns the remainder when that length is divided by 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 47 bytes

```
0i1+48*%:?v~2%n>~!
26a28*2b* \
r&:{=&+r  >l3(?v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDTUNvEQkvVyr6szkg1z65OkcvILNHIQssoSUshhqtIzaraVk27SEHBLsdYw77s/39P58S0zOCMTNdiAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 34 bytes

```factor
[ [ "aeiouAEIOU"in? ] count odd? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxLCsIwFEXnXcWlC3ABOpAiIp3ooHRUHMT0STLI7@XFUsS1x0wuHDjnvpWWwHWexvvtiEyS26RCXlOGU2IQmUT2yNYL0oZT16XtC2FqwotLNrgMrZrUJ1gCm12Mw68uWNArsqEM1/Ex99af8YQOpd2EdW1QnYo41D8)

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (Perl / PCRE / Boost / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup>) + `/i` flag, 24 bytes

```
^((.*?[aeiou]){2})*+(?2)
```

Returns a match if odd; returns no match if even.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NbsIwEITvfooVsbBNaUOQeokJUVS4tgd6K9QKxSiWnJ86CSqK0ldPN6pacRrtzDezlXb2ccivQJ2EzpYfqQXqSzyj1SZ5TdY9OZeOUxMt5GotUQPRgTmjI7rKmaKByb6YyB6ohQjq9lg3iKv5fTAPhP4cQ4hv/AUmAkKgShLAIeBYnE7/CYtEIArNPPb3gI9I9A0@db4RMXs5nUIAFrLtRRchMCF7nPplqZXQK7V93ig1vHP@MIvfUm3K9iC6ZS9mdzxeimHwYOyC/krzyuqakMZplF16KY0mLrs2WU6IB/jqBjq6ts7IU9LUPw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDLbsIwEEX3@YrBRMSm4bnEjaKqTSukCqrQHVArBEMiOQ/ZBrVCfHs6oYtWXVi2r@@c65k6q5v7sM5qcDUEQEYEhlBreRRa1ipJJfVGw34oRJYoK9KqqHMl9YZuGN/EI@P54OE6oCiOsjWUVpbWUCGe56@REMyHCUMkGZ1ywp1DpambB2PuquCABYau3p/mC8bZBfIDddXaWK1kiSc2mGyDgGxKwtBsTjt8Qdkf@4MJ4zd3zmSaVa2FA1In3AHUgf4yej1EjredwOt6GOEWwa23IrFpRl3to4VDC/npWSXGCqk1/pJ1grc4ehGLpYjieBmHJGr1GZAZdYuQLPf7GeCFRGdZooqcK8bfWMRVhF//zYwy3nxQisNcJzKvTlt2mV5Z/46GU9Y0XWg5ID@TolbSOI7VErdVcq5y6ejsy2aF43QBY/@YdvpkMufxwZpv) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBjtowEL3nK6YgLTYb6MJKPSSwqK16rrTtYVeURsYMidXEsWxnWUD8elPbgZatD/Z4/GbevJdwpUY5521fSF42G4TZuq6Nfa8xx9dxodRDxAumIVPLFczhsfdpt/u1vm@e9/un78WHXUHan4SMh4slQ1E3K3qcnujwliymtKX/Y3sxDNU8U7eTNPpHKByfRlY9REJaUNrtGWpda8JraSwE/mGFxrAc6dHYTZJwB4DZDM5ZH4Y8yk2ZgkbbaAmT9BRaVkxIQuEYgVtq6dhKlETR0WQ1v0uhcZj7aWah9jdfkLsggENPhxcydw@qsSl0MwWTkiS45OiIit@kkkRwZpCml6ypmOUF7Apmu87bWgPxXAdPGnhytKWQSDqBQsYdpWtymE8u4/sltkAOFNybt4YMfsgBTd@8hsLl3QpubuASv5sP@gP6Fxa88F5vyfXkmUGmedF1iMPAsRNIYQG9r5tNAtCDBHpfXlC644p2u9PCYlc35pkzjdCzgrERB/S3SeyV1l5TqDuF/fy1nOWntg@@M@Arq1SJJorcn@GOb@ylFhjpYm@LKor64Ea5Aq11Y4ro80drfvNtyXLTjsogKgua/gA) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBT8MwDIXv@RUmPTQZpWrHLSiapqlCXJjEjl2RCvVopDStknRsQvz2ksIOSHCybD9/78nD2be9uZ1UN/TWgzu7xOIbnogFCZZSOj0zli5WZY2qHyv@sfzki2u2WvIpLMtc3OTVHSiZkUNvQYMyMyN1vlFGEAB1ACVgsMp4xude5j9TjYZpDrVpQJcBImW8N7EALXWZzdR/ZFl1JeMoiC4W/ejTd6s8MrptGgFA55Pv/KnD2r62zCagk8vo4f5x@1Rs1ruCA2qHQIsjGgF0DvYHqfkUwSwAPNXdoNER4i2GsquPvUJi2/C7jpAIgvkv0YsdXUs2a@@@AA) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>

Explanation:

`^` - Anchor to the beginning of the string

Each `(.*?[aeiou]){2}` matches the first two "odd" characters it finds, consuming them as it goes. The `(`...`)*+` wrapping it causes this to consume as many pairs as it can (minimum zero), where the `+` makes it a possessive quantifier, holding onto the first complete match (disabling backtracking).

At this point, the maximum even number of "odd" characters has been consumed, and if the word is "odd", exactly one "odd" character will remain, otherwise none will. `(?2)` attempts to match one more "odd" character, calling `(.*?[aeiou])` (group 2) as a subroutine.

## Regex (Ruby / PCRE) + `/i` flag, 25 bytes

```
^((.*?[aeiou]){2})*+\g<2>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1Pb4JAFMTv@ykGSPzXSpQjdGuIkqYXTbQ3pQTDq2yyIFkWlTTtV0cobdLT5M38Zp6qjnWjwLGlE90KO6crVv6bbyuKk8fedN3Xl/VmGyz9XeBB8JmHayokQfIT6ZIB4gPC6Pyi0qUHypOOm3tdIPfTeci5echNr23I/cy2p074Q/VVQ9qUFbpeYDBo8Vlo8KE1bDOgUCLXkODfUFjA3CSJC5hwYQYXylv52/kl@zOKgvUqipr30cieLPYxiXMVjj@dr/Hk4XB6cp6bxkI3ALrFWSGpZEwramUXX86CmEprnWaMWWg//oOOqipTtvR1eQc) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDLbsIwEEX3@YrBRMSm4bnEpKhq0wqpgip0R6gVwJBIzkO2Qa0Q355O6KJVF5bt6zvneqZKq3o6q9IKXA0BkAGBPlRaHoWWlUp2knqDfncmRJooK3ZlXmVK6pjGjMfRwHg@eLgOKIqjbAyFlYU1VIjn@WsoBPNhxBBJBqeMcOdQaupmwZC7KjhggaGr96f5gnF2gexAXbU2VitZ4In1RpsgIHFBGJrNaYsvKPtDvzdi/ObOmNylZWPhgNQRdwB1oL@MTgeRw00r8NoeRrh5cOstT@wupa720cKhgfz0rBJjhdQaf8lawVsUvojFUoRRtIxmJGz0CZAJdfMZWe73E8ALCc@yQBU5V4y/sYirCL/@mxllvP6gFIe5TmRWnjbsMr6y7l18nI7v67oNDQjkZ5JXShrHsVritkrOZSYdnX7ZNHecNmDuH9NWn0zqPD5Y8w0) - PCRE

This is a port of the Perl/PCRE/Boost regex to Ruby's style of subroutine call. This syntax is also supported by PCRE.

## Regex (Java or better) + `/i` flag, 29 bytes

```
^((.*?[aeiou]){2})*+.*[aeiou]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdb9MwEMDf81fcUmm1s@EVHheFqUxFqsQKIoiXMZCbOI07xwn2Ze1U5W8vlzZDGywv5/v63VfW8kG@Wef3e101tUNYky50LaIYnlta1OZVm1Mrte09Tbs0OoPMSO/hRmoLu8HkUSKJh1rnUJGDpei0XYF0K397xwFLV288zLaZalDXlBgAfNRGQZFYtTk8WSiyOleC/CGPP7RFoZzKvyqZKwfLQ9hLI3vKHNSC83io688x3pQ9nzGfLGkEmX/SVjHOTxLbGsN1wbxQv1tpPAsvoigKOd@9DD0SGMNXATsi4F8CAS6IsKS4@9ifJeMfdtxLjLujrfsiEZWz4JLhRdNWTV/Anz9Zrqfp7Nd8kc4W6fzb/PuMx7SmNJPW0gq0bVqEBPqpBxtLHz2qSmjL6W4WQSeTGIbBD/GilH6htkh9ww6oZX2STPiQVpO/oX2hsawHJG/7elTxuERDxY4QS4RhJ8QAZoRRdoUl4@8ncHoKRmSldFNkE9rOeDTmh/v2343ErKTmK2I5UR01Zojzbw8Fq0Shbc44XEH4Oc8vAUK4hHD2oCwJHnf/5fSgruuC/n77n4yJ6OpWKl23d3z3ruPRmYgGfd8faD@CHgZqK6vGKB8E6BSJVNKPqwJXPmJZBcEIqPqzoKVrfRlcT9H/AQ)

This is a port of the regex to flavors that have no subroutine calls, but do have possessive quantifiers.

## Regex (.NET or better) + `/i` flag, 32 bytes

```
^(?>((.*?[aeiou]){2})*).*[aeiou]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7BbsIwDIbveQorRGpS0YrtWMRgqnbYYdphR8SkjhoSKSRdklIG6rN3odrELjvZv/z5sxvbofMStR6YW6wd7vG0KQqDHV8lwztfPnCep8t1hcq2G3G570Uq8vQnD8lqSkt7aJTGevq8N9ZhWXmkYs7Oi9l8F3O1lZxpUAaYMk0bxIUAqB1nZ3HpnAqYSetDH/m7cQCRzvATKIXMOmB6PduMeUIFXHd7QO1xbAFuBsiMjW9rZRAo46PI5S9V2Er00SnidvJa1wVA8qtIno5oipgFvYrJfz6mST9M4EoDnqpDo9ETEhzG8lYdrULi5FeQB0ImEG/8gT5c6yUpH4P/Bg)

This is a port of the regex to flavors that have no subroutine calls or possessive quantifiers, so the clause `(`...`)*+` has been changed to `(?>(`...`)*)` to replace a possessive quantifier with an atomic group.

## Regex (ECMAScript or better) + `/i` flag, 36 bytes

```
^(?=(((.*?[aeiou]){2})*))\1.*[aeiou]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxdS8MwFIbv8ysyCss5Zes2ES9aYhHZteAu54TYnq3RNC1JOvfBfnvthoJXL8/79an2yhdOt2HqW12Sqxv7RcfeSUvf/JV2y0MLcJKPs7h/h1wCQBLna0W66TZ4vrtgjPi2SOJfq49nJ0xCswpO2x1g4o0uCB4m03uccKEFZtvGgZbzDIx0pEqjLQHiSNrOmEzLBZ4Z53oLGtvhIwBmAxs@HnOznm9GUkTiCm0XfHBgklqFogKHuXgpy5RzkYrlnmzKxW3518Ps0kf8mnA6qLo15BkLjgZZqX2jibnqGKqasYgPR/9KH67zFXt@Cv4H) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBS8QwEIXv@RVjemhSatnqrRKWZSnixQX32K1QbZYG0qRM0tVF/O01wT0I7ml4wzfvDW86@8Ga@0WNk0UP7uxylARBAFJKl1e2FoyxIls3nVR2bvnX3TfPOD@URXZZLQFsyuq2bB9AiRU5WgQNykSzwvlemYoAqCOoCiZUxjMetSh/t1oapjl0pgfdBBMh0oNJK9BCN6voegVbtTciTQJ0ibCzLz5Qecnoru8rABpPUBZOdvg@MMxB51E/PT7vXurtZl9zkNpJoPVJmgpofOmfmeZLAhEA@dmNk5aOEI8yjH13sir0NIT6RkISCLF/oDec3UC2G@9@AA) - Python

This is a port of the regex to flavors that have no subroutine calls, atomic groups, or possessive quantifiers, so the clause `(`...`)*+` has been changed to `(?=((`...`)*))\1` to replace a possessive quantifier with an emulation of an atomic group (using an atomic lookahead, group capture, and backreference).

## Regex (POSIX ERE or better) + `/i` flag, 51 bytes

```
^(([^aeiou]*[aeiou]){2})*[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NbsIwEITP9VOMnIgkSJFKjwk5VKiVeuqBYxSqUK/qSCYGO9AfzLOnTqCl6l5G8@3s7Lq2sjdUC6RGIIpg5vPo5TJRv4rjclVTo/fVtDxrcrw7JdP/9NeH/c81e5eNIjw9LgtcPkA5VyJtwUPFUeVCsxvvvxBaVM7Rq9S5LWb5yM6Z4YCHR5XdZrMTRwEejDQewmPG0ZuhLdJmR94bjskE43L48yxEBnA4d2UPB2oz8CS/Il/DhG6pDzBsQR/1ZqvIMtYZ8rKsD7ohZuRnJzeMBfC9f0Jrs7eSLe47@w0)

This is a port of the regex to flavors that have no subroutine calls and no way to disable backtracking.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 28 bytes

```
<<<$[${#1//[^aeiouAEIOU]}%2]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwU21tPwiBUMFjZKi1NRihaSi0uIMhWTHkmKF4MSy_MxUhaKMypKMXM2lpSVpuhZ7bGxsVKJVqpUN9fWj4xJTM_NLHV09_UNja1WNYiFKFkApKA0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 39 bytes

```kotlin
{it.count{"aeiouAEIOU".contains(it)}%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://pl.kotl.in/IDd5iBSFI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 33 bytes

```arturo
$=>[%match.count&"[aeiouAEIOU]"2]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?OJSIDw)

Returns 0 for even, 1 for odd.

Answer (score 1):

## **excel, 76 bytes**

```
=MOD(SUM(--(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)={"a","e","i","o","u"})),2)
```

put the input in cell A1 and put the output formula in whichever other cell u want

returns 0 for even and 1 for odd

excel equates upper case and lower case letters when doing a direct comparison or something idk i just started using it for work and i'm still figuring it out

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms thank u :)

Comment: Consider using the `sequence` function in place of `row(indirect("1:"&...))`. this gets your solution down to 66 bytes `=Mod(Sum(--(Mid(A1,Sequence(Len(A1)),1)={"a","e","I","o","u"})),2)`

Comment: @TaylorAlexRaine the sequence function came out after this challenge was posted didn't it? that's why i didn't use it. if it actually came out before then i'll modify my answer but i just didn't want to cheat :)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 143 bytes

*Output is a boolean which is true if the word is odd.*

```
public static boolean isOdd(char c){
return c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u';
}


public static boolean isOdd(String k){
  boolean y=false;
  for(char x:k.toLowerCase().toCharArray())
    if(isOdd(x))
      y=(y?false:true);
  return y;
}
```

Golfed:

```
boolean i(String k){boolean y=false;for(char c:k.toLowerCase().toCharArray())if(c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u')y=!y;return y;}
```

***Edit:***

- Fixed Case-sensitivity

Comment: Did you run this against the third test case?

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
i`[aeiou]
1
T`Ll`
11
```

(there's a mandatory additional empty line, but formatting ignores it)

Returns `1` for odd words, and *void* for even ones.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=aWBbYWVpb3VdCjEKVGBMbGAKMTEK&input=Q0F0c2Vl)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 59 bytes

```
s->s.chars().map(c->"aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c)<0?0:1).sum()%2;
```

## Ungolfed test program

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Function<String, Integer> func = s -> s.chars().map( c -> "aeiouAEIOU".indexOf( c ) < 0 ? 0 : 1 ).sum() % 2;

    System.out.println( func.apply( "cat" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 17 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
2|≢⍞∩'aeiouAEIOU'
```

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B2%7C%u2262%u2375%u2229%27aeiouAEIOU%27%7D%A8%27trees%27%20%27brush%27%20%27CAts%27%20%27Savoie%27%20%27rhythm%27&run)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 56 bytes

```
#S::((& 1 (~ (length (split S (regex "[aeiou]" "i"))))))
```

- Odd words: returns 1
- Even words: returns 0

This was one of my test cases for developing my language. It was modified extensively after this challenge was posted to support running code such as this.

---

This is the same logic as the JavaScript response above. The language is a simplistic Lisp-like dialect with a fairly small interpreter.

Ungolfed:

```
(
    (var F #S::(
        (var L (split S (regex "[aeiou]" "i")))
        (& 1 (~ (length L)))
    ))
    (print (call F "brush"))
)
```

There is not currently an online repl to test this in, but there is a variation of this challenge in [one of the provided examples](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp/blob/master/l_src/oddword.lithp) that can be run with the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 128 bytes

```
boolean f(String k){return k.chars().flatMap(i->"aeiouAEIOU".contains(((char)i)+"")?IntStream.of(1):IntStream.of(0)).sum()%2>0;}
```

There's definitely a better way than using `Instream.of(0)` and `Instream.of(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 131 bytes

```
rEeEEeeeeErEeEEeeEeErEeEEeEeeErEeEEeEEEErEeEEEeEeEREeEeeeeeEREeeEeeeeeREEREEEerrEEEEEerEEeeREEEEReeReReREEeREEEEeeeRREeeeReEEEEReEE
```

Ouputs `0` for odd, `1` for even.

[Try it online!](//soaku.github.io/Pepe/#!c2!ca!ci!cu!d6!ab!8hF!p@&0!k!r/..TDt-!d@nN)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 39 bytes

```powershell
($args|sls "[aeiou]"-a).Matches.Count%2
```

Explanation:

- Takes arguments from the predefined `$args`;
- Selects all matches to vowel characters (`sls` is alias for [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String). By default, matches are not case-sensitive);
- Takes the Matches.Count, and %2 to check whether it's odd/even.

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

($args|sls "[aeiou]"-a).Matches.Count%2

}

@(
    ,("trees", $false)
    ,("brush", $true)
    ,("CAts", $true)
    ,("Savoie", $false)
    ,("rhythm", $false)

) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 0
True: 1
True: 1
True: 0
True: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8**: **88** bytes

```
s->s.chars().map(c->"aeiouAEIOU".contains((char)c+"")?-1:1).reduce(1,(x,y)->x*y)<0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdAxb4MwEIbhnV9hebLbYJW1NFRRlEgdqg6oU9XhMCY4BRv5jigI8dsprbKWTrc8rz7pznCB@Fx@zV1fNFYz3QAiewXrxsg6MqECbdhxLLxvDDhWiZyCdSeGMp2iW4QEtJyLtyVrl/RmPj4ZhBPKMTqyim1njDNUuoaAQqoWOqHjjIOxvt8dXt7eudLe0ZKjED9K6nvO5XOcPCZSBVP22ohkI66bQcbZ9W6QTw/pnA9IplW@J9Utm9Q4UalKcA2EXMo0@gtQMGZdFKHHelXsd/@M5LD8xKySUA9Ut79kmuZv)

Dang it, I didn't see the older Java solution that used regex. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(c in"aeiouAEIOU"for c in x)%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyNZITNPKTE1M7/U0dXTP1QpLb9IASSmUKGpavT/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

### brev, 62 bytes

```
(as-list odd?(c count(fn((as-list(c member x))"aeiouAEIOU"))))
```

Example:

```
(map
 (as-list odd? (c count (fn ((as-list (c member x)) "aeiouAEIOU"))))
 '("trees" "brush" "CAts" "Savoie" "even"))

=> (#f #t #t #f #f)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 19 bytes

*18 bytes for code; +1 byte for -p flag*

```perl
$_=s/[aeiou]//gi%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rZYPzoxNTO/NFZfPz1T1ej//5Ki1NRirqSi0uIMLmfHkmKu4MSy/MxUrqKMypKM3H/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Prints 0 for even words; 1 for odd.

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 154 Bytes

This is a complete `program` according to ISO standard 7185 “Standard Pascal”.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var n:integer;begin n:=0;repeat n:=n+ord(input^in['A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u']);get(input)until EOF;write(odd(n))end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program oddWord(input, output);
var
    n: integer;
begin
    n := 0;
    
    repeat
    begin
        n := n + ord(input^ in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']);
        get(input);
    end
    until EOF(input);
    
    write(output, odd(n));
end.
```

Comment: It would be helpful to me if you explained why you are downvoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṃSɗ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWyx7ubA4-OX1JcVJyMVRowZLkxJJiCBsA)

##### Explanation

```python
ṃSɗ  # Implicit input
ṃ    # For each letter: 1 if vowel, 0 if consonant
 S   # Sum the resulting list of 1s and 0s
  ɗ  # Get its parity (mod 2)
     # Implicit output
```