# URL-Friendly Titles

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

People on this site really love to embellish their post titles...

```
Stewie's sequence: + * - / + * - /
```

However, when this title needs to be included in the page URL, it is simplified:

```
stewies-sequence
```

---

## The Challenge

Your task is to create a program or function which, given a string representing a post title, outputs/returns its "URL-Friendly" conversion.

**The algorithm is:**

- Convert to lowercase (where applicable)
- Replace every space (), period (`.`), comma(`,`) or slash (`/`) with a dash (`-`)
- Remove any non-alphanumeric characters, except dashes.
- Minify groups of adjacent dashes (`a---b -> a-b`), remove any that are leading/trailing.

<sub>Please note that this algorithm is a simplification, and may not always produce the same results as the site's real method.</sub>

---

## Rules

- You can assume that input:

  - Will not be empty.
  - Will contain at least one alphanumeric character.
  - Will only contain characters in the ASCII range 32-126 (printable)
- Full programs or functions are permitted.
- A builtin which does the exact task specification is *not* permitted.
- **This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution (in bytes) wins!**

---

## Test Cases

Most posts on this site will serve as tests, but here's a handy list:

```
Loading... Forever       -> loading-forever
N(e(s(t))) a string      -> nest-a-string
"Hello, World!"          -> hello-world
URL-Friendly titles      -> url-friendly-titles

C.U.S.R.S                -> c-u-s-r-s
1+2+3+4+...+n = -1/12?   -> 1234-n-1-12
How can I use cmp(a,b)   -> how-can-i-use-cmpa-b
```

Some longer ones...

```
Export The $PATH Variable, Line-By-Line   -> export-the-path-variable-line-by-line
Do n and n^3 have the same set of digits? -> do-n-and-n3-have-the-same-set-of-digits
Quine Anagrams! (Cops' Thread)            -> quine-anagrams-cops-thread
The Golfer Adventure - Chapter 1          -> the-golfer-adventure-chapter-1
Bootloader golf: Brainf***                -> bootloader-golf-brainf
```

And some edge-case checking samples (feel free to suggest more):

```
0123   ->   0123
a a1   ->   a-a1
2-1=1  ->   2-11
```

Comment: What about leading `-`s? Will they have to be removed? For example in `asdf-`, will the last `-` have to be removed?

Comment: Can we use a built-in function to check if the char is alphanumeric like this `if(isalphanum(ch))...`

Comment: @KritixiLithos _Minify groups of adjacent dashes (a---b -> a-b), **remove any that are leading/trailing.**_ I guess this should make you clear.

Comment: And what about `_` underscores? My code works except when there are underscores.

Comment: @L3viathan Doesn't matter now, I changed my code so that even underscores will be removed

Comment: @MukulKumar yes, that's fine. A built-in is only disallowed if it completes this exact algorithm.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I just did some poking around and it looks like they actually create dashes,, but because I don't want to invalidate answers, so I'll accept any behaviour with underscores.

Comment: Anything about underscores?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 you can either replace them with a dash or treat them as invalid characters. really they should create dashes but I don't want to invalidate all the answers by changing the rules now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Retina, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
T`L`l
[^a-z ,-9]+

\W+
-
^-|-$
```

(The program has a trailing newline)

I'm not sure I can squeeze more out of this. This should cover everything. Came similar to Mama Fun Roll's. [Another 33 bytes version using recursive regexes](http://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=retina&p=C0nwScjhitbR1Y/V5tLl0k6I063RVamJjkvUrYpJ0Y3l@m@obaRtrG2iraenp52nYKuga6hvaGSvkAhkVinYAgA)

[Try it online!](http://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=retina&p=C0nwScjhio5L1K1S0NG1jNXm4ooJ1@bS5YrTrdFV4fpvqG2kbaxtoq2np6edp2CroGuob2hkr5AIZFYp2AIA)

### Explanation

```
T`L`l
```

This line is simple, it converts to lowercase by **T**ransliterating `A-Z` (`L`) to `a-z` (`l`, lowercase).

---

This stage is simple, it essentially gets rid of all unneeded characters to save ourselves a lot of trouble later on

```
[^a-z ,-9]+
```

`[^a-z ,-9]` Matches any character that is NOT:

- `a-z`: lowercase alphabet (remember entire string is lowercase because of previous item)
- : space chacacter
- `,-9` this is char code range of `,` to `9` which happens to be `,-./0123456789`, exactly the characters we need

---

Next we convert all non alphanumeric chars to dashes (which is now just  and `,./-`.

```
\W+
-
```

This won't (not) match `_` which is included in `\w` (negation of `\W`) because it was removed in the previous stage

Comment: I think this will fail for inputs like `a = b`.

Comment: I really want to accept this, but as martin said, it doesn't minify adjacent dashes when you input `a = b` :(

Comment: @Flp.Tkc sorry for late response (Finals week right now). I've managed to squeeze out two more bytes _and_ fix it. I believe this correctly handles such cases now

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>90</s> <s>82</s> <s>79</s> 75 bytes

This is an attempt to do the job with a single `replace()`. This code extracts only the characters that we're interested in and ignores everything else. There's some additional logic to process the hyphens.

```js
s=>(s.toLowerCase().replace(/[ a-z,-9]/g,c=>S=c<'0'?s+'-':s=s?S+c:c,s=0),s)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>(s.toLowerCase().replace(/[ a-z,-9]/g,c=>S=c<'0'?s+'-':s=s?S+c:c,s=0),s)

console.log(f(`Loading... Forever`));                         // -> loading-forever
console.log(f(`N(e(s(t))) a string`));                        // -> nest-a-string
console.log(f(`"Hello, World!"`));                            // -> hello-world
console.log(f(`URL-Friendly titles`));                        // -> url-friendly-titles
console.log(f(`C.U.S.R.S`));                                  // -> c-u-s-r-s
console.log(f(`1+2+3+4+...+n = -1/12?`));                     // -> 1234-n-1-12
console.log(f(`How can I use cmp(a,b)`));                     // -> how-can-i-use-cmpa-b
console.log(f(`Export The $PATH Variable, Line-By-Line`));    // -> export-the-path-variable-line-by-line
console.log(f(`Do n and n^3 have the same set of digits?`));  // -> do-n-and-n3-have-the-same-set-of-digits
console.log(f(`Quine Anagrams! (Cops' Thread)`));             // -> quine-anagrams-cops-thread
console.log(f(`The Golfer Adventure - Chapter 1`));           // -> the-golfer-adventure-chapter-1
console.log(f(`Bootloader golf: Brainf***`));                 // -> bootloader-golf-brainf
console.log(f(`0123`));                                       // -> 0123
console.log(f(`a a1`));                                       // -> a-a1
console.log(f(`2-1=1`));                                      // -> 2-11
console.log(f(',a^a,'));                                      // -> aa
```

Comment: For `,a^a,`, this code gives `-aa-` (there are leading/trailing hyphens)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Oh, thanks for pointing this out. I didn't pay attention to that rule. That should be fixed.

Answer (score 9):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>41, 40, 37</s>, 36 bytes

```
VuÍ[ .,\/]/-
Í0-9a-z­]
Í-«/-
Í^-ü-$
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=VnXDjVsgLixcL10vLQrDjcKEMC05YS16wq1dCsONLcKrLy0Kw41eLcO8LSQ&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi) or [Check all test cases at once!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=Vkd1w41bIC4sXC9dLy0Kw43ChDAtOWEtesKtXQrDjS3Cqy8tCsONXi3DvC0k&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEiCkxvYWRpbmcuLi4gRm9yZXZlcgpOKGUocyh0KSkpIGEgc3RyaW5nCiJIZWxsbywgV29ybGQhIgpVUkwtRnJpZW5kbHkgdGl0bGVzCkMuVS5TLlIuUwoxKzIrMys0Ky4uLituID0gLTEvMTI_CkhvdyBjYW4gSSB1c2UgY21wKGEsYik)

As usual, here this contains a bunch of unprintable and non-ASCII characters, so here is a hexdump:

```
0000000: 5675 cd5b 202e 2c5c 2f5d 2f2d 0acd 8430  Vu.[ .,\/]/-...0
0000010: 2d39 612d 7aad 5d0a cd2d ab2f 2d0a cd5e  -9a-z.]..-./-..^
0000020: 2dfc 2d24                                -.-$
```

It's challenges like these where V's "Compressed regex" system come in handy.

## Explanation

First things first, we will convert everything to lowercase. Fortunately there is a really convenient way to do this in two bytes. I wrote a tip about that [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90098/31716). So we do

```
V           " Visually select this whole line
 u          " Convert this whole line to lowercase
```

After that we do a bunch of compressed substitute commands. A nice overview of how V's compressed regex works can be foud [here](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/wiki/Regexes), but the basic idea is we can set the high-bit to avoid having to escape certain characters. Another convenience is that ranges (like `:%`) and flags (like `/g`) are automagically filled in. But in the end, it all translates to vim substitute commands. In fact, we could even directly translate the rest of the program to vim. That would give us this:

```
:%s/[ .,/]/-/g
:%s/[^0-9a-z\-]//g
:%s/-\+/-
:%s/^-\|-$//g
```

If you speak vim-regex, it should be more clear what the rest of the program does now. So here is the rest of the program:

```
Í               " Substitute:
 [ .,\/]        "   a space, period, comma or forward slash. (Due to a strange bug, this needs to be escaped)
        /-      "   with a dash
Í               " Remove:
 [^0-9a-z­]     "   Any character that is not a dash or alpha-numeric
Í               " Substitute:
 -«             "   One or more dashes
   /-           "   with one dash
Í               " Remove:
 ^-             "   A dash at the beginning of a line
   ü            "   OR
    -$          "   a dash at the end of a line
```

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6) 91 <s>96</s>

*1 bytes saved* thx @ETHproductions

```
s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/([ .,/-])|\W|_/g,(c,d)=>d?'-':'').replace(/^-*|-*$|-(?=-)/g,'')
```

**Test**

```js
F=
s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/([ .,/-])|\W|_/g,(c,d)=>d?'-':'').replace(/^-*|-*$|-(?=-)/g,'')

;[['Loading... Forever.....', 'loading-forever'],
['N(e(s(t))) a string', 'nest-a-string'],
['"Hello, World!"', 'hello-world'],
['URL-Friendly titles', 'url-friendly-titles'],
['C.U.S.R.S','c-u-s-r-s'],
['1+2+3+4+...+n = -1/12?', '1234-n-1-12'],
['How can I use cmp(a,b)', 'how-can-i-use-cmpa-b'],
['Export The $PATH Variable, Line-By-Line', 'export-the-path-variable-line-by-line'],
['Do n and n^3 have the same set of digits?', 'do-n-and-n3-have-the-same-set-of-digits'],
['Quine Anagrams! (Cops\' Thread)', 'quine-anagrams-cops-thread'],
['The Golfer Adventure - Chapter 1', 'the-golfer-adventure-chapter-1'],
['Bootloader golf: Brainf***', 'bootloader-golf-brainf'],
['0123', '0123'],
['a a1', 'a-a1'],
['2-1=1', '2-11']]
.forEach(t=>{
  var i=t[0],k=t[1],r=F(i)
  console.log(r==k?'OK':'KO',i+' -> '+r,r==k?'':k)
})
```

Comment: This has exactly the same bytecount as my answer if it is converted to a named function

Comment: Don't think you need the last `*` in the last regex, though I may be wrong

Comment: I may be mistaken, but are you sure the lookahead is necessary?

Comment: @KritixiLithos the lookahead is necessary to keep at least 1 - inside the string, while removing all at start and end

Comment: @ETHproductions right, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>103</s> <s>100</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

*5 bytes saved thanks to Flp.Tkc*

```
import re
lambda s,y=re.sub,d='-':y('-+',d,y('[^0-9a-z-]','',y('[ .,/]',d,s.lower()))).strip(d)
```

Comment: @Flp.Tkc Indeed..

Comment: Oops, I accidentally downvoted this. I can't reverse my vote until you edit this post

Comment: @KritixiLithos Done

Answer (score 4):

## Retina, 34 bytes

```
T`L`l
[^a-z\d .,/-]+

\W+
-
^-|-$
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBMYGwKW15hLXpcZCAuLC8tXSsKClxXKwotCl4tfC0kCg&input=MSsyKzMrNCsuLi4rbiA9IC0xLzEyPw)

Note the trailing newline. Essentially the OP's implementation.

Comment: The TIO link points to a slightly different code

Comment: Yeah I just fixed it.

Comment: You can use `T\`L\`l` to go to lowercase with less bytes

Comment: Fails on `a..` snd similar

Comment: fixed @Downgoat

Comment: This doesn't work for the `1+2+3+4+n = - 1/12` test case, but [this should cover you](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBMYGwKW15hLXpcZCAuLC8tXSsKCltcV10rCi0KXi18LSQK&input=MSsyKzMrNCsuLi4rbiA9IC0xLzEyPw) (and save a byte)!

Comment: `[\W]` is just `\W`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 38 bytes

```
'-'jyvk45y' .,/'m(t8Y245hm)'-*'45YX6L)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6@uq55VWZZtYlqprqCno6@eq1FiEWlkYpqRq6muq6VuYhoZYeaj@f9/cElqeWaqerFCcWphaWpecqqVgraCloKugj6MBgA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#FVDJTsMwEL37K6YVUrbaxWmKEFJVdaH0ECHoAvSCMMo0MTh25bgR@friXmb0tnnSfF0CGvx07W827gJgg2FQh@7@kGbjqo4CGgfZ@PBxl0eX5e6SG1FIXTLGYGUstmjJc4hhE7ooikBA46yXSX@NSpkBvBuril6f7Dc5XVmJulAdOOkUNmTB9mzLNmxLeJImoyRL/NVEwwQoH/J0Sh7/TsY62FUINy@z3RrehJXiW@EAcqmRzjt63WRpQIPQBejPEVSiRXA@0ojaD3RgjlDIUrpmSl7P3g8zLUor6qYH4cKcmsA3WBRFRK5NT0Yd0cKsaFG7s0WgsKjEyXmOk7kxTvkPeFB63wPMrZD6GMcxueXpiAgQnKSUT/g/).

#### Explanation

```
'-'jyv       % Take input line. Append and prepend a dash. Gives a char column vector
k            % Convert to lowercase
45y' .,/'m(  % Replace any of ' .,/' by a dash, using assignment indexing
t8Y245hm)    % Keep only alphanumeric chars or dashes, using reference indexing
'-*'45YX     % Replace each run of dashes by a single dash, using a regular expression
6L)          % Remove first and last chars, which are always dashes. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>74</s> 69 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^-/,. a-z\d]/g,``).match(/\w+/g).join`-`
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=/[a-z\d]/i.test(this.value)?f(this.value):``><pre id=o>
```

Edit: Saved 5 bytes by realising that I had already deleted all characters except `-/,. 0-9a-z` so I can use `\w` to match the remaining words.

Comment: I think you have to include the HTML code into the bytecount since it is being used to solve the challenge

Comment: @KritixiLithos No, it's only there for demonstration purposes. The question says that my code can assume at least one alphanumeric character, and the HTML code simply tests this before calling the function.

Comment: `[a-z\d]` could be `[^\W_]` ?

Comment: @edc65 Nice, but I then realised that it could be even simpler!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>61</s> <s>60</s> <s>61</s> <s>64</s> 53 bytes

(52 bytes of code plus one byte for the `-p`)

```ruby
$_=$_.tr("A-Z ,-/","a-z ").gsub(/[^\w ]/){}.split*?-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#U1bULy0u0k/KzNNPzStTKCpNqlTQLfivEm@rEq9XUqSh5KgbpaCjq6@ko5SoW6WgpKmXXlyapKEfHRdTrhCrr1ldq1dckJNZomWv@/8/AA)

> **`tr(`**…**`)`** – convert upper case characters, space, comma, period, and slash. Temporarily substitute the `-` with whitespace so I can use `strip` later on.
>   Note the `-` character in the `"A-Z ,-/"` expression is actually a range operator, which also makes the `.` character subject to transformation. This maneuver won’t actually shave off bytes but it’s fancy so it gets to stay.
>
> **`gsub(/[^\w ]/){}`** – remove all characters not in the allowed set.
>
> **`split`** – technically, we don’t exactly need that array but `split` eliminates leading and trailing whitespace (which is actually `-` characters in disguise). As a bonus, this squeezes together runs of multiple spaces.
>
> **`*?-`** – Shorthand for `.join("-")`; this reverses both the preceding `split` operation *and* the whitespace transformation at the same time. One more byte is saved by using the [abbreviated notation for character literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html), which makes the program require Ruby 1.9 or newer.

**Update 1:** <s>Using `gets` instead of Ruby’s stream editing mode saves one byte.</s>
Reverted as per [ValueInk’s suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102812/url-friendly-titles#comment250085_102888).

**Update 2:** **(+3 bytes overall)**

- Fixed edge case `..--hi, $/` (→ `hi`) **(+10 bytes)** – once again courtesy of user ValueInk
- Took malus for `-p` **(+1 byte)**
- Got rid of `squeeze` and used `gsub` instead **(+2 bytes)**, which allowed me to:
- Use `strip` to handle the leading and trailing dashes **(-10 bytes)**.

**Update 3:** Hattrick by ValueInk. We save 11 bytes by leveraging `String#split`’s habit of auto-squeezing runs of the same separator, which enables us to ditch the whole final `strip`/`gsub` chain and replace it by a `split`/`join` combo. **(-11 bytes)**

Comment: This only returns the string in a REPL environment and fails if run as a proper Ruby program, and that's no good. Full programs or functions/lambdas only. In fact, your old version would've worked with the `-p` flag, but this definitely won't.

Comment: @ValueInk You are of course correct. I’ve changed my solution accordingly. Thanks for your comment; it is exactly the kind of guidance I appreciate a lot as this is my first attempt at golfing.

Comment: Thank you for making the fix; I have removed my downvote. A thing to note is that using the `-p` flag implicitly adds 1 byte to your code (because it changes your code execution from `ruby -e 'your code'` to `ruby -pe 'your code'`). I have also found one edge case where it gives `-hi-` for input like `..--hi, $/` when you should be removing all leading/trailing dashes and thus be returning `hi`.

Comment: @ValueInk Thanks once again. I have edited my answer to fix both issues.

Comment: -2 bytes by changing `gsub(/[^\w ]/){}` to `tr('^a-z ','')`, and then end with `.split*?-` instead of `.strip.gsub...` since it automatically handles duplicates *and* the ends of the string, all in one go!

Comment: @ValueInk Regarding that `tr`: unfortunately, we’re supposed to preserve the digits (the `\w` regexp covers that); another possible variation of `tr('^a-z0-9','')` would actually add one byte to the tally.  
The `split`/`join` combo is brilliant though. Thanks – this saved a whopping 11 bytes!

Comment: Since nobody said it, welcome to code-golf!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>90</s> <s>98</s> <s>94</s> <s>93</s> <s>91</s> <s>90</s> 91 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @edc65!*

*1 byte saved thanks to @IsmaelMiguel for spotting a leading semi-colon!*

*1 byte gained after failing for* `,a-^-a,`

```
f=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^ a-z,-9]/g,"").replace(/[ ,-/]+/g,"-").replace(/^-|-$/g,"")
```

The thing I like most about this particular submission are the ranges. In the first `replace`, we remove anything that is not alphanumeric and not a `,`,`-`,`.`,`/` and not a space. We use `a-z` for detecting the letters, and we use `,-9` to detect those special characters *and* numbers since the character codes of these ASCII literals all line up!

```
, = 44
- = 45
. = 46
/ = 47
0 = 48
...
9 = 57
```

```js
f=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^ a-z,-9]/g,"").replace(/[ ,-/]+/g,"-").replace(/^-|-$/g,"")

console.log(f("---"));//TEST
console.log(f("!@#$%ˆ&*()_+"));//TEST

console.log(f("Stewie's sequence: + * - / + * - /-"));

console.log(f("Loading... Forever"));
console.log(f("N(e(s(t))) a string"));
console.log(f("\"Hello, World!\""));
console.log(f("URL-Friendly titles"));

console.log(f("C.U.S.R.S"));
console.log(f("1+2+3+4+...+n = -1/12?"));
console.log(f("How can I use cmp(a,b)"));

console.log(f("Export The $PATH Variable, Line-By-Line"));
console.log(f("Do n and n^3 have the same set of digits?"));
console.log(f("Quine Anagrams! (Cops' Thread)"));
console.log(f("The Golfer Adventure - Chapter 1"));
console.log(f("Bootloader golf: Brainf***--"));

console.log(f("0123"));
console.log(f("a a1"));
console.log(f("2-1=1"));
```

```html
<input oninput=a.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=a>
```

Comment: Doesn't remove leading dashes: "-1" becomes "-1", when it should become "1".

Comment: @L3viathan Should work now

Comment: No need to count `f=` so your byte count is 96 right now. And no need of the \ inside a range in the regexp, so it could be 95. But ... still not working: try `...title`

Comment: @edc65 I have edited it so it should work now. Also, thanks for the tip for removing the `\\` :)

Comment: Hei! I'm not *that* old! (65 not 64)

Comment: I believe you don't need the `f=` and the `;` at the end. Just specify that this is an anonymous function. With this, your answer should be 90 bytes long.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks for spotting the lone `;`! But the reason I don't use anonymous functions is because I personally detest them

Comment: Then why did you used one?

Comment: Here, a shorter one: `f=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/[ ,-/]+/g,"-").replace(/^-|-$|[^ a-z,-9]/g,"")`. I've moved the 1st RegExp into the last.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Doesn't work for `a-^-a`, it gives `a--a`. That is why I ordered my regexps in that order

Comment: Makes sense. I really didnt test with that.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 87 bytes

The idea of the regular expressions come from existing answers.

```php
<?=trim(preg_replace(['@[^ a-z,-9]@','@[ ,-/]+@'],['','-'],strtolower($_GET[T])),'-');
```

It requires you to have a server running PHP, and access over HTTP.

The title must be on the key `T`, and the result will be printed on the screen.

Example: `http://localhost/title.php?T=<my shiny title>`

Answer (score 2):

## bash/Unix tools, 56 bytes

```
tr A-Z\ .,/ a-z-|tr -cds a-z0-9- -|sed s/^-//|sed s/-$//
```

Replace upper-case with lower-case letters, and the required special characters with dashes.

Delete (-d option to tr) characters other than letters, digits, and dashes, and then squeeze (-s option to tr) multiple dashes in a row into a single dash.

Delete dashes at the beginning, and then at the end.

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell, 85 Bytes

```
($args[0].ToLower()-replace'[ .,/]','-'-replace'[^a-z,-9]'-replace'-+','-').Trim('-')
```

make it lowercase, then 3 regex replaces in a row, and trim any trailing `-`'s

Comment: mightn't `$input` save you 2 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 91 bytes

```
a=a:lower():gsub( '[ .,/]', '-' ):gsub( '[^%w-]', '' ):gsub( '%-+', '-' ):match'%-?(.*)%-?'
```

Where `a` is the URL string.

Explanation:

- Most of it's pretty straight forward. `a:lower()` returns the lower-case function
- `:gsub` finds the match of the pattern and replaces it with the string.
- `'[ .,/]'`: Brackets mean "or", so this matches space, period, comma, and slash. No need to be greedy because `:gsub` does all occurrences.
- `'[^%w-]'`: `^` means "not" when inside brackets, `%w` means anything alphanumeric. So `'[^%w-]` matches anything that's *not* alphanumeric or a dash.
- `'%-+'`: Match as many dashes as you can and replace them with just one dash.
- `match'%-?(.*)%-?'`: In Lua, if a string is the function's only argument, no parenthesis are needed. Only needs to check for one dash at the start and end because dashes have been minimized already. No need for anchor characters because `.*` is match everything, greedy.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 194 bytes

```
i,j;f(char*s,char*d){if(*s>47&*s<58|*s>96&*s<123)d[i++]=*s;if(*s>64&*s<91)d[i++]=*s+32;if(i-j&&*s>43&*s<48|*s==32&&*(s+1)&&*(s+1)>47|(*(s+1)<44&&*(s+1)^32)){d[i++]=45;j=i;}*++s?f(s,d):(d[i]=0);}
```

Call with:

```
int main()
{
    char *in="Loading... Forever";
    char out[128];
    f(in,out);
    puts(out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### SAS, 108

One of the less competitive answers here due to the verbose syntax of SAS - the 9 character penalty per regex really hurts - but it was a good regex learning exercise:

```
t=prxchange('s/^-|-$//',-1,prxchange('s/-+/-/',-1,compress(translate(lowcase(t),'----',' .,/'),'-','adk')));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 35 bytes

```
:r::rQ0"[-.,/]"d"[^\w ]"k6"[ -]+"\-
```

#### Explanation

```
    rQ0                              Convert letters to lower case
   :   "[-.,/]"d                     Replace all -.,/ with spaces
  :             "[^\w ]"k            Remove all remaining symbols
 r                       6           Remove leading and trailing spaces
:                         "[ -]+"\-  Turn runs of spaces and dashes to one dash
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 75

```
{lc .subst(/<[\ .,/]>/,"-"):g.subst(/<[\W]-[\-]>/,""):g.subst(/\-+/,"-"):g}
```

Answer (score 0):

### GNU Sed, 65 bytes

```
s/.*/\L\0/
s@[ .,/]@-@g
s/[^-a-z0-9]//g
s/-\+/-/g
s/^-\|-$//g
```

A series of regex substitutions.  Uses non-portable `\L` from GNU sed to lowercase the input.  Run from a file using `sed -f`.