# Find the smallest file

Tags: code-golf, file-system

### Goal:

Create a program to find the smallest file in the current folder.

- File size may be measured in bytes or characters.
- If multiple files have the same size, you can either choose one or display all of them.
- You can assume there will be at least one file in the folder, and no files will have a size of 0.
- Assume that all files in the folder can be loaded by the language you're using.
- #### Assume that there are no folders in the current directory.

#### Input:

The program should not take any input from the user, unless:

- If your language doesn't have a "current folder", it may ask the user for a folder name/path.
- If your language cannot directly access files on your computer, it may allow the user to upload files. (JavaScript, for example)

#### Output:

The name of the smallest file should be displayed.

- Leading/trailing symbols are allowed, as long as it's clear which file has been chosen.
- (Printing a list of all the files is against the rules).

#### Notes:

- [Standard Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are not allowed.
- You cannot modify/create/delete files in the folder to change the result.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Can we assume files _can_ have a size of 0?

Comment: Also, what does "assume that all files in the folder can be accessed" mean? does that mean hidden files don't need to be shown?

Comment: What if there are multiple files of the same size? does any work?

Comment: Can we assume files *can* have a size of 0?: sure
"assume that all files in the folder can be accessed": If your language is only able to access, for example, `.png` files (for some reason), you can still post an answer.
What if there are multiple files of the same size?: You can display one or all of them.

Comment: So if your language can only support it, not if it just takes more bytes?

Comment: Can I assume there are no folders on the current folder? It makes all the difference if you have a language function that returns both files and folders instead of only files!

Comment: Whenever possible you should avoid making edits that invalidate existing answers. Also, I don't know what *work if there are other folders* means. Should it simply not break or should it search recursively for the smallest file?

Comment: The only other choice was to leave an ambiguity in the question.

Comment: Not necessarily. *You may assume that there are no directories inside the current directory* is unambiguous and doesn't invalidate any answers.

Comment: Now that I think about it, that would be closer to the original intent of the challenge.

Comment: You never answered my question about more bytes vs actually impossible. For example, bash's `ls` can access hidden files, but it takes the `-a` flag. Are we required to use that? You say "If your language _is only able to_ access .png", but that's a bit unclear.

Comment: (sorry I haven't replied sooner, my internet connection was down for a few days) The problem I have with allowing you to skip hidden files is that it seems to open a lot of loopholes. Allowing you to skip files that are "slightly harder to access" would mean people could do something like only checking the first 9 files because it saves a few bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Vim 12 bytes

```
!!ls -Sa
Gd{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@6@omFOsoBucyOWeUv3/PwA)

### Explanation:

`!!` is the *filter* command. It pipes the contents of the current line to an arbitrary system command, and sends the output back into the buffer. It's useful for using external tools for things that bash is better at than vim, for example `!!rev` to reverse the current line, or `!Gxxd` to hexdump the buffer. In our case, the buffer is empty so it's equivalent to `:r!ls`, which just feeds the output of the command into the current line.

Now the cursor is on line 1, and we want to delete every line but the last one. The naïve approach is

```
G       " Go to the last line
 k      " Go up one line
  d     " Delete:
   gg   "   Everything up to the first line
```

But we can do better. Like I explained in [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103946/31716), the `{` can *usually* (but not always) be equivalent to `gg`. Here, it's even better. Because the motion is *character-based*, not *line-based* like `gg` is, we don't have to go up a line first, leaving us with

```
Gd{
```

Answer (score 16):

## Bash + coreutils, 13 bytes

```
ls -Sar|sed q
```

Explanation:

```
ls -Sar|sed q
ls            # list files
   -S         # sorted, biggest first
     a        # show hidden files
      r       # reversed (smallest first)
       |sed q # q is quit at first line that matches given regex, 
              # given regex is empty so guaranteed match.
```

Comment: Posted this as my own answer, but I think it's too similar to yours. `ls -1Sa|tail -1` is 3 bytes shorter and has cleaner output.

Comment: I don't think you need the '-1', pipe automatically puts one file per line.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk I think GB is right.  if `ls` detects output is to the terminal it will format the output into multiple columns.  But if output is a pipe it will just do 1 per line.  Compare `ls` vs `ls|cat`

Comment: Two bytes shorter: `ls -Sar|sed q`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma ah, true. and thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this fall into the "using other programs" loophole?

Comment: @MichealJohnson which one? That's not a loophole... It's perfectly allowed to import modules in a submission, and coreutils is basically a module for bash that doesn't need to be imported

Answer (score 9):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>30</s> <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```powershell
(ls|sort le*)[0].Name
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@RU1xTnF9UopCTqqUZbRCr55eYm/r/PwA)

`ls` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. That's piped to `sort-object` with the `length` attribute, so the files are sorted by size. We index into that with the `(...)[0]` to get the first (i.e., smallest), and then take the `.Name` thereof. Output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion.

*Saved 6 bytes since we're guaranteed that only files exist in the directory. Saved an additional 3 thanks to ConnorLSW.*

Comment: Can you not get rid of the `-file` since only files are in the current directory?

Comment: @Mutantoe Yes -- that was edited into the challenge after I posted this answer. Thanks!

Comment: you can use `sort le*` to shave some bytes since powershell will accept it.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Yes, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

### Python <s>2</s> 3, <s>94</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> 54 bytes

-18 bytes thanks to @orlp
-2 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Allan
-20 bytes thanks to a change in challenge specs

```
from os import*
print(min(listdir(),key=path.getsize))
```

Comment: `print min(filter(path.isfile,listdir(".")),key=path.getsize)` is cleaner and substantially shorter.

Comment: Save two bytes moving to Python 3 since `"."` is the default. `print(min(filter(path.isfile,listdir()),key=path.getsize))`

Comment: Also I count 76 not 77.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I measured the byte count count with `wc` which gave me 1 byte more

Comment: The extraneous byte would be due to a trailing newline, which is not required for Python. Additionally, since the challenge was updated to state that there are no subdirectories present, the whole `filter` bit is unnecesary. This also doesn't work in Python 3, since `print` is a function. The following would work, and be substantially shorter: `print(min(listdir(),key=path.getsize))`

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, <s>61</s> <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

Thanks G B and Value Ink

```
p Dir[?*,".*"].min_by{|x|File.size x}
```

Comment: You can use ?. instead of Dir.pwd, and min_by{} to get the smallest file. `Dir.foreach(?.).min_by{|x|File.size x}` gets the same result in 38 bytes.

Comment: @GB Thanks! [​](https://wat.wat)

Comment: It's a shame that "all" files the language can access must be looked at, because `Dir[?*]` is much shorter but doesn't include hidden Unix files like `.bash_profile`...

Comment: Maybe Dir[?*,".?*"] could work. I haven't tried. And it's shorter.

Comment: @GB It'd actually be `Dir[?*,".*"]`. Glob string `.?*` won't match file `.a` if it exists.

Answer (score 7):

## Java 7, <s>149</s> 142 bytes

```
String f(){String n="";long s=-1>>>1,p;for(java.io.File f:new java.io.File(".").listFiles())if((p=f.length())<s){n=f.getName();s=p;}return n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TY8xbsMwDEX3nILwRAGpgKxR5bFbu2QsMiip5KiQJUGkUwSGz@7SSIdO/HwEicdrckTw7mKGeT1xi3mAgGr@i9l2nUlFEtmXQ9/3h301oTT8dnenY9FvMXkIx@x/4D/CTndKp0i8dYRKxYBYbdDJ54FvAl5JzVnA4PnDjR6VIVvN0jxPLUM2y1qnS4pXIHYs5V7iF4wiik@3z7Nrg4J5B099BxY2ja2RY4JPD2I/6jKxrrLBKaPT8pwMl92y/gI)

-7 bytes thanks to CAD97

Comment: I think you want File::length not File::getTotalSpace

Comment: Untested Java 8: `()->java.utils.stream(new java.io.File(".").listFiles()).max((a,b)->a.length()-b.length).get().getName()` for 104 bytes

Comment: @CAD97 You're right! What was I thinking...

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
FileNames[]~MinimalBy~FileByteCount
```

`FileNames[]` produces a list of names of all the files (and directories) in the current directory; `~MinimalBy~FileByteCount` selects the name of the file whose byte count is smallest. `FileByteCount` throws a bunch of errors when it's applied to directories, but the errors don't derail the program.

Answer (score 6):

### SH (Linux/Unix) <s>15</s> <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 14 bytes

```
ls -aS|tail -1
```

`-S` sorts by size (descending),

<s>`-r`reverses</s> and `tail -1` outputs the last file in the list.

@ Dennis Thanks for saving 1 byte
@Dani_l Thanks for saving 1 byte.

Comment: That finds the *largest* file, no?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm tired. You could use `tail` though instead of reversing, and `-1` is a shorthand for `-n1`.

Comment: @Dennis Updated

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Now it should :)

Comment: @AbelTom cool, thanks for fixing.

Comment: What's specific to BASH in your solution?

Comment: @yeti I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean. The solution would also work on UNIX shell ( `/bin/sh` ), `/bin/bash` is the program that use on my machine.

Comment: @AbelTom — BASH has more features than SH, so if you do not use them, label your solution with SH... that was the direction I wanted to point at...

Comment: @yeti Updated Sir.

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB / Octave, <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
d=dir;[~,n]=min([d.bytes]./~[d.isdir]);d(n).name
```

**Explanation**

This gets a directory listing of all files and folders in the current directory using `dir`. The output of `dir` is a `struct` containing the filename, whether it's a directory or not, the size (in bytes), etc.

We can then take an array of the sizes of each in bytes `[d.bytes]` and perform element-wise division with a boolean indicating whether it's a directory or not `~[d.isdir]` which will yield `Inf` where it's a directory (division by zero) and the size in bytes otherwise (division by 1).

We find the index of the minimum of this array using the second output of `min` and use that to index into the initial struct and display the name with `d(n).name`

Comment: You should add `disp(...)` around the output to properly print it. Otherwise if for example there was a file called `ans` that is not the smallest in the folder the output wouldn't be clear as to which file is the smallest to anyone unfamiliar with MATLAB.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Hmmm I interpreted "Leading/trailing symbols are allowed, as long as it's clear which file has been chosen" to mean that the `ans = ` is ok

Comment: I've just realised MATLAB adds the implicit `.` (current folder) and `..` (folder above), so cant remove the directory check it seems. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, <s>43</s> <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```
@dir/b/os|(set/pf=&call echo %%f%%)
```

Output includes a leading space for some reason, but fortunately that's allowed. Edit: Now assuming there are no directories to save 4 bytes.

Comment: Oh, using /p like that, dang clever!

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Ah, I hadn't noticed that was allowed, thanks!

Comment: You're guaranteed that no sub-directories exist (the challenge was updated) so you can eliminate the `/a-d`.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
>{.,(/:2&{"1)1!:0'*'
```

Saved a byte thanks to @[Conor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien).

### Explanation

```
>{.,(/:2&{"1)1!:0'*'
                 '*' Glob all files in current directory
             1!:0    Table of file metadata in that directory
       2&{"1         Get the file size of each
     /:              Sort the files by that
   ,                 Flatten
 {.                  Get the first value
>                    Unbox
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>33 32 31</s>  16 bytes

```perl6
'.'.IO.dir.grep(*.f).min(*.s).put
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@6@up67n6a@Xklmkl16UWqChpZemqZebmQdkFGvqFZSW/P8PAA)

```perl6
put '.'.IO.dir.min:{try .s//Inf}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@19QWqKgrqeu5@mvl5JZpJebmWdVXVJUqaBXrK/vmZdW@/8/AA)

```perl6
put $*CWD.dir.min:{try .s//Inf}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@19QWqKgouUc7qKXklmkl5uZZ1VdUlSpoFesr@@Zl1b7/z8A)

```perl6
put dir.min: *.s
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@19QWqKQklmkl5uZZ6WgpVf8/z8A)

### Expanded:

```perl6
put        # print with trailing newline
dir        # the list of files in the current directory
.min:      # find the minimum by
  *.s      # calling the `s` method (size) in a Whatever lambda
```

Comment: The function form of `dir` defaults to `$*CWD`, and the task description says you can assume there won't be any folders, so I think you can shorten that to `dir.min(*.s).put`.

Comment: When I wrote this, it said the program must ignore folders.

Answer (score 4):

**Scala, 52 bytes**

Old version, 79 bytes

```
new java.io.File(".").listFiles.map(a=>a.getName->a.length)sortBy(_._2)apply(0)
```

Adjusted according to jaxad0127's advice.  It is only 52 bytes now.

```
new java.io.File(".").listFiles.sortBy(_.length)head
```

Comment: Using head instead of apply(0) is shorter. Also, the toString method of File is fine, no need to call get name.

Answer (score 3):

### BATCH File, <s>77</s> <s>72</s> <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```
@FOR /F tokens^=* %%G IN ('dir/o-s/b')DO @SET[=%%G
@ECHO %[%
```

There's no direct equivalent of `head` or `tail` in BATCH, at least to my knowledge, so here's a kludgy work-around. (with much assistance from @Neil - thanks!)

The `dir` command, with `/o-s` to sort in descending file size, and `/b` to output only the file names. We loop through those with `FOR /F`, setting the variable `[` to the file name each time. Finally, we output just the last one with `ECHO %[%`.

*Saved 9 more bytes thanks to Neil and thanks to guarantees that no directories are present.*
*Saved 3 bytes thanks to HackingAddict1337.*

Comment: Your `FOR` variable needs two `%`s to work in a script. Otherwise, a few golfing tricks: 1. Don't use `@ECHO OFF` on short scripts, add a `@` to each line and after `DO`. 2. Delete the space before `DO`. 3. The spaces and `:`s aren't needed in the `dir` command.

Comment: @Neil Ack, thanks. Sorry, pretty rusty since I've been doing PowerShell... Thanks!

Comment: `tokens^=*` instead of `"tokens=*"` using `[` as the variable name will save you one byte, because `set[=%%G` is enough. the space in front of `do` is optional...

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, <del>84</del> 62 bytes

```
$t=array_map(filesize,$g=glob('*'));asort($t);echo$g[key($t)];
```

Since the question was updated with the assumption that there will be no folders in the current directory, I was able to remove the file check stuff and golf this down.

---

**Here is my old answer:**

```
$t=array_map(filesize,$g=array_filter(glob('*'),is_file));asort($t);echo$g[key($t)];
```

This is the best I could do. Maybe there is a better way I'm missing.

```
$t=array_map(              # visit each array element and...
    filesize,              # map each filename to its filesize...
    $g=array_filter(       # using an array of...
        glob('*'),         # all files and directories...
        is_file            # filtered by files...
    )                      # 
);                         # 
asort($t);                 # sort the array of filesizes, then...
echo$g[key($t)];           # print element from the array of files using the first key of the sorted array as an index
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 110 bytes

```
DIM F$[0]FILES"TXT:",F$FOR I=0TO LEN(F$)-1F$[I][0]="TXT:
S=LEN(LOAD(F$[I],0))IF!Z||S<Z THEN Z=S:B=I
NEXT?F$[B]
```

Only looks at `TXT:` files, since `DAT:` files cannot be loaded unless you already know their size, making it impossible to load a random one.

Comment: How do you load a `DAT: ` file? Could you brute-force every name/file size in the folder?

Comment: Trying to load a 3-dimensional `DAT:` file into a 2-dimensional array (for example) will cause an error, so you can't brute force it. You just have to know the number of dimensions beforehand, which you normally would.

Comment: Could you load a 2-d `DAT: ` file into a 3-d array? Then you could create a maximum size array. And you can't catch errors in any way?

Comment: Nope, that will cause a Type mismatch error. And there's no way to catch errors either.

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 88 bytes

```
set s Inf
lmap f [glob -ty f *] {if [set m [file si $f]]<$s {set n $f
set s $m}}
puts $n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7LCsIwEEX3@YpZdCXoF7gSpHThxm3Joo9JCEweOClVSr89JioiBXeXyzlzJw6UGCMoaH1AB2w7okO8R5ilCFNkqBSwGMgz5ijEL2xxNJPd0hcc//C90RpvW/7U1PX5@lVe7zA0TgmyXSiyJt/DPj5y3klYTK4KZKFVhhDYZE3KY8WwlN6V4feVyq7rZ8il9AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Node.js (using [`walk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk)), 114 bytes

Ignore newline:

```
require('walk').walk(__dirname).on('file',(r,s,n)=>
(m=s.size>m.size?m:s,n()),m=0).on('end',_=>console.log(m.name))
```

This invokes a walker that traverses through the current directory (`__dirname`) and for each file calls a function with its stat `s` and a function next `n()` that must be invoked to continue the traversal. Then at the `end`, it prints a filename with the minimum `size` in bytes found. `s.size>m.size` returns `false` when `m.size` is `undefined`, so after the first callback, `m` is equal to the first file found, and continues from there normally.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 36 bytes

```
x=file.info(y<-dir())$s;y[x==min(x)]
```

**Explained**

`file.info()` returns a `data.frame` of "file information" when given a character or character vector of file/folder names which when used on the list of files/folders in the current directory (`dir()`), looks something like:

```
                                                               size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
Polyspace_Workspace                                               0  TRUE  777 2014-11-28 17:29:25 2014-11-28 17:29:25 2014-11-28 17:29:25  no
Python Scripts                                                    0  TRUE  777 2016-03-21 23:59:41 2016-03-21 23:59:41 2016-03-21 23:59:41  no
R                                                                 0  TRUE  777 2015-12-23 20:11:02 2015-12-23 20:11:02 2015-12-23 20:11:02  no
Rockstar Games                                                    0  TRUE  777 2015-04-14 12:23:05 2015-04-14 12:23:03 2015-04-14 12:23:05  no
TrackmaniaTurbo                                                   0  TRUE  777 2016-03-24 17:15:05 2016-03-24 13:13:48 2016-03-24 17:15:05  no
ts3_clientui-win64-1394624943-2014-06-11 03_18_47.004772.dmp 314197 FALSE  666 2014-06-11 02:18:47 2014-06-11 02:18:47 2014-06-11 02:18:47  no
```

Subsequently we just have the find the name of the file for which the `size` column (abbreviated using `$s`) is the smallest. Consequently, if there are more than one file with the smallest size, all will be returned.

Bonus: if we also wanted to disregard folders in the current directory we could simply search for size when `isdir == FALSE`: `x=file.info(y<-dir());y[x$s==min(x$s[!x$i])]` which turns out to be 44 bytes.

Comment: Bit late, but `file.size` is shorter because you don't have to do `$s` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```
m={f->f.listFiles().sort{it.length()}[0].getName()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/groovy#@1@dpmuXppeTWVzilpmTWqyhqVecX1RSnVmil5Oal16SoaFZG20Qq5eeWuKXmJsK5P3/DwA)

Closure, usage: `m(new File("location"))`

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 277 bytes

Not the shortest, but what would you expect from C#?

### Golfed

```
using System.Linq;using static System.IO.Directory;class P{static void Main(){var x=GetFiles(GetCurrentDirectory());var d=new long[]{}.ToList();foreach(var s in x){var b=new System.IO.FileInfo(s).Length;if(!d.Contains(b))d.Add(b);}System.Console.Write(x[d.IndexOf(d.Min())]);}}
```

### Ungolfed

```
//Linq using for List.Min()
using System.Linq;
//Static using to save bytes on GetCurrentDirectory() and GetFiles()
using static System.IO.Directory;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //String array containing file paths
        var x = GetFiles(GetCurrentDirectory());
        //Creating a Long array and converting it to a list, less bytes than "new System.Collections.Generic.List<long>()"
        var d = new long[] { }.ToList();
        foreach (var s in x) //Loop through all file paths
        {
            //Getting file size in bytes
            var b = new System.IO.FileInfo(s).Length;
            if (!d.Contains(b))
                //If there isn't already a file with this size in our List, add the file path to list
                d.Add(b);

        }
        //Get index of the smallest Long in our List, which is also the index of the file path to the smallest file, then write that path
        System.Console.Write(x[d.IndexOf(d.Min())]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
{ls""|sort key=fileLength|pull}
```

It's an anonymous function that sorts the files in the current directory by file length and selects then the first file with `pull`.

Use it like this: `main{ {ls""|sort key=fileLength|pull} }`

Comment: Apparently `ls""` works just as well as `ls"."`. I think you can save a byte from that

Comment: @KritixiLithos It seems to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-C4`, 9 bytes

- `-C`: enables noclobber (Zsh will not redirect to files which already exist)
- `-4`: enables globdots (`*` matches files beginning with `.`.

> Leading/trailing symbols are allowed, as long as it's clear which file has been chosen.

The following prints the file name, preceded by `$0:1: file exists:`  and followed by a newline, to stderr:

```sh
>*(oL[1])
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@bnZJZpFCSWlzClZwCoVOTM/IV1HPy89IV0jJzUtUV7BQSoYIQPhjYKSRhU5n8HyyooVWjp6Wpke8TbRir@f8/AA)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@bnZJZpFCSWlzClZwCoVOTM/IV1HPy89IV0jJzUtUV7BQSoYIQPhjYKSRhU5n8HyyopeGS7xNtGKv5/z8A)</s>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKg62zClZudklmkUJJaXMKVnAKhU5Mz8hXUc/Lz0hXSMnNS1RXsFPQSoaIQATAAiiZhVZv8305LI98n2jBW8/9/AA)

- `(oL)` sorts by size
- `[1]` selects the first match

---

I used to have just `*(oL[1])` and rely on Zsh printing "command not found", but if the file matches the name of a builtin or executable, this would break.  Additionally, the previous `echo` methods would break if the smallest file was `-e` or `-` or similar (interpreted as a flag to `echo`). This new method works for all file names and is still very short.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC 3, 105 bytes (competing?)

Beats [12Me21's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108408/42096) but still suffers from inability to load DAT files (which feels very cruel to be disqualifying considering the circumstances.)

```
DIM F$[0],T[0]FILES"TXT:",F$FOR I=0TO LEN(F$)-1F$[I][0]="TXT:
PUSH T,LEN(LOAD(F$[I]))NEXT
SORT T,F$?F$[0]
```

The shorter version above is annoying and prompts you on every file to load, but it does work. For two bytes more you can suppress the prompt; change line 2 to this:

```
PUSH T,LEN(LOAD(F$[I],0))NEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch File, 33 bytes

Batch files are moderately competitive this time, oddly enough.

```
@dir/os/b>..\q&set/pa=<..\q&"%a%.
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Find a way to stop the creation of `q` prior to `dir/os/b` being run and you'll save a maximum of 6 bytes by not needing to put the output file in a separate directory.

```
@dir/os/b>q&set/pa=<q&"%a%
```

Will always output `q` as the smallest file (unless tied for another 0 byte file) as it is created as an empty file before `dir/b/os` gathers a list of files.

Answer (score 0):

## [C++17 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 180 bytes

```cpp
#include<filesystem>
using namespace std::filesystem;auto f(){std::error_code e;path r;size_t m=-1,s;for(auto&p:directory_iterator(".")){s=file_size(p,e);if(s<m)m=s,r=p;}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NasMwEITP9VOIFBqJ2IWcCpaUJykYIa9dgfXDrnRIg1@9rpRDe9pld@absSkNq7XHqwt2KzMw5SJlBONvfze1uA3oThn8rSvkwsqC8UDJWGCU53H8F0hTcmQLF4/nAxAjTjZWMMhk8hdDSe4bpsy8Hq49ySUib563NM4OweaI98llQFM3fno/iYrSLWBqRp56ENItnJQXXlOPOskdIRcMlb0fLlS0cYEL9uheniVsLJkp1Vq1cf4MZ9ntx49dNrPSMVSRtpfL9eMX)

Requires a recent standard library that implements `std::filesystem`.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) 6+ for Windows, 20 bytes

```powershell
ls|sort l* -t 1|% n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P6e4pji/qEQhR0tBt0TBsEZVIU/r/38A)

Unrolled:

```powershell
ls|sort length -top 1|% Name
```

See also AdmBorkBork's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108409/80745).

Answer (score 0):

## Red, 56 bytes

```
first sort/compare read %. func[a b][(size? a)< size? b]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 51 bytes

```
.ml$open(b,"rb").read()$$__import__("os").listdir()
```

I feel like Pyth might not be the best tool for the job here...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCsAgCADQf4kOClu/JIuCCZViXvbzc3vXp4/fEWWOLNoX1CNZTVisXw0wZyKeKuZEkGT/MXh7YwOMeEWdZe042wc)