# Draw a big ASCII X

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## Problem

Inspired by a [previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125383/draw-a-big-slash-x) doing something similar

Given positive integer input `n` output a shape that follows this pattern:

input `n=1`:

```
* *
 *
* *
```

input `n=2`:

```
**  **
 ****
  **
 ****
**  **
```

input `n=3`:

```
***   ***
 *** ***
  *****
   ***
  *****
 *** ***
***   ***
```

and so on...

It has these properties:

`n*2+1` lines tall

the "arms" are `n` wide except when they merge

the center line is `n` wide

if `n` is even the lines above and below the center are `n*2` wide

if `n` is odd the lines above and below the center are `n*2-1` wide

## Rules

- Trailing newlines accepted
- Standard loopholes apply
- **Shortest bytes win**
- Output may be print out or a string or array of strings

## Edits

- `n=0` doesn't need to be handled
- Trailing spaces allowed

Comment: Is it okay if the output has `1` instead of `*` and `0` instead of space?

Comment: Can our patterns be 0-indexed?

Comment: @JungHwanMin I will allow it but then you aren't allowed to win, might be swayed if you are most upvoted.

Comment: @LeakyNun 0 Indexed is fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

Thanks to @ErikTheOutgolfer for a byte

```
ＦＮ«ＰX⁺*×*Ｉθ→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9jaGFyY29hbP//77ym77yuwqvvvLBY4oG6KsOXKu@8qc644oaS//8y)

This is my first ever Charcoal answer, and I'm pretty sure it's not golfed as well as it could be, but I figured I'd start somewhere.

```
 ＦＮ«            # For input() (i in range(0,input()))
     Ｐ           # Print
       X          # In an 'X' shape
        ⁺*×*Ｉθ   # '*'+'*'*int(first_input)
               →  # Move the cursor right one
```

Comment: [You can use `Ｉ` for -1.](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9jaGFyY29hbP//77ym77yuwqvvvLBY4oG6KsOXKu@8qc644oaS//8y)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I knew there had to be a way to do that!  Thank you!

Comment: And yes it actually seems as golfed as it can be.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It wasn't before you came along anyway :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can't say that's 12 bytes, as some of those characters would require multiple bytes to represent them.

Comment: @thomasrutter Charcoal has it's [own custom code-page with 256 bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page), where each of those characters is 1 byte. So it's not encoded in ASCII, where some of these characters would indeed be multiple bytes. _nmjcman101_ +1 btw. Was trying my first Charcoal answer as well yesterday, but it didn't really worked out in the few minutes I had before going home from work. So you've beat me to it. I did learn some things from your answer, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 14):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
EQXyG:Y+tP+g42*c
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zUwotLdKlK7JEA73cRIK/n/f3MA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `2` as an example. Stack contents are shown with more recent ones below.

```
EQ    % Implicitly input n. Push 2*n+1
      %   STACK: 5
Xy    % Identity matrix of that size
      %   STACK: [1 0 0 0 0;
                  0 1 0 0 0;
                  0 0 1 0 0;
                  0 0 0 1 0;
                  0 0 0 0 1]
G:    % Push [1 2 ... n]
      %   STACK: [1 0 0 0 0;
                  0 1 0 0 0;
                  0 0 1 0 0;
                  0 0 0 1 0;
                  0 0 0 0 1],
                 [1 2]
Y+    % 2D convolution, extending size
      %   STACK: [1 2 0 0 0 0;
                  0 1 2 0 0 0;
                  0 0 1 2 0 0;
                  0 0 0 1 2 0;
                  0 0 0 0 1 2]
tP+   % Duplicate, flip vertically, add
      %   STACK: [1 2 0 0 2 1;
                  0 1 2 1 2 0;
                  0 0 1 4 0 0;
                  0 1 2 1 2 0;
                  1 2 0 0 1 2]
g     % Convert to logical
      %   STACK: [1 1 0 0 1 1;
                  0 1 1 1 1 0;
                  0 0 1 1 0 0;
                  0 1 1 1 1 0;
                  1 1 0 0 1 1]
42*   % Multiply by 42.
      %   STACK: [42 42  0  0 42 42;
                   0 42 42 42 42  0;
                   0  0 42 42  0  0;
                   0 42 42 42 42  0;
                  42 42  0  0 42 42]
c     % Convert to char. Char 42 is '*'. Char 0 is displayed as space
      %   STACK: ['**  **';
                  ' **** ';
                  '  **  ';
                  ' **** ';
                  '**  **']
```

Comment: You're faster than me...

Comment: @LeakyNun Very rarely :-)

Comment: I wish Jelly had 2D convolution... I had to append 0 in each row and then apply vectorized sum...

Comment: @LeakyNun You know [what they say about convolution...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67650/36398)

Comment: @LuisMendo In my heart you are the winner for using convolution, brings back such nice memories.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
Ḥ‘Ḷ⁶ẋ;€”*ẋ$»Ṛ$Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//4bik4oCY4bi24oG24bqLO@KCrOKAnSrhuoskwrvhuZokWf///zM)

Comment: Very nice. 8 bytes short of me.

Comment: @LeakyNun The straightforward approach helps quite a bit.

Comment: A very nice approach

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yeah, especially tfw you learn `»` vectorizes...

Comment: I really like your username! But I wish you used "vi" or "vim" instead, so you could choose "Erik the vi King" ... (Monty Python fan here ...)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
Å4bS{I·ƒDÂ~„ *èJ,À
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v8wNWFiMWX//8OFNGJTe0nCt8aSRMOCfuKAniAqw6hKLMOA//8z)

**Explanation**

Example for `n=2`

```
Å4                   # push a list of 4s with length as the input
                     # STACK: [4,4]
  b                  # convert each to binary
                     # STACK: [100, 100]
   S{                # split into digit list and sort
                     # STACK: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
     I·ƒ             # input*2+1 times do
        D            # duplicate top of stack
                     # 1st iteration: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
                     # 2nd iteration: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
                     # 3rd iteration: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
         Â~          # or each item in the duplicate with its reverse
                     # 1st iteration: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
                     # 2nd iteration: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
                     # 3rd iteration: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
           „ *èJ     # use the resulting binary list to index into the string " *"
                     # 1st iteration: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], "**  **"
                     # 2nd iteration: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], " **** "
                     # 3rd iteration: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], "  **  "
                ,    # print
                 À   # rotate list left
```

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to @DJMcMayhem's input trick.

```
Àé*ÄJÀälÀñ2ÙÀl2x>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4ZVah1u8gPSSHCCx0ejwzMMNOUYVdv///7cEAA)

Explanation

```
Àé*ÄJÀäl
```

This inserts `[n]*'*'+[n]*' '+[n]*'*'`

```
        Àñ        ' [arg] times
          2Ù      ' Duplicate the current line down twice
            Àl    ' Move right [arg] times
              2x  ' Delete two characters
                > ' Indent this line one space
```

Each iteration of the loop the buffer goes from

```
|**   ***
```

To

```
***   ***
 |** ***
***   ***
```

Where `|` is the cursor with a `*` under it

Comment: Wow. You *waaay* outgolfed me. Good job! A few tips: You could do `Àé*ÄJÀäl` instead of `Àá*Àá Àá*`, and you can do `<M-c>`, i.e. `ã` (mnemonic: *center*) to move to the middle of the line, which is a byte shorter than `Àl`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4ZVah1u8gPSSHCCx0ejwzMOLjSrs/v//bwwA "V – Try It Online")

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I'm trying to talk to you in a bunch of different places.  I'm going to steal the first suggestion I think, but the `<M-c>` breaks for higher numbers

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>88</strike> <strike>87</strike> 86 bytes

-1 thanks to @Laikoni

```hs
(!)=replicate
x n=[zipWith max(reverse m)m|m<-[i!' '++n!'*'++(n*2-i)!' '|i<-[0..n*2]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcmxCsMgEIDhvU9xTmpCQmnX@gbplKFDkCLlIEc9EWODlLy7tdMP37@67Y3e16qENgmjp5fLeCoQzPKl@KC8AruiEu6YNgTWfPBtWEhIkH0fhOxaVOguA@m/HdTueRybWGsrOwqGXbw/IX7ynNMUQBW46voD)

Comment: `zipWith max m(reverse m)` can be shortened to `zipWith max(reverse m)m`. This is the same as `zipWith max=<<reverse$m`, and then `m` can be inlined: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X0NR07YotSAnMzmxJJWrQiHPNroqsyA8syRDITexwtbGpii1LLWoOFUlU1FdQV1bO09RXQtIaeRpGelmaoLEajJtdKMN9PSAIrGx/3MTM/NscxMLfOMVCkpLgkuKfPIUNCoUTDT/AwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 23 bytes

```
Àé*ÄJÀälÀñÙãlxx>ñyHæGVp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4ZVah1u8gPSSHCCx8fDMw4tzKirsDm@s9Di8zD2s4P///xYA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: c0e9 2ac4 4ac0 e46c c0f1 d9e3 6c78 783e  ..*.J..l....lxx>
00000010: f179 48e6 4756 70                        .yH.GVp
```

For whatever reason, this challenge is significantly harder in V than the last one. Since our general approach of *n times, grow an 'x'* won't work here, we'll instead construct the top of the X, copy it and flip it, then attaching the two parts together.

Explanation:

```
Àé*ÄJÀäl                " Insert ('*' * n) + (' ' * n) + ('*' * n) 
                        " The obvious way would be 'Àé*ÀÁ ÀÁ*', but this 
                        " non-obvious way saves us a byte
        Àñ      ñ       " 'n' times:
          Ù             "   Duplicate this line (below us)
           ãl           "   Move to the center of this line
             xx         "   Delete two characters
               >        "   And indent this line with one space.
```

Doing the indent at the *end* of the loop, allows us to [take advantage of implicit endings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124600/31716). This also conveniently creates *n+1* lines, which is exactly the top half of the 'X'. Let's say the input was 4. Then at this point, the buffer looks like this:

```
****    ****
 ****  ****
  ********
   ******
    ****
```

And we're on the last line. So then we:

```
                yH      " Copy the whole buffer and move to the first line
                  æG    " Reverse every line
                    Vp  " And paste what we just copied *over* the current
                        " line, deleting it in the process
```

Comment: I did the `ãxx` thing at first too, but I think it breaks for e.g. n = 8?

Comment: @nmjcman101 Ah, you're right. It's fine if you do `ãl`, or if you indent before centering though, but that doesn't actually save any bytes. I don't understand why it works for smaller numbers though.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <strike>139 130</strike> 115 bytes

-1 byte by creating a string and calling `WriteLine`, thus saving the check for the new line.
-6 bytes thanks to Kevin and his master golfing techniques!
-2 bytes by replacing `n*3-n` with `n*2`.
-15 bytes after Kevin kindly pointed me in the right direction: I can just return the string instead of printing it, thus saving the call to `System.Console.WriteLine()`. And some other tips also...

```
n=>{var s="";for(int i,j=0;j<=n*2;j++,s+='\n')for(i=0;i<n*3;)s+=i>=j&i<j+n|i<=n*3-j-1&i++>=n*2-j?'*':' ';return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc5NS8NAEAbge37FkEPzsUmxDYK42XgQvIggeuhBPSzbTZilnYXdbaHU/PaYaE@CmPc487zDKF8q6/SgdtJ7eHa2c3IP5wjG@CADKjha3MKTREp9cEjd2wdI1/nsoqa8nnzQ@@XDgVSNFIof2EALAgYSzfkoHXgRx7y1Lh0FYGHEFTe1oHzNDWOFZyJ@pzj7BuMKa8orno1jbIRZYG0YfeLkq9KUqwUy1kzl0twleXKbQMKdDgdH4Hk/8Oj3b/eWvN3p5cZh0GmbrrKM/2fWM0w1w1zPMDeT@Qu9aLl91Kf0cqaP@uEL)

Ungolfed:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Func<int, string> g = n =>
        {
            var s = "";
            for (int i, j = 0; j <= n*2; j++, s += '\n')
                for (i = 0; i < n*3;)
                    s += i >= j & i < j+n | i <= n*3-j-1 & i++ >= n*2-j ? '*' : ' ';
            return s;
        };

        System.Console.Write(f(1));
        System.Console.Write(f(2));
        System.Console.Write(f(3));
        System.Console.Write(f(5));
        System.Console.Write(f(8));

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It just iterates along the rows and columns of the space needed to print the big X and prints either a `'*'` or a `' '` depending on the condition.

Comment: +1! Some small things to golf. All the `&&` can be `&` and `||` can be `|` in this case. `for(int j=0;` can be `for(int j=0,i;` and then you can remove the `int ` in front of the `i` in the inner loop. Also, after the first change of `&` and `|`, you can also remove the `i++` inside the for-loop, and change `i==n*3-1?...` to `i++==n*3-1?...`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thank you very much! I changed the inner loop and now I create a string so I can call `WriteLine`, saved just 1 byte. So now I'm not sure what to do with your last advice.

Comment: Well, with my advice for `i++=n*3-1?...` I simply put `++` at the last occurence of `i`. So you can still remove `i++` in the for-loop, and change `i>n*3-n-j-1?` to `i++>n*3-n-j-i`. Hmm, btw, isn't `n*3-n` the same as `n*2`? :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes, I have just realized that... ^__^U

Comment: Btw, why the `System.Console.WriteLine`? Returning the string: `n=>{string s="";for(int i,j=0;j<n*2+1;j++,s+="\n")for(i=0;i<n*3;)s+=i>=j&i<j+n|i<=n*3-j-1&i++>n*2-j-1?'*':' ';return s;}` is shorter [**120 bytes**] (and also gets rid of the brackets by putting everything inside the for-loop. [Here is a TIO-link](https://tinyurl.com/ycyfkn5j) to show it works. Also, feel free to add this (or your own) TIO-link to your answer. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I didn't know that TIO could handle C# code! I added the `WriteLine` in the code because the OP asked to **output** the big X, not just to **return** it, so I felt that the outputting of the X (by calling the `WriteLine` method) should be part of the code. Nonetheless, I'm still not used to the rules of code-golf, and I don't know what licenses I can take when writing code. I have just seen that some of the other answers here print the X in the code, and some others print it in the footer. What is the valid approach in this case?

Comment: Usually returning a string as well as using a function instead of a program is allowed by default, unless stated otherwise. Also, in the question it states "_Output may be print out or a string or array of strings_", so returning a string is allowed. :) Oh, and one last thing you can golf: `j<n*2+1` can be `j<=n*2`. I've also created a [Java 8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126284/52210) port of your answer with the same byte-count, crediting your amazing answer of course.

Comment: [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##jc5PS8NAEAXwez7FkEPzZ5OiLYK42XgQvIggevCgHpZ0E2ZpZ2FnWyg1fvWY1p4EMe/45sdjGi4b583QrDUzPHnXeb2BQwRjOOiADewcruBRI6UcPFL39gHad5yd1TEvew5mM7/fUlMhheIH1tCCgoFUfdhpD6ziWLbOp6MALKy6kLai8oukFaJgoeJ3irMTGE9YUb6U2VhjrewMKyvo81SWdiYE1pQvSnub5MlNAon0Jmw9Act@kNHvv@4csVub@avHYNI2vcwy@Z9ZTDDLCeZqgrk@mr/Qs9GrB7NPzzN91A/f) Credit goes to _@ceilingcat_, since he suggested these golfs on [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126284/52210).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 16 bytes

```
Ḥ‘Ḷ⁸+þṬ+Ṛ$a”*o⁶Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//4bik4oCY4bi24oG4K8O@4bmsK@G5miRh4oCdKm/igbZZ////Mw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>93</s> <s>90</s> <s>89</s> 83 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to Zachary T</sup>
<sup>-6 bytes thanks to xnor</sup>

```python
n=input()
x=n*'*'+n*'  '
exec"print`map(max,x,x[::-1])`[2::5];x=' '+x[:-1];"*(n-~n)
```

[Try it online!][TIO-j3xwsktf]

Starts with a string like `'***      '` for `n=3`, applying `map/max` to pick the `*` over the spaces for each position, then append a space and remove the last character from the string and do this all again.

Comment: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoAgEEDRfaeINupYi4w2iieJQIkgF01DGExd3tw@Pp/efFxoSkGfkJ4sVcMeQYDQCAZEK5qd962jO2EOZyR5Ru6/RJJ7XqwdxlWpsBhr59Wxr72uXNV1IOtBj6qU6Qc)

Comment: Can't you replace `n*2*' '` with `n*'  '`?

Comment: The `map(max` can be done directly without a `zip`. Also, `n*2+1` is `n-~n`.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <strike>153</strike> 126 bytes (17.6%↓)

Thanks to @LuisMendo's comment, function `disp()` can output chars without single quotes, thus I could prevent using `fprintf` with `formats` and omit a few bytes. Besides, his comment reminds me that I need use `char(32)` to present a space rather than `char(0)` (null).

```
n=input('')
r=2*n+1
c=3*n
a=0
for i=0:n-1
a=a+[zeros(r,i),diag(1:r),zeros(r,c-r-i)];
end
a((a+flipud(a))>0)=10
disp([a+32 ''])
```

[Try it online!](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/3Np)

#### MATLAB, 153 bytes

```
n=input('')
r=2*n+1
c=3*n
a=0
for i=0:n-1 
a=a+[zeros(r,i),diag(1:r),zeros(r,c-r-i)];
end
a((a+flipud(a))>0)=42
fprintf([repmat('%c',1,c),'\n'],char(a)')
```

Result example:
    n=10

```
**********          **********
 **********        ********** 
  **********      **********  
   **********    **********   
    **********  **********    
     ********************     
      ******************      
       ****************       
        **************        
         ************         
          **********          
         ************         
        **************        
       ****************       
      ******************      
     ********************     
    **********  **********    
   **********    **********   
  **********      **********  
 **********        ********** 
**********          **********
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 70 bytes

```hs
f n=[[last$' ':['*'|y<-[1..n],(c-n-y)^2==r^2]|c<-[1..3*n]]|r<-[-n..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6OiexuERFXUHdKlpdS72m0kY32lBPLy9WRyNZN0@3UjPOyNa2KM4otiYZImOslRcbW1ME5OjmgdTF/s9NzMxTsFXITSzwVSgoLQkuKfLJU1BRSFMw/Q8A)

Outputs a list of strings.

For each position of row `r`, column `c`, uses a formula to determine whether it falls in one of the two diagonal bands and so is `*`.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES2017), <s>155</s> 157 bytes

```js
n=>[...e=[...Array(n+1)].map((a,i)=>[...d=((b=''.padEnd(n))[c='slice'](i)+'*'.repeat(n)+b[c](0,i))[c](n/2)].reverse().join``+d[c](n%1)),...e.reverse()[c](1)]
```

Returns an array of strings. I perform operations on arrays then mirror it. This could probably be optimized with matrices like the other answers, but I wanted to be unique.

Edit: As pointed out by Neil, for even values of `n`, the center line was not `n` wide, so I added a modulus to detect even/odd when slicing the column.

```js
n=5
['*****     *****',
 ' *****   ***** ',
 '  ***** *****  ',
 '   *********   ',
 '    *******    ',
 '     *****     ',
 '    *******    ',
 '   *********   ',
 '  ***** *****  ',
 ' *****   ***** ',
 '*****     *****']
```

**Ungolfed**

```js
n => {
  e = [...Array(n+1)].map((a, i) => {   // Create and iterate over array with n+1 elements
    b = ''.padEnd(n)                    // String of n spaces
    d = (b.slice(i) + '*'.repeat(n) + b.slice(0, i)).slice(n/2) // Create row string
    return [...d].reverse().join`` + d.slice(1) // Mirror and combine row horizontally
  })
  return [...e,...e.reverse().slice(1)] // Mirror and combine vertically
}
```

**Quadrant**

```js
n=5
   *****
  ***** 
 *****  
*****   
****    
***
```

**Mirrored Horizontally**

```js
n=5
*****     *****
 *****   ***** 
  ***** *****  
   *********   
    *******    
     *****
```

**Mirrored Vertically**

```js
n=5
*****     *****
 *****   ***** 
  ***** *****  
   *********   
    *******    
     *****     
    *******    
   *********   
  ***** *****  
 *****   ***** 
*****     *****
```

Comment: This produces incorrect output for even `n` - the centre line is not `n` wide.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>119</s> <s>118</s> 111 bytes

```
n->{var r="";for(int i=0,j;i<n-~n;i++,r+="\n")for(j=0;j<n*3;r+=j>=i&j<i+n|j<n*3-i&++j>n*2-i?"*":" ");return r;}
```

Port from [*@CarlosAlejo*'s amazing C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126277/52210), after I helped him golf a few things. **So make sure to upvote him as well!**
-4 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##RY/BasMwDIbvewrhQ4njJnQb7DDF6RO0lx23Hbw0HfJSpThOYHTZq2dqUhjIAv@S4Pu8G1zmD19T1biug50jvtwBEMc6HF1Vw/76BXiJgfgTqkQmwBolHOVJddFFqmAPDBYmzsrL4AIEqxQe2zDvk92sPVLB2S8jGbMOxqo3Vvq64O0GfcHpI0rqS0srX5DhnznLaGWMLzl9yGirUvWsQGkMdewDQ8BxwgXi3H80AnFjGVo6wElUkgX79R2cXjz@ke4RqHiSZoyeRyL53cX6lLd9zM9yFxtOOBdlffMdpz8)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 148 bytes

```
T=Table;(a=Join[T[T["*",i],{i,(n=#)+2,2n,2}],T[Join[t=T["*",n],T[" ",y],t],{y,1,n,2}]];Column[Row/@Join[Reverse@a,{T["*",n]},a],Alignment->Center])&
```

Answer (score 0):

### R, 102 bytes

Code:

```
n=scan();x=matrix(" ",M<-3*n,N<-2*n+1);for(i in 1:N)x[c(i-1+1:n,M+2-i-1:n),i]="*";cat(x,sep="",fill=M)
```

Test:

```
> n=scan();x=matrix(" ",M<-3*n,N<-2*n+1);for(i in 1:N)x[c(i-1+1:n,M+2-i-1:n),i]="*";cat(x,sep="",fill=M)
1: 10
2: 
Read 1 item
**********          **********
 **********        ********** 
  **********      **********  
   **********    **********   
    **********  **********    
     ********************     
      ******************      
       ****************       
        **************        
         ************         
          **********          
         ************         
        **************        
       ****************       
      ******************      
     ********************     
    **********  **********    
   **********    **********   
  **********      **********  
 **********        ********** 
**********          **********
```

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 24 bytes

```
{:T2*){S*T'**+}%_W%..e>}
```

This is a block that takes a number from the stack and outputs a list of lines to the stack.

#### Explanation:

```
{                        e# Stack:           | 2
 :T                      e# Store in T:      | 2, T=2
   2*                    e# Multiply by 2:   | 4
     )                   e# Increment:       | 5
      {                  e# Map over range:  | [0
       S                 e#   Push space:    | [0 " "
        *                e#   Repeat string: | [""
         T               e#   Push T:        | ["" 2
          '*             e#   Push char '*': | ["" 2 '*
            *            e#   Repeat char:   | ["" "**"
             +           e#   Concatenate:   | ["**"
              }%         e# End:             | ["**" " **" "  **" "   **" "    **"]
                _        e# Duplicate:       | ["**" " **" "  **" "   **" "    **"] ["**" " **" "  **" "   **" "    **"]
                 W%      e# Reverse:         | ["**" " **" "  **" "   **" "    **"] ["    **" "   **" "  **" " **" "**"]
                   ..e>  e# Overlay:         | ["**  **" " ****" "  **" " ****" "**  **"]
                       } e# End
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Python 2**, 110 bytes

```
x=a=0
n=c=input()
while x<2*n+1:
    print ' '*a+'*'*n+' '*c+'*'*(2*n-2*a-c)
    x+=1
    a=n-abs(n-x)
    c=max(0, n-2*a)
```

This program breaks each line into 4 parts, first spaces, first stars, second spaces and then second stars. For each horizontal line of the X it calculates how many stars or spaces are needed for each of the 4 sections of the line, then constructs and prints that string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 144 bytes

```
.+
 $&$* $&$* $&
 
$`#$'¶
¶\d+$

( *)#( *)(\d+)
$1$3$**$2#$3$* #$2$3$**$1
( +)(\*+)( *)(# +#)\3\2\3 +
$3$2$1$4$1$2$3
+` (# +#)
$1 
+` #...
#
##
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxCgMxDAT7fYVgl@RsgeHsPMfFBZIiTYqQt90D7mOOzJFCIwZG@jy/r/d9jOIwXZT/gEEbdT12HHt/uIDFcuLEEp6gVU05q3Juo@rpa4QeTQ7MmOZMvfXamzmiqXF5i4kevtkZxDubxlIKCBJjtB8) Explanation:

```
.+
 $&$* $&$* $&
```

Add 2n+1 spaces before the input value (one for each output line).

```
$`#$'¶
```

Replace each space with a `#` and collect the results. This gives a diagonal line of `#`s, space padded on both sides, with the input value suffixed.

```
¶\d+$
```

Delete the original input value, as we now have a copy on each line.

```
( *)#( *)(\d+)
$1$3$**$2#$3$* #$2$3$**$1
```

Build up two diagonal lines of n `*`s, with a separator column of `n` spaces wrapped in a pair of `#`s.

```
( +)(\*+)( *)(# +#)\3\2\3 +
$3$2$1$4$1$2$3
```

On those lines where the `*`s are nearer the middle, swap the two halves around. This gives an appearance resembling `>  | |  <`.

```
+` (# +#)
$1
```

Move the `| |`s as far left as they will go, giving a sort of `>> >    <` appearance.

```
+` #...
#
```

For each space between the `#`s, delete the three following characters. This joins the `> <` into an `X`.

```
##
```

Delete the now unnecessary `#`s.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ENI>1})¦'*…×82SΛ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f1c/TzrBW89Ayda1HDcsOT7cwCj43@/9/YwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
E      # Loop N in the range [1, (implicit) input]:
 N     #  Push loop-index N
  I>   #  Push the input, and increase it by 1
    1  #  Push 1
})     # After the loop: wrap all values on the stack into a list
  ¦    # And remove the very first 1
'*    '# Push "*"
…×82S  # Push "×82" as list: ["×",8,2]
Λ      # Use the Canvas builtin with these three arguments
       # (after which it is output implicitly)
```

*Canvas explanation:*

The Canvas builtin takes three arguments:
1. The lengths of the lines to 'draw', which in this case is the list we generate at the start with the loop. For an input \$n=3\$, the list will look like this: \$[4,1,2,4,1,3,4,1]\$ (or more in general: for sequence \$x_n\$ in \$[2,n]\$, the list will be \$[n+1,1,x_1,n+1,1,x_2,n+1,1,x_3,...]\$).
2. The string to 'draw', which in this case is `"*"`.
3. The directions, which in this case is `["×",8,2]`. These will be the directions `[cross, reset-to-origin, →]`.

With these arguments, it will draw as follows (let's take the \$n=3\$ as example again):

```
Draw an X-shaped cross of character "*" with arms of length 4:
*     *
 *   *
  * *
   *
  * *
 *   *
*     *

Reset back to the origin (8), and draw 2-1 characters "*" in direction 2 (→):
(NOTE: The origin is the center of this first cross.)
*     *
 *   *
  * *
   **
  * *
 *   *
*     *

Draw an X-shaped cross of character "*" with arms of length 4 again:
**    **
 **  **
  ****
   **
  ****
 **  **
**    **

Reset back to the origin (8), and draw 3-1 characters "*" in direction 2 (→):
**    **
 **  **
  ****
   ***
  ****
 **  **
**    **

Draw an X-shaped cross of character "*" with arms of length 4 again:
***   ***
 *** ***
  *****
   ***
  *****
 *** ***
***   ***
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine for a more in-depth explanation of the Canvas builtin.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210)